# How to figure out if a SO question is viable prior to posting?

Tags: discussion

I decided a couple months ago to try out the Stack Exchange API. While looking for ideas, I started reading a bunch of the more popular questions. I wanted to try to solve a problem affecting SO with the API. A reoccurring theme is that users are frustrated with the low quality of questions that are being submitted. To that end I've been writing a web site that will help new SO users craft good questions. It is essentially a wizard that gives feedback and hints as a user is crafting the question. It also includes links to relevant guides, tutorials, and discussions. Some of the types of feedback include:

- Is the question subjective or objective?
- How many times have questions with similar titles/keywords been asked?
- What is the average score for questions with similar keywords or tags?
- How many exact matches exist for the title?
- Is the overall sentiment positive or negative?
- How readable is this question (basic, advanced)?

The wizard breaks the question creation process down into individual steps.

1. Topic Selection (programming problem, algorithm, software development, tools)
2. Problem Description
3. Attempted Solution
4. Code Paste
5. Error Logs

At the very least, some of the bad practices in question creation can be fixed by simply getting a users to break it down into those steps.

During each step, the user gets hints and feedback:
[image: Screenshot of the problem description step]

I'm not having any trouble using the Stack Exchange API, but I'm hoping for some feedback from users on how to craft a generic algorithm for assigning a score to the users question before they post it. I understand that generally a question should get a low score if (the question):

- asked before (more so if it has been asked over
  and over)
- tags such as Android with certain red-flag
  keywords such as cOdEZ, HELP, immediately
- poor grammar or spelling
- Too short or vague problem description

And it should get a higher score if it is unique, well written, thoughtful, and contains all the relevant information needed for the experts to be able to help you.

Can anyone think of other quantifiable criteria I could use when presented with the complete question to help assign a score? I'm looking for ideas such as interesting query suggestions or criteria I haven't thought of that could help improve finding bad questions before they are posted. Or possibly a way I could mine for a generic bad question format.

Here is a screen-shot to get a complete idea of what I'm doing.

[image: A screenshot of stack-rat.com]

Out of curiosity - Am I going to have an issue with self-promotion guidelines by suggesting to new users that get down-voted for poorly written questions to try my wizard to help them write better questions?

Comment: On the topic of "criteria" I'd love to know what kind of magic goes behind this http://imgur.com/cF2V24s

Comment: @mxyl Bayesian inference based on users marking other similar questions subjective in the pastis my guess. That's what I'm using for my statistics.

Comment: This. Is. **AMAZING!** `<3 <3 <3` Is this free? Do you have a demo or beta publicly available yet?

Comment: @Cupcake Thanks. There is no beta yet. It will be completely free. The last problem I need to solve before publishing it: I need a smart way to determine some kind of score for the user. As they complete each part of the wizard, they get points (game theory, people love rewards for each little thing they do). It needs to subtract points based on exact matches (zeros out the score) and similar matches as well as bad grammar, spelling, subjectivity, etc (-1 point). Also, I need to be smarter about how I query the API to save my search results rather than attacking it for a bunch of information.

Comment: This looks absolutely awesome. Good work!

Comment: We started [something similar](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7198/alpha-testing-a-wizard) on Ask Ubuntu, but it never made it far since everyone working on it got too busy :(

Comment: Updates please!

Comment: See also [Thwart publishing duplicate and low quality questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253317/456814). Someone just proposed building a similar question asking workflow into [main] itself.

Comment: @Cupcake Thanks for the link and for linking that one to this. I suppose if this is something that takes off I should abandon spending any more time one it.

Comment: @Cupcake people were dreaming about something like this for long, see [Add a “Magic 8-Ball” feature to the Ask a Question page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1696/165773)

Answer (score 10):

We've all seen wizards. Every company we've used inevitably tries to get us to use one.

Our ISPs do it.

Our electricity/gas providers do it.

Our government services do it.

We've always *hated* it. "Why can't these lazy people just hire more staff? Why do I have to go through this hell? I *know* what my question is and *I just want to talk to a human*!"

Well, folks, the problems we have on SO are *precisely* why those wizards are put in place. I, for one, welcome our new wizard overlords. +1 from me.