# Punish answerers of bad questions

Tags: discussion, reputation, answers, closed-questions

[This answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252531/2888561) got me thinking…

> To stop the bad behavior, we have to stop encouraging the bad behavior. We need to stop answering bad questions, and we need to downvote the answers to bad questions. The downvote tooltip says "This answer is not useful." **Answers (even correct ones) are not useful if they contribute to the demise of the site.**

So, how about instead of having to manually downvote these answers, we could have a bot do it? An answer to a bad question contributes to the demise of the site, so **How about a -10 rep penalty when the question you answered gets closed?**

Comment: Are you expecting some answers?

Comment: There's a sweet irony here with this question.

Comment: So... punish people for trying to help the people that need their help the most?  That seems... counterintuitive.

Comment: @JustinTime This isn't a help site.

Answer (score -13, accepted):

Rather than punishing what I feel is that if an answer is closed ***due to reasons that point to it being bad quality*** then the user *providing answer* can be notified that:

*The question which you answered was closed due to quality issues, please pay attention to the quality of question*

And then if the user gets some *n* count of these warnings then we can come up with some mechanism to punish such users (**answerers**), because constantly raising these warnings means that the user is totally rep centric and not interested in keeping the community clean.

Comment: I think this is a great idea. Direct reputation change may be too much, but warnings and eventual punishment would deter answers almost as well.

Answer (score 45):

**Some closures aren't justified.**  I shouldn't be punished because I didn't agree with the mob's decision to close an answer.

I suppose to add on to this answer (although I feel my point was made) - what happened to optimizing [pearls instead of sand](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/)?  If an answer is truly spectacular, even on a question that is closed, why should we be punishing that?

Yes, the question *may* have a duplicate, or it *may* have been too subjective, or it might have been closed for some legacy reason.  But the answers are still incredibly useful.

Implementing a system like this seems extremely heavy-handed to a problem that I'm not convinced is really a problem.

Comment: That's what the reopen button is for. Saying "well closing might not be right, so all features related to closing is useless" is wrong. Closing can be reversed, the rep given back.

Comment: -10 for answering a bad question =] jk

Comment: @bjb568:  I doubted the effectiveness of a question getting reopened; we have [some numbers now](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252561/1079354) to at least demonstrate that the occurrence is pretty rare.

Comment: But what does that have to do with this? If the closing system is unjust, fixing it is out of the scope of this post.

Comment: At that point, you're merely fixing a symptom, not the actual *problem*.  If the problem, as you describe it, is poor questions, then editing them and nominating them for reopening is also a problem, as it means that so-called "bad" questions don't get the same attention again.  I feel like they're one and the same, and I still believe that a heavy-handed approach like the one you're describing is ***way*** overboard.

Comment: "If an answer is truly spectacular, even on a question that is closed, why should we be punishing that?" Because it encourages bad questions.

Comment: Correlation doesn't imply causation.  Yes, some questions there are truly awful, but the ultimate goal is to find an answer.  Attempting to punish someone because they're participating within the confines of a Q&A system seems...counter-intuitive to me.

Comment: @Makoto Poor questions are a problem, so we should stop rewarding them with answers. Reopening is not a problem, it's a great thing that undoes wrongs.

Comment: I would have upvoted this answer if there weren't the last *" I'm not convinced is really a problem."*. I go away from SO more and more often because I more and more see only crap.

Comment: [It's definitely a problem.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/g79YD.png)

Comment: @bjb568:  I don't disagree with the notion of creating high quality Q&A.  But I maintain that it's still a very heavy-handed approach. That said, the graph you linked to indicates that the trend for an initial upvote is down, which may be a symptom of another problem - questions that were asked eons ago were welcomed with open arms, as they didn't have a canonical answer here yet, whereas similar (even slightly similar) questions are met with a lot of hostility.  So I'm not that surprised that it's hard to get an initial upvote on a question.

Comment: If it's too much, do you think Narendra's approach would work?

Comment: @bjb568:  I don't; it's effectively showing me a message stating that I answered a question that I shouldn't have, and I should be more careful about it in the future before God knows what else may happen.  That feels more detrimental than beneficial, and it would actively discourage those of us from answering.  Now, I can respect that one may believe that the questions that are affected by this are those of low quality, but that may not necessarily be true.  In either event, I see more negatives than positives with that approach.

Comment: @Makoto Well… I guess I agree that just warnings that happen before "God knows what" don't work very well. It does seem negative. Do you think that moving the warning to *before* posting the answer would help? "Are you sure you want to answer this question? It currently has 2 pending close votes - please vote to close if you believe it is appropriate."

Comment: Again, no; it feels like that is placing one's expectations of a question that is both downvoted and/or has close votes into a pigeonhole.  It's almost like it's saying, "We think this question is poor, and you should too, so we're warning you before you interact with it."  I don't think that's a positive message or approach at all.

Comment: @bjb568 - wow I have never seen that chart, how depressing, can you share the link to the query so we can get an updated chart ourselves?

Comment: @JarrodRoberson http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/312593/initial-quality-timeseries#graph http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/312596/initial-quality-timeseries#graph