# No one should get rep for asking or answering "typo" questions like this!

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

Strawman Example: [Boolean/Integer usage in this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30147283/boolean-integer-usage-in-this-code)

#### I guarantee there is a dupe of this somewhere:

I answered this because I know from experience that finding a duplicate will take a couple of minutes and it would probably have half a dozen answers by then and be re-opened by some high rep user just so they could answer it and get rep on it anyway.

I also added the following comment:

> **this is a typo it should be vote to closed as such and deleted**, I know I answered this, but that should encourage you to vote to close
> and vote to delete! They got their answer and no-one deserves rep for
> answering a question like this!

Lets see how long this question stays open, it is just noise and will not help anyone, this is why **too localized** existed. I agree that the name of that reason was poorly worded semantically, but there still needs to be that classification.

If the system was *working as designed* it should get closed quicker than the answers were given. That did not happen, so the next best thing is people respond to the comment I made, including the OP.

### How can we gamify the moderation tools?

So that they balance out the gamification of the Q/A and reward those that do moderation as much or more than it would for them to answer these types of questions and just add to the noise in the system.

I have proposed what would be an extremely effective system that mimics what is already in place for other things.

[Probationary period for Questions to be Answered to encourage better questions with more effective Moderation?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252769/probationary-period-for-questions-to-be-answered-to-encourage-better-questions-w)

But it does not address rewarding community moderation equally to the Q/A, which would probably be more effective with that probationary period actually.

Comment: What design do you see that would enable this?   The question has a low view count, and only three other users (likely after seeing this post) with access to moderation tools closed it.  Not just that, but how would we guard against questions flagged as typos incorrectly?  [The mob isn't always right.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252657/1079354)

Comment: If we had a better quality, rapid dup-finder, as has been discussed and requested elsewhere, this would be a non-issue, since basic typo errors are usually common errors/SO questions. I know that this is not a trivial request, but it has to be possible. Otherwise the only other solution would be to develop different flavors of Mjölnir, but that brings in other inherent dangers of too much power concentrated in too few.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - I like the Mjölnir reference and props for the correct unicode characters! I think that term negatively characterises the tool. The community can undo whatever Mjölnir does, it just does it quicker.

Comment: The potential energy barrier towards undoing a Mjölnir closed question is high, and so likely many that should be un-done are not.

Comment: It is no higher than it is to close the question without Mjölnir powers ... right? The same is true even more so of things that are noise and I personally think the needs of the many out weigh the needs of the few. And unlike Thor there are many people with Mjölnir that can undo with a single swing as well.

Answer (score 3):

You are right and wrong.

I agree with you that people shouldn't gain rep from basic typo questions - but that doesn't mean you can't answer it and help the user. There's been many times I've answered but also voted to close for some reason.

Now for the part where you are wrong... the system *is* working. Right at this moment that question is closed which means no new answers can be given, and there's two delete votes cast (3 are needed). When a new question is deleted any rep gained or lost on the answers is reversed. As per your statement ***no-one gets rep***. If this isn't an indication of the system working, then what is?

> If the system was working as designed it should get closed quicker than the answers were given

The system relies on human reviewers, most of whom are reasonably proficient and knowledgeable. The system also has checks and balances. This is a more accurate and efficient mechanism than any programmatic method that could be devised.

But as I already said, your outrage at a basic typo question and an allegedly "failing system" still doesn't mean the user should be denied an answer if someone wants to help. It simply means their question has no value according to the site manifesto, therefore it can be pruned at an appropriate time. Which is what is happening.

Comment: that question was only closed because of the `meta-effect`, and even that took 45+ minutes, on a tag like the [Java] tag that should have taken less time than it took to answer, and I answered 2 minutes after.

Comment: I've always thought of the typo close reason as one that is best applied retroactively, or based on answers - it is often the *answer* that reveals that the question was based on an isolated problem and/or solved in a way that will not help future readers. One could argue that one should then post the solution as a comment or CW to avoid rep gains, but then you're going to get people telling you that you're misusing comments or CW. Frankly I think this rep-gain deal just adds a needless complication to the whole thing.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson the meta effect certainly helped, but once a close vote is cast the question enters a queue where other reviewers will have to evaluate it too. This can take time, but is a crucial part of the checks and balances system. Sometimes close votes age away before the question is closed (I've seen it happen on some truly awful questions), but in any case there is no point raging against the system unless you have a viable solution which is better (and ideally costs or takes little to nothing to implement).

Comment: @slugster - I have [Probationary period for Questions to be Answered to encourage better questions with more effective Moderation?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252769/probationary-period-for-questions-to-be-answered-to-encourage-better-questions-w)

Comment: The system is **not** working. Answer a typo question, get it accepted before moderation tools are effective (which are less and less effective as the volume of questions increases). Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53836376/3303195

Comment: @faintsignal That's a bad example and not necessarily a typo, rather that was the OP referencing the wrong thing due to failing to distinguish between plural and singular. In any case, so what? Is there really an issue here? A person got some fake internet points because they took the time to point out the error of the OP, thus helping them. You're entitled to cast a close vote, it's then up to the community to support you with that - if they do then great, if they don't then things are still great. You win some, you lose some, it's up to the community.