# Should downvotes on questions affect answers?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, low-quality-posts, question-quality

Today I opened up Notepad++ and wrote:

> Please note StackOverflow is dedicated to helping programmers learn to program rahter than providing free coding services. Your question should be in the form of ***Why isn't my code working? I think it should!*** rather than the form of ***Code this for me, please! Many thanks in advance!***

I wanted to be more efficient so I thought I'd make a template.

But I realized I was wrong. This is not what StackOverflow efficiency should be about. It shouldn't be repeatedly having to add a comment that has to do with common sense and is already covered in the rules.
Efficiency here should be about having better questions and better answers.

New users have to click through [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to be able to post their first question. Yet, most fail to read it. Ok, so not much can be done in order to improve the questions quality or to prevent duplicates. Fine.

But an effective counter measure would be to make those low quality questions ***a lot less likely to be answered***.
What if a few downvotes on the question (say 3?) would translate in `-1` on each of the answers? Wouldn't it make people care more about the quality of the questions they answer?

A good answer is a good answer and should not have to suffer for the low quality of the question. **True**. But if it's a good answer, it will make up with only one upvote for the loss from 30 downvotes on the question. So its loss could be considered symbolic, compared to the gain from upvotes. And I think it should be punished, even if only symbolic, because ***a good answer on a bad question encourages more bad questions***.

Besides, a good answer would, at best, be wasted on a bad question. A bad question will likely get down-voted. Hence, it will get fewer visits, even it shows up in *related* list. So the awesome answer will get fewer views and will help fewer future visitors.

---

**Edit:** [@Servy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1159478/servy) assumed this would add a perverse incentive for answerers to group and vote up a poor quality question. But that would happen only if both negative and positive votes on question would affect the answers. I'm proposing *only negative votes would*.

Ultimately, I don't think this would affect the rep system much. Not so many `-3` questions get answered and usually bad questions are bad because they require answers which are unlikely to help future visitors. Besides, `-1` is nothing. But it will serve as a mental barrier. A reminder to always consider the quality of the question before posting an answer, which now doesn't happen particularly often.

---

Another important distinction I'd like to make about what I'm suggesting is that I'm not proposing that an answer automatically gets downvotes for exiting negative votes on a question, but only for votes cast after it was submitted and only if at the time of the downvote it was active (not deleted)

---

As [@makoto](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1079354/makoto) pointed out below, I'm not the first to propose a penalty for answering low quality questions. [This question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252656/punish-answerers-of-bad-questions) proposes a different, more drastic penalty for it. IMHO, Makoto's write-up there is worth a read.

Comment: so, what if the question is unclear... but has GREAT potential for future searches? We shouldn't answer it, then clarify it for posterity? (We even have the 'reversal' badge for these situations). Ultimately stack is about building a repo of knowledge. Qs are just a vehicle (and a poor one at that if you ask me) to get that repo populated. Answers are where the meat's at

Comment: You're now adding perverse incentives though.  People answering low quality questions are given an incentive to upvote the question, because it'll make the answer "worth more".  The result of this may well just result in these code requests getting more upvotes (or other readers not downvoting a bad question "because that would hurt the answerers), rather than the answerers being discouraged.

Comment: You're right up to a point, @Servy. But you should know one vote against the **stream** doesn't matter much. I believe people upvote the questions they answer, for the very same reason, anyway, to a certain degree.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu That's one upvote *if there is only one answer*.  Many help vampire code requests get half a dozen people falling over each other to copy-paste the first google result for the OP, and they're all now incentivised to upvote the question.  Additionally, in lower traffic tags, a single vote from an answerer is likely enough to keep a question from getting to, say, -3, because it's pretty rare for a question to even get that far in many niche topics.

Comment: Often there are more answers than downvotes in some of the very basic questions though, which should be closed. I agree with Servy, incentivizing the group answering these to also then upvote the question would probably be counter productive.

Comment: @Makoto It does tackle the same issue, but proposes a different solution.  But your answer there shows that good answers can dwell on downvoted questions. However, it never showed up in my searches and I believe it should have. Could it have to do with the minus score of the question?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu:  I don't know how you were searching, but this particular question reminded me of a moment in time in which I realized that "the mob" of users closing/voting down a question *could* be wrong, so I searched that in my own history.

Comment: Although judging quality of questions on Meta by score is not exactly the same as on SO. I'd like to believe the downvotes on this question have to do with the affinity towards the proposed method/idea, not with the quality of my "question".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do this the way you've suggested without:

- Punishing people for answering controversial questions
- Punishing people for answering questions that *were* bad but got fixed
- Allowing all users to see vote counts (because you can't expect people to avoid questions with down votes, *regardless of their actual score*, if they can't even see it was down voted)

But in general I can't get on board with the idea that we're going to be OK with a question being on the site (that is, not closed)* but then punish people for answering it. If the question shouldn't be answered at all then the question needs to be removed. Deletion already causes any rep gained by answering it to go away.

<sup>*I am, however, a fan of this effort to [fix or delete find/rec requests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341987/lets-rescue-wayward-resource-requests-trial-run).</sup>

Comment: I agree with your point about controversial questions. But the other two assume the answer would lose rep for downvotes preceeding the answer. I was proposing a system when a downvote on a question would add a `tick` to existing answers. When an answer gets 3 `ticks`, it would get `-1` and get all ticks removed.

Answer (score 2):

There's always going to be those who aren't ashamed to occasionally downvote answers to really bad questions (like myself) and those who think that's completely outrageous and wrong, and we should only ever focus on the content of the answer and never *ever* on the circumstances.

This is ultimately down to belief and has been discussed before, like [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255853/should-downvotes-be-used-to-punish-people-who-answer-bad-questions).

We *could* discuss it some more, but the system is *very, very unlikely* to ever be changed in a way that automates the punishment of answers to bad questions.

Comment: I didn't write this thinking about how likely it is to make a change. I wrote it as I thought it has the potential to change something for the better and because I wanted to know if others thought the same. If people shut up every time they feared it might not make a difference, the world would be worse today, at least that's what I think. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm not saying this out of fear - rather *experience*. :) It's certainly not wrong to talk about the topic in general. A good takeaway from this is that it's not always wrong to downvote good answers when the question is really really bad.

Comment: Not sure why that would be the takeaway, since nothing here nor the citation linked supports downvoting good answers. Ultimately, the belief alluded to here has been disproved if anything - not that has stopped such a belief from still residing in the "vote as you see fit" guideline.

Comment: @TravisJ You're making the *assertion* that people dumping code on Gimmie Teh Codez answers *are good answers* (or people sharing their opinions on opinion surveys, or posting wild guesses on unclear unanswerable questions, etc.), and then from there saying that downvoting them is contrary to guidelines.  That's a faulty premise.  Such answers *aren't good answers*.  They aren't useful.  The fact that they may not have factually wrong statements doesn't prevent them from being bad answers.

Comment: @Servy - I was responding to the statement: "it's not always wrong to downvote good answers". There was no assertion needed as it was explicitly stated. I agree that the list of scenarios you outline are not good answers, but would note that there was no inference from my response.

Comment: @TravisJ Indeed, I should have directed that comment at Pekka.  My apologies.