# Team up with Moderators

Tags: discussion, flags, privileges, moderators, moderator-abilities

**Case:** I have voted to close [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22103323/jquery-mobile-viewport-height) as duplicate before two month. Since no other user seconded my vote, the vote is automatically retracted and I can't vote again. I flagged it a Moderator that should be closed as duplicate, but my flag got declined and the question is still open.

**Case:** I couldn't close [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23308215/how-to-add-data-dynamically-in-jquerry) as a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23306311/1771795). Both questions are by the same user but under two different accounts. I raised a flag with explanation and I am still anticipating the feedback. Since the first question has an answer but isn't accepted nor up-voted, It can't be closed. The *workaround* is to up-vote that answer, then vote to close second question.

**Case:** I have noticed that *user-X* is receiving *suspicious* up-votes even on wrong/vague/incomplete answers. Again, I have flagged that user with no response so far.

> Dear Moderators, are you overloaded? Allow us to take a *weight* off your shoulders, you can lean on us.

There are over **8k** users with "[*Access To Moderators Tools Privilege*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)", and the number is increasing day by day. I can't tell how many of them are actively participating in keeping SO's atmosphere *healthy* for both help seekers and help providers. However, I am sure that the majority are willing to volunteering if they get the chance to be deeper involved in the community.

Why don't each Moderator team up with experienced users in *tags* that have high traffic? As I have mentioned in this [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252195/there-is-no-shame-in-using-skip/252264#252264), why not to utilize "Gold Badge"?

We are not after rep nor badges, we want to help! Can't we team up?

Comment: Handling vote fraud and sock puppeting might take a few days, you might want to indicate how long exactly those flags are active.

Comment: The 8k must be taken with [a grain of salt](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252561/more-effective-closing-down-voting-of-junk-questions-to-help-with-the-signal#252648)

Comment: @PlasmaHH this is a bad indicator, thanks for sharing.

Comment: Yes, we are overloaded. Since it doesn't require a moderator to close questions as duplicates, it would be better to team up with other experts in your tags to get them closed.  (Try using chat to find other users who are interested.) Also, I went through your profile to find the "suspicioius votes" flag and handled it. Good flag.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Thank you. I know I shouldn't have flagged a moderator for such an issue, but believe or not, there are not much users interested in that tag, you can check top users of [jquery-mobile](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-mobile/topusers).

Comment: @BilltheLizard pls my profile again whenever you can.

Answer (score 9):

The best way you can help us out is by *good* flagging and by voting to close duplicates.

There's a close review queue. Let's use it.  Moderators shouldn't really need to get involved with question closure (though the fact that we do indicates there aren't nearly enough people voting to close).

There's no need to flag questions for closure.  You can just 'vote to close as a duplicate of...'  In the case where a different user posts the same question, vote to close it, and flag it with a custom flag, "Hey, I think user X and user Y are the same user because they posted the same question."

A good general rule to follow:

> If you can handle it through your menus, handle it. If you can't handle it through the tools given to you, try to enlist others through chat.  If you can't handle it then, flag it for us.

While we are the strongest line of defense, we are not the first; we're the last.

Comment: Thanks, you're the fastest in closing duplicates. I usually keep an eye on questions and try to keep the tag I'm experienced in clean. The problem is there is no much traffic on that tag and hence my close votes are hidden to close queue. As I said, I want to help and I'm willing to. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228270/are-my-close-votes-being-neglected