# "spend" some available flags on the review queues

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, flags

Unless I've missed something, flagged posts seem easier to police and are less susceptible to the robots sitting on the review queues.  It stands to reason then that they may perhaps be a better indicator of the community's trust in a user than mere rep. alone.

I can easily hit the limit on a review-queue over the course of the day but I've rarely used all of the flags I have available to me.  What would be the implications of allowing a user to exchange flags or otherwise offset their review-limit by the number of additional flags they had been trusted with as a result of ***successful*** flagging?

It sounds minor but as a mechanism for allowing those folks who are actually reading through posts and flagging appropriately to have a few extra votes on the review-queues, then the cumulative effect might reduce the impact of robo-reviewers?

Answer (score 4):

For what it's worth, you can (judiciously) use flags to "leverage" your reviews.

When you stumble upon a blatantly bad post in review, simply open it in a separate window and flag appropriately.

For low quality questions, this will generally [speed up the closure](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252852/839601). For low quality answers, this will make an [additional "protection"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/204691/165773) that post won't be kicked off review by a mistaken *Looks Good* vote.

---

<sub>I spend about 20-30 flags daily this way, working in [CV](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close) and [LQ](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts) queues. I could spend more, by skipping posts I flag to avoid bumping into [review limit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147981/165773) (that way, others would take care of these posts) but frankly, I don't feel like I need more - picking and additionally analysing flag-worthy stuff takes quite a lot of effort.</sub>