# Is Stack Overflow becoming too big for manual moderation?

Tags: discussion, moderation

EDIT: This question is about information management. Its not about how to moderate. Its about asking if moderation is the best way to manage all that info, as it grows bigger and bigger.

EDIT 2: by *manual moderation* i mean a human editing or deleting or marking as duplicate it, etc. As opposed to a user *rating*, such as upvoting - which i dont see as moderation at all.

I've been reading threads about how SO is struggling with the sheer volume of low-quality questions and answers and duplicates, and wondering how to moderate itself out of this mess.

This cannot be moderated away. Trying to do so will fail. Moderators will lose their zest for life. And still nothing will improve after all that effort. There is so much new content that moderation can no longer keep the site usable for those people wanting to use SO as a coding resource...or to get rep for their fantastic career...get their work done for them...etc.

To keep providing this resource to users, it will continue to grow, and manual moderation will become impossible—if it hasn't already.

Other sites that are too big to moderate, change the way the site runs. They give up trying to control the content, and pass on all of the work to the user - so that the users vote up questions that are good, and searches return better questions before junk.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to say/ask?

Comment: There is an ongoing discussion [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252561/2507539) and I'm sure there have been others. There are some suggestions to increase moderator power, however I've argued for semi-automation and time delays (probation) as you quite correctly point out, increasing moderation load is not going to work.

Comment: `They give up trying to control the content, and pass on all of the work to the user - so that the users vote up questions that are good, and searches return better questions before junk.`.... Um, unless I am misunderstanding you, this already happens.  Most of the moderation is done by regular users.

Comment: @psubsee2003 thats what im calling manual moderation - its done by humans. and its not stemming the tide. also, arent i a regular user? im not a moderator.

Comment: @kodintent then explain your point because nothing you are saying is clear.  What do you want to?  Create automated moderation bots?  Break it up into smaller pieces?  Stop worrying about content and just let anyone post any crap they want?  Shut down the site?

Comment: @psubsee2003, release the Kraken.

Comment: haha @psubsee2003 now i understand where you are coming from. as im just thinking about mass information management, i didnt anticipate your reaction.

Comment: @kodintent so are you trying to suggest that moderation should be automated more, instead of having users do it manually?

Comment: @Cupcake. im not suggesting that. im asking about the usefulness of human moderation over a large and growing body of info. Im sorry if im offending any moderators.

Comment: @kodintent you're not offending anyone, it's just that your question (is it a question?) is confusing. Do you have any suggestions for an alternative to human moderation?

Comment: @Cupcake well, i see that as the next question - what alternatives are there to human moderation, for SO - IF it is decided that SO is getting too big for human moderation. i think many people feel that human moderation is still the way to go.

Comment: What I would worry about is quality of moderation - see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340014/moderators-should-be-downrated-too-for-their-actions - 2nd time I see Wikipedia-style (unjustified or stangely-justified moderation actions that is) moderation in this community

Answer (score 20):

If you mean diamond moderation, we can't do it all without the community's help. To do that, we would need about four times the number of *active* moderators than we have now, and you could say goodbye to meaningful community influence.

No, what the site really needs is *more community involvement.*  There are 24,000 people on the site with vote to close privileges, more than enough to make the front page clean 24 hours a day.  Why doesn't this happen?  In part, I think it is because we make moderation too complicated.  We wring our hands over scope, and argue about whether or not we're being fair by closing people's questions.  We debate endlessly over legalistic interpretations of the rules, and argue with those who close questions "prematurely."

What we really should be doing is making a judgement call, and closing poor or incomplete questions *immediately,* while the OP gathers more information and improves the question so that it can be reopened.  Questions should be reopened as soon as they are made answerable and on-topic.

In short, I don't think we do this close/reopen cycle quickly enough.  Closing doesn't stop a question; it only stops *answers,* and if your premise is that bad questions get rewarded because they get answered anyway, this is the correct way to stop it.

More automation is not the answer either, unless you can find a way for SE to get a sentient computer to pre-screen questions.  Those folks who are looking for a way to block the questions before the community sees them, or dropping new user questions into some sort of purgatory or ghetto are *missing the point;* you need to see the questions to be able to moderate them.

Tim Post has discussed ways to make the question bans more permanent, so that people can't just delete their accounts and come back.  I've proposed a way to give high-rep users a stronger close vote, so that new questions on the front page can be *closed by two or three high-rep community members,* instead of five.  This would not only give high-rep users some better tools, but more incentive to use them.  These are the kinds of solutions I think we should be focusing on.

Comment: Your thoughts on probation periods, mentioned [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252750/2507539) and [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253489/2507539) ?

Comment: @dilbert: Those proposed solutions appear to focus on *answers,* which is backwards.  We should be focusing on *questions,* and if your premise is that answers on poor questions should be delayed until the question is improved, that's exactly what closing is for.

Comment: No, that's the probation mechanism described in the first link. I've argued for a probation period on **asking** questions; check the second link.

Comment: If I had to wait to post my first question; that's exactly what I'd do.  I'd leave for lunch, come back when the probationary period has expired, and ask my question then.  I'd find it goofy, but whatever.

Comment: All that said, if a new post by a new user got two downvotes, I wouldn't be opposed to inhibiting answers for 5 minutes.

Comment: Consider that we are dealing with people (new users) who only have a singular interest in their immediate problem and are unwilling to perform proper research beforehand. This unwillingness is probably driven by laziness and impatience. The idea is that an impatient person when confronted with waiting, will seek to avoid it somehow; in this case, avoid it by finding an already answered question and thereby never ask the duplicate question in the first place.

Comment: I'm not sure what the original poster was asking/saying, but regardless, this is one of the best written summaries of the current moderation problem (and proposed solutions) on [main] that I've seen yet.