# Reviewing system for edits to existing answers needs change (see comments thread)

Tags: support, moderation

PLEASE ALSO READ COMMENTS IN DISCUSSION BELOW

copying my comment from
[How I can change the color of a TPanel with the VCL Styles enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309190/how-i-can-change-the-color-of-a-tpanel-with-the-vcl-styles-enabled/22825182?noredirect=1#comment69656614_22825182)
here:

> StackOverflow is getting Wikipedia-moderation-type-illness - See at
>   the comments at this rejection - let's see if they'll reject my change
>   again - what a #fail -
>   https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14631823

The #fail is that I augmented a correct but very short answer to show HOW to implement the suggestion. The HOW part isn't obvious, since it is a "set" type property - even me [with a Spirit of Delphi award for JEDI QuickTime] coming back to Delphi latest version from many years of Java and C# to update some opensource project that wasn't rendering properly had to look up that it is a set property and the syntax to remove a flag from it. After all, I believe StackOverflow answers are useful when they provide sample code, not just some plain short text

btw, I'd expect to get a notification when my changes are rejected, I just happened to notice the change was missing there and started wondering why (neither the author of the question I had augmented with sample code and article url was notified to vote - system should be changed to first give him the chance to accept they change, unless they've opted to not get such notifications)

**update:**
was pointed to this suggestion which I upvoted

[Decision on rejected edits should be displayed as a notification to the editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120624/decision-on-rejected-edits-should-be-displayed-as-a-notification-to-the-editor)

I do feel though that more is needed (see discussion in comments below)

Comment: and I'd suggest allowing people to vote on moderator actions (pro/against) at the comment that comes with their action

Comment: Another case of "I have no idea how the system works, but I'll make bold, scandalous claims about it anyway." The information you are trying to add should be an answer of its own, for several reasons. The most important one is that the author of the original answer may not want to be associated with the content you're adding (they'll be getting the downvotes if it's incorrect) and reviewers may have no way of checking whether your addition is technically correct - that isn't the job of the review system.

Comment: @Pekka no, I'm not providing any new answer - I voted for the correct answer and just augmenting it with sample code. This is how the system SHOULD work. I won't get credit for the answer that someother person gave, especially since it wasn't obvious to find the answer to that problem in the first place

Comment: `This is how the system SHOULD work` it *can't* work that way for the reasons above. Just provide your own answer. No one will mind.

Comment: The author could be notified and DOWNVOTE the change if the wish to. The author told me in a comment at that answer that he didn't receive any notification about my change. And no, ignorant moderators doing rejections on technical subjects is Wikipedia plague. A big #fail that is

Comment: Also they rejected it saying I was replying to the author - see my text again, the text was replying to the person asking the question with sample code for that short answer that was originally given and a link to an article from Embarcadero Developer Network (the company now behind Delphi) that shows how to remove a flag from that property

Comment: So basically, "THE SYSTEM SUX AND SHOULD BE COMPLETELY DIFFERENT!!!!!!". Got it. (Note that it's generally not moderators who reject changes, and there's a HUGE difference to Wikipedia: *you can add your own contribution as a separate answer in under five seconds.*)

Comment: BTW, this has nothing to do with *moderators*, but with *reviewers*. There are only a handful of moderators, distinguished by the ♦ next to their name (Hi!). What happened to you were regular other community members peer-reviewing your edit.

Comment: so, why isn't the original author the first the system asks? If they don't act in say a couple of days, then the item should be passed on to the community (but only to people with upvoted answers in that subject preferably)

Comment: ...mean author of the edited answer btw, but author of the question could also vote on the proposed change to the answer (especially if they had accepted the answer)

Comment: That the system should maybe work that way is a reasonable suggestion. If you are, in fact, interested in reasonable discussion, you could start a separate feature request for that (unless it already exists, which is possible.) I predict  people won't agree with it, though, because that would slow down the pace of edits in the system. Another idea would be that the post author could retroactively accept the edit even if it gets rejected

Comment: This topic is unfortunately receiving a bunch of downvotes, very likely due to the confrontational and aggressive tone used. Though there is a true concern here, which only really surfaces in the comments. Yes, this edit was probably pretty good and warranted, no, unfortunately reviewers weren't able to see that, likely because they were missing some context while doing the review. Question: how can this be avoided to make the content on SO the best it can be? – If you could constructively rephrase your question towards this end I'll think we'll get somewhere here.

Comment: I believe it would save time if people are by default notified for such edits and accept/reject before reviewers get to see the changes. They could have option to not get such notifications (if they feel they're spammed). In such cases the system would pass it immediately to reviewers.

Comment: Regarding the downvotes here, unfortunately people don't really read before "following the train". That's also the problem with the "me too" actions of the reviewers. Somebody gives a misjudged review and then others say "me too" without first trying to debate that review (which is the scientific way of judging something in the first place)

Comment: Unfortunately you'll have to content with reality here. We do need *some* sort of review to avoid real content degradation. The review queue is always overflowing, putting in delays or expecting people to spend more time on each review isn't going to go very well probably. So in the end reviewers tend to look for patterns, and yours rather fit a pattern that leans towards declining the edit. You fell through the cracks. Let's discuss how to avoid that, instead of slinging accusations and calling everything a #fail.

Comment: Btw, professionals (in contrast with hobbyist/student devs) generally have less time to spend in trying to fix the system, unless they have grown to the habit of it. But their contributions should be encouraged (that is have less things that could potentially feel it's loss of time to contribute) I feel if quality content is to flourish. Just my 2c on this. Hope people catch up with this comments thread and rethink the reviewing system a bit

Comment: I don't use #fail as accusation to somebody, just use it to flag something that doesn't work correctly (even in edge cases). I'm really afraid of the Wikipedia pattern creeping into StackOverflow too (it is my 1st goto place to find answers)

Comment: ...and my suggestion of "downrating" moderation/reviewing actions in the title is for eventually having people with different voting "power" in the system. That can cause a problem to newcoming reviewers and an elite forming up, but still communities are held by people that persist in quality (be it answers, reviews, etc.), so such people should get rated for their actions (either by peers or by people with higher level, e.g. say just moderators rate reviewers [say mostly downrate, or uprate for excellent review on rare cases - when they go against the "train"]) in order to get more power

Comment: So, try to present that whole thing in a more coherent and constructive way. 1. Hey, here's what happened to me. That seems very unfortunate. 2. Should we do something about that? 3. If so, how about X? – Try reading your post again from the top with fresh eyes; it's an incoherent mess right now.

Comment: [How can I appeal a rejection of a suggested edit?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113727/how-can-i-appeal-a-rejection-of-a-suggested-edit), [Decision on rejected edits should be displayed as a notification to the editor](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120624/decision-on-rejected-edits-should-be-displayed-as-a-notification-to-the-editor)

Comment: @deceze do you mean this post or the original change I did to the answer?

Comment: @deceze thanks for the pointer - seems somebody has started the discussion already (even it if is just the part of sending notification to author of original answer and not about rating reviewer actions for them to get more or less voting power eventually). That's encouraging (apart from the fact that is started at 2014 and two years have passed already)

Comment: Re "I just happened to notice the change was missing there and started wondering why " => Go to your profile => all actions => suggestions if you're concerned about your edit being approved/rejected.

Comment: @Tensibai - I eventually searched and found it from there. But the thing is that I accidentally noticed my edit was missing when the author of the original answer replied to my thank you comment at his answer. A notification should be sent. Moreover the original author of the answer should be the first person to be notified on the change (before reviewers see it) and accept it. That would also save reviewer work. Only if they opt at such a notification to not receive any more (or set it from their profile), the reviewers should get told to oversee the change

Comment: ...btw, not sure if it currently sends such, but if the accepted answer is changed (and change gets accepted), the person asking the original question should also get notified to see that change in case it helps them some more

Comment: Well, suggested edit are done only by users < 2k reputation, over 2k the edit is done and the post author is notified. The main idea is not to bother everyone with spam bots and so on editing posts, that's what the review queue is for.

Comment: Any new post/edit on a answer to your question will trigger a notification to you; seriously, spend some time reading the help center, you'll find answers to most of your questions.

Comment: @Tensibai - not sure how easy it would be to implement, but maybe only people with some number of upvoted answers on a tag or category (?) like "Delphi" in this case should be allowed (or their upvote/downvote given more "power/votes") for a specific question/answer thread

Comment: @Tensibai indeed, indeed I remember having received such for updates to a thread (apart from comments I guess).

Comment: That's a terrible idea, if someone correct spelling in one of my answer when I'm sleeping, I don't care who review it, it doesn't need an expert in the subject for that...

Comment: @GeorgeBirbilis Really, read the help center, search, Try to solve your problem by yourself etc. before writing an essai in comments.

Comment: @Tesnibai the system already asks you to not do very small changes (has a limit of characters changed if I remember well), so I guess people rarely change spelling. It could judge the extend of the change (say diff) and don't notify maybe in such cases. I still believe the author of an answer should have the say on changes to their answer. If they fell they're spammed they could turn off such behavior of the system (the notification could have the option to never receive such again [for changes to their answers])

Comment: @Pekka 웃  - have edited that answer again. If it gets rejected again, then it didn't just happen that it got rejected without much consideration by the reviewers. Hope it wasn't an incident that reproduces consistently. I really don't see why I should add a new answer stealing somebody else's suggestion when I can augment it with sample code instead

Comment: @GeorgeBirbilis it *should* get rejected again, as it's *explicitly* against how the system works. If you still haven't got that into your head after all this discussion, there is no point in discussing any further.

Comment: #hashtags #don't #work #in #comments

Comment: @Pekka 웃 - so the system is that the new change gets accepted and then somebody goes on and deletes it? http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22825182/revisions - and also deletes my comments at that answer where I was discussing with the author of the answer whether they got a notification for my change? Hmm... Something is really wrong here, sorry but I won't bother anymore with a broken system like this

Comment: ...and "that's how the system works" is the Wikipedia path of moderation/reviewing going "by the book" instead of caring about the value of the content that end users face when searching for an answer to their question (and are pointed to the site by Google) and "rewriting the book" if needed

Comment: As said repeatedly, differently from having your contribution deleted on Wikipedia, there's a super obvious and easy way for you to contribute what you want to contribute in this situation: *write an answer*. The only thing it requires is you to stop insisting that things must work exactly as you think they need to work. By providing an answer you're not "stealing" anything from anyone; reference the author of the original answer, point out that you're contributing a bit of code to add more detail, and everything's hunky dory.

Answer (score 10):

Oh boy.

- Don't use Hashtags on Stack Overflow (that'd be a real illness)
- Format your question (spelling, grammar, punctuation)
- Keep it professional (don't rant like that, offer constructive feedback)
- Match title onto question content (Yours does not match)

Your edit changed the meaning of the original answer. **That's a "no can do sir".** If I post on here I expect the meaning of what I posted to stay the same (except for CW-answers). I would really hate having words put in my mouth. Thus, your edit was rejected. You don't receive a notification for that because (that's what I assume) it could really clutter your notification box.

Lastly, your title doesn't match your question *at all*.

Comment: where exactly did I change any meaning of original answer? I just added sample code for it. Please read again my change.

Comment: and not, I don't expect people doing changes and getting rejections all the time to clutter their inbox. By making rejection silent information is eventually lost and bad moderation (bad actions or wrong system that needs rethinking and fixing) doesn't surface. E.g. at comments above I get told that original author isn't notified about change to accept/downvote it. How come? They should be the go-to authority to accept such changes, not some moderators that are ignorant in the subject. Moreover, why do people moderate subjects they're ignorant about? That shouldn't be done in the first place

Comment: @GeorgeBirbilis Edits mostly get reviewed by community members. Three equal decisions result in that action being taken as consensus => 3x Approve, 1x Reject leads to Approval. You can see if your edit was rejected/approved under "Activity" -> "All Actions" -> "Revisions".

Comment: that's what I call moderation (or reviewing in this case, didn't know the distinction here) hell - a crowd of people not knowing a subject voting against an expert's text

Comment: btw, see some suggestions on how to fix this system at discussion under the question above

Comment: the title matches my concern, it's not about the specific rejection, it's about the system that results in rejections in the first place

Comment: ...and the downrated part in the question title is more of a suggestion - voting on moderation/reviewing actions would mean such actions could be monitored (or maybe if there is some automated system to flag bad reviews if a moderator reverses review or something). I mean to have reviewers with more power in the system (due to not downvoted past actions). Maybe moderators only could downvote such actions of reviewers to avoid revenge voting