# Should we flag "look at my answer" comments?

Tags: discussion

I sometimes see *"ooh, ooh, look at me, look at me"* comments, where a user who has posted an answer then posts a comment under the question to the effect of *"hey, look at my answer I posted below, I think it'll help you!"* Random sample:

> @user3467855 try my suggestion. might work for you.

"My suggestion" here refers to an answer the user posted just a few pixels below. That's it. No further context, no links, nothing. What do we do with those? Sometimes they're clogging up a rather lengthy comment thread while adding absolutely nothing of value. Should we flag those as "too chatty"?

Comment: On the other hand, they're a great signal for a duplicate question.

Comment: @dilbert How so?

Comment: As you've probably seen, there is an ongoing [discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252561/more-effective-closing-downvoting-of-junk-questions-to-help-with-the-signal-no) about poor question quality. If a Machine Learning algorithm were used to determine a likelihood of poor question quality, a question which contains a link to an answer (along with phrases like: "try this", "check out my answer", etc.) could be used as a trigger. This would turn the repwhore into an informant.

Comment: @dilbert Answers and the corresponding questions with such comments indeed tend to be rather low quality and it could probably be used as an indicator, yes. I'm confused by your original statement about *duplicate* questions however; they're not really pointing at duplicates per se.

Comment: If a new question can be answered by a pre-existing answer (in this case, mentioned in the comments), then it must, by definition, be a duplicate of the corresponding question to the pre-existing answer.

Comment: @dilbert The case I'm talking about is when a comment points to an answer **within the same "thread"**. The commenter is just needlessly advertising that he posted an answer to the question in the same page below. I'm not talking about cross-promotion of different duplicates. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23511157/warning-in-header-function#comment36059768_23511157 (don't know how long that comment will stay there...)

Comment: Oh god ... I didn't know that was a thing. I guess Machine Learning won't go far enough; Orbital Ion cannon it is then.

Comment: Flag as not constructive.  Ofttimes when I do this the comment goes poof immediately. Go democracy.

Comment: I have a confession. I've actually done this sort of thing a few times. **Oh Gosh! I R TERRIBLE PERSON!!!** @dilbert, don't shoot Cupcake with UR geeky space gun plz!!!

Comment: But its not a Cupcake if it hasn't been baked ....

Comment: @dilbert I've seen Cupcake's writing and it's clear that he's completely baked already.

Comment: Looks like we don't need to flag those comments anymore. Usually they are quickly dissapearing by just adding a comment with a link to this post ; ).

Comment: *Look mommy, LOOK LOOK, look at what I can do!!!* - Pathetic.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

[Yes, absolutely](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202109/flagging-look-at-my-answer-pls-comments/202111#202111). They're annoying and the OP already gets a notification anyway when an answer is posted to their question.

I asked a very similar question, to which BoltClock replied:

> If you posted your answer, somebody is bound to see it. There isn't
>   much of a point announcing your answer, it just creates a needless
>   distraction *before* someone even gets a chance to see your answer,
>   and at worst it'll even discourage someone from looking at your answer
>   (for reasons like what Da_smokes said, they smell like rep-whoring).
>
> You can flag such comments as not constructive or too chatty.
>
> I do post such a comment if I think I have a good reason to call
>   attention to my answer, for instance if I believe the existing answers
>   are misleading or wrong despite having received upvotes:
>
> > Note that many of the answers here miss a certain important point [explain what that is], which I've addressed in an answer of my own.
>
> but that doesn't mean if I don't comment, nobody will see my answer.
>
> At the end of the day, it's all about whether a comment adds any
>   useful information to the topic at hand. If it doesn't, it's noise and
>   it doesn't need to be there.

Comment: Just flagging seems too inconsequential. I don't think that will really change user behaviour. I suggest a new 'badge' ... the Repwhore. A user receives it when flagged for self-promotion in the same question (maybe a new flag reason, and icon, needs to be added for this to work).

Comment: @dilbert: Please, no badge for that. Half the new users will want one of those for themselves and will just spam those comments until they get their hearts desire. Still, +1, hoping it was satirical.

Comment: Hmmm... can we have *anti-badges*?

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher - I like the suggestion. A "black badge" might be the thing. Earning N black badges in time interval T would generate a time-out of sorts. And while you have an "active" black badge, your other badges become invisible to the community. It would automatically decay - first one after 1 week, second one after 2, third after 4, ... "rep-whore deterrent".

Comment: People will vye for these "black badges" or "rep whore" badges. It would become comical, because we have a bunch of sick and twisted people here

Comment: @Floris I like the idea of having badges invisible while the user has an anti-badge (it annihilates regular badges, if you will, just like physics!).

Comment: @staticx - your black badge would not be visible to anyone but yourself. It would be "silent shame" - so nothing to boast about, just an indication that you are losing privileges. Let it be the sicko honeypot - they will be out of here fast.

Comment: I disagree with you. Sometimes OP accepts wrong answer (it solves current problem only and will generate other problems later). You should draw OP's attention, as well as other future users, to you answer in such cases.

Comment: @Floris, I don't know that it should be *totally* private. It's quite clear that these people don't have a concept of shame. Maybe they could have a form of CSS punishment on their posts (visible to everyone else) like, yellow text on white background or variable letter sizes, wingdings, etc. Also, a more creative graphic perhaps a "W" to the left of an anchor.

Comment: @dilbert did you really just say what I think you said? Worthy of the joke/ "what do you call a collection of bankers? A wunch." But again that kind of flair might become a perverse badge of honor. Strip'em and leave'em without.

Comment: @Floris, well, that leaves us with the punishment CSS.