# Should '@user check my update' comments on answers be flagged as too chatty

Tags: discussion, flags, comments

In [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253833/should-we-flag-look-at-my-answer-comments) question the point is about comments on *questions* where users try and raise attention to an answer they just posted. This is not encouraged, and I agree fully.

There is also lots of comments on *answers* though where the comment is mostly a `@user check updated answer` so that it will popup a notification.

The usefulness of those is debatable but I think they *are* useful. When reviewing a bad question I downvoted I'm happy that the user will notify me that he updated his text so that I can remove my downvote, or comment further.

Also, in [this removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24963631/html-onclick-button-not-working/24963715#24963715) question where an answer of mine was quite bad my `@user` comments indicating my updates allowed to get a higher rep attention long enough for him to help me understand my confusion. Or maybe he would have checked afterwise anyway, I'll never know, but for now I assume without my comment he would not have looked back and I would have stayed in the dark.

However, I find myself flagging a lot of these 'useful' comments because after a day, they are pretty much too chatty.

Should we:

- Have a notification when a post you commented/voted on get updated? (this could generate way too much noise in my inbox though)
- Follow up on our downvotes and comments?
- Just accept that those comments are also just noise that should not be commented in the first place?

Comment: Does one comment really meet the threshold of "chatty?"  Does a mod *actually* have to come in and do something about it?  Ugh, chatty comment flags.

Comment: @Will Yeah, one comment such as 'thanks guy' or 'me too' is easily in the threshold of chatty, is it not? Now for the mod to have to come and do something about is another concern, here it's wether we flag them or not. if the 'too chatty' comment offends you you're welcome to propose for it's disappearance.

Comment: I always considered "too chatty" to mean just that--you keep getting pinged in the inbox because someone is going on and on about nothing in particular.  That takes more than one comment...

Comment: oh.. yeah, chatty does refer to some kind of chat, which a comment section is not.. maybe we could flag comments as plain noise then, instead as too chatty?

Comment: "noise" and "chatty" are pretty much synonymous in this case.  But again, a single comment I wouldn't consider noisy...

Comment: Why should they be flagged? The placeholder for a comment says: "Use comments ... to notify [other users] of changes."

Comment: @Teemu That text shouldn't be misinterpreted to just plainly notify; rather it means to explain what exactly was added/edited (other than also doing it in the edit summary).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the `@user check my update` comment is more than a day or so old, then it is obsolete.  They serve a useful purpose in the short term — I have even requested that a user create one to let me know I need to come back and see their revised question (usually) or answer.  But after I've come back and seen it, the comment is obsolete, and I flag it as such.  But I flag it with a custom reason that starts 'Obsolete' and then gives an explanation of why.

For example, I recently flagged two comments to a single question:

- Obsolete: I've seen the update, and changed my answer and added comments as a result of seeing it.
- Obsolete: a comment in response to a difficult to parse comment of mine which I have since deleted. My following comments serve some purpose (the first one barely since the info is in the answer).

Both have been deemed helpful.  Note that the first of these is flagging a `@JonathanLeffler: check my update` comment, but I flagged it minutes after it was posted rather than waiting for a day.  If the comment addresses someone else, leaving it a day or so is reasonable, unless there's evidence that the user did see the comment (another comment from the addressed user, or a change to an answer that recognizes the changed question, or something similar).

(Just for the record, 18 of my last 24 flagged comments started 'Obsolete'.  The others were a 'spam', two 'not an answer', a 'not constructive', and two 'rude or offensive'.)

Comment: Maybe it'd be useful to be able to have a type of comment which is temporary. Which you could flag as autodelete after the OP has visited his question and seen your comment (or answer), or which for which you decide an obsolescence threshold when you first post the comment.

Comment: Comments that are deleted within hours (or minutes, I think) will trigger an inbox notification that will still stay even if the comment gets deleted.

Comment: @yu_ominae: Or maybe a `@@`username ping, which *shares* ownership of the comment with the other user (either one can delete it)

Comment: @yu_ominae: that would complicate the existing, deliberately rather minimal, comment system.  And deciding on thresholds, and whether the person addressed has seen the comment, is not necessarily trivial.  It is probably just busy-work — but a member of the Stack Overflow team would have to pontificate on that.  It's not necessarily a bad idea; it may be more work than they're willing to undertake, though.

Comment: @BenVoigt: that's a nice simple system...could be effective and not very hard to implement.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, I agree with that. It's just that I realised through reading this thread that I have been guilty of being overly chatty too and have left quite a few such comments behind... It would be nice to have an auto-tidyup feature.

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi: I believe there is some period during which an inbox notification remains even after a comment is deleted, but it is not all that long, and trying to go to a deleted notification leads to confusion.

Comment: @Jon Yes, but one can look at the time that the post was last edited and the ones they commented on to determine which one is the one that was edited.

Comment: Sharing ownership of comments sounds like it would require a database schema change (or at least a new table and some shenanigans with the Community user).