# When did I get close-vote superpowers?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions, tag-badges, dupehammer

I just marked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23616682/mysql-check-that-value-does-not-match-multiple-values?noredirect=1) as a duplicate all by myself. I am not a moderator and I don't think this should be possible.

Did I miss something?

Comment: So who has a gold badge in "vote-to-close" on Meta, to close all the duplicates of this question?

Comment: Related on MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231504/how-do-i-opt-out-of-privileges/231505#231505

Comment: I've my 1x bronze badge on Meta and darned proud of it too! Is this like the code Olympics? ;-)

Comment: Wait a minute, I've a "Silver", not bronze. It just gets better all the time. Momma would be proud *'er*.

Comment: how is this an event that ends in 7 days?

Comment: @eis Perhaps that's the only way to keep a notice in the bulletin for several days?

Comment: @AndrewS Why not just edit them and re-tag to anything you do have a gold badge in?

Comment: @Duncan possibly, though haven't seen it mentioned anywhere.

Comment: All I can say is that my motivation for acquiring a gold badge for certain tags has increased manifold with the superpowers that come along now.

Comment: @J... It is based on the tags from the first revision so re-tagging won't work.

Comment: @Jack Good to know.  At least that is sensible.

Comment: I wish people had to have at least a bronze badge in one of the tags in the question to be able to vote to close it.

Comment: @Akavall: When the initial tags are all obscure or nonsense, that doesn't work so well.

Comment: @Jack That's unfortunate.  I had a question earlier that had all the wrong tags on it:  they tagged it with all of the technologies involved *except* the one where the problem was (which is the one I have gold in) :-(.  The only other tag that could relevant to the problem doesn't have a single user with a gold.

Comment: @cimmanon I think it's a problem they are aware of but doing it on all revisions or the last revision allows more potential abuse. There was a [suggestion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders/231212#comment760794_231212) that maybe it should include all edits by the OP.

Comment: Do keep the consequences in mind, it isn't just "stackoverflow sucks" anymore, it is *you* that sucks.  Do expect revenge downvotes, they'll pick your favorite posts of course.  Afaik you can't lose the gold badge by those votes.

Comment: Indeed, revenge downvotes are inevitable. But that is a price I'm willing to pay. Now if only we can get gold badge holders the ability to close questions as off-topic, we could really start making some difference in the signal-to-noise ratio...

Comment: @user2357112 in that case, just edit the question to add a tag you have a badge in, then close... And just about everyone can add tags. Thus requiring a badge related to a specific tag is utterly useless.

Comment: @jwenting As mentioned above in the comments, you can not retag to get the superpower.

Answer (score 439, accepted):

Yes, you are now a Superhero, able to wield [the mighty Mjölnir](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders/231212#231212).

[image: question marked as duplicate immediately because Jack has the JavaScript gold badge]

The rules are:

- You can instantly close any question *as a duplicate* that was originally asked with a tag you have a gold badge for.
- You can instantly reopen any question *closed as a duplicate* that was originally asked with a tag you have a gold badge for.
- You can instantly close/reopen any question *as a duplicate* that currently contains a tag you have a gold badge for, unless you were the one that edited them in.
- You can only close or reopen a given question *once* (this hasn't changed).
- If you get in a fight with someone over whether a question should be closed, moderators will be notified and they'll <s>hit everyone with hammers</s> lock everything down and tell you to go home.

Remember: duplicates are questions that *ask for a solution to fundamentally identical problems* - many questions have similar or identical *answers* but are not duplicates. By the same token, many questions are asked using *very* different wordings but seek to solve identical questions - closing these helps folks find their way to a solution even when they don't know what terms to search for.

**GO FORTH AND USE YOUR NEW POWERS FOR GOOD!**

Comment: Hmmm, I was surprised to see my new superpower and am now thinking I will have to vote to close more carefully if I am now a sole decider.  When I've had my own question closed by a single person (a moderator at the time), I was a bit miffed that it didn't require at least a few souls thinking the same way.  It will be interesting to see how this goes.  On the other side of things, I am glad that more questions which are clearly dups will now get the right action.

Comment: @jfriend00 the rationale is that you should only have been voting to close as a duplicate if you *were sure* it was a duplicate to begin with. So, if you're not sure - same methodology applies that you shouldn't be voting. Hopefully it'll stop obvious duplicates lingering and potentially not getting closed - it's a trail run - guess we'll see how it goes :)

Comment: I wonder if the gold badge is a bit restrictive for low-activity tags.  A gold badge requires total score of 1000 in at least 200 answers.  In low activity tags, it's easy to get well over 200 answers, and still far less than 1000 score.  I don't really have a solution proposal either, though.

Comment: You're correct: this is not particularly helpful for niche tags, @Joshua. We have other plans in the works that should help there, but hopefully this change will reduce some of the backlog and let smaller topics get more visibility.

Comment: @Shog9 Glad to hear it!  I think it might help a lot in the niche tags, because the fact that questions are answered by a smaller number of users means that awareness of the duplicates is higher (i.e., the *answerer* of the original recognizes the duplicate).  At the same time, fewer users means that the close votes come much more slowly.

Comment: @JonClements - that makes sense.  It's just that when you suddenly have 5 times more power than you used to and can unilaterally close something, that greater responsibility makes me think that I need to vote even more cautiously.  There is still a significant gray area for duplicates, particularly when the question/code presented is different, but the solution is the exact same as other questions.  I will certainly still mark dups, but I will probably comment as "possible dup" more often than before and see if there are others who think the same.  Not complaining, just adapting a bit.

Comment: Just a small note: unless I'm missing something, there doesn't appear to be any change to the UI that would alert someone that the close vote they're about to cast is going to be binding. I know of one person that was caught off guard by that already. I realize that everyone should be using the same amount of caution anyway, but I was sort of expecting a more direct warning than a Meta post.

Comment: _"We have other plans in the works"_ - are they secret?

Comment: I'd like to tell you I'm not using you all as guinea pigs to see how you behave in this situation, @joran... But that's pretty much what's happening. If folks don't screw it up with no forewarning, we'll talk about it more in a few days - until then, Robert added this post to the event board.

Comment: @Peter: not really. Like almost everything that gets done, it's been talked about on [meta.se] for years.

Comment: @Shog9 Cool. Hopefully we make [Uncle Ben](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncle_Ben) proud. :)

Comment: Pretty much everything has been talked about on Meta, but there's a massive huge lot of it (not to mention two places to look now), so it's not easy to keep track of what may or not be happening - was curious if there might be a list.

Comment: What about my dupe close votes in the queue? Will they be taken to effect immediately as well (reducing the queue size)?

Comment: We're not making this retroactive at this time, @Bergi.

Comment: Sorry, @Peter - nope. Only solution is to read everything that everyone's ever written. I'd recommend starting with [Pekka](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/138112/pekka).

Comment: _Everything?_ Aww, I'm gonna need a bigger candle...

Comment: Wow! I can’t wait to try th… oh.

Comment: *"GO FORTH AND USE YOUR NEW POWERS FOR GOOD!"* ... and not for "evil".

Comment: This seems a bit extreme to me. I personally feel that it should count as 3 close votes instead of 5 (and 3 reopen votes). This way, there needs to be enough people who agree.

Comment: What's "enough", @quincunx? There are 1.8k gold badge holders, 4k active 10k users, a few hundred thousand active users... What does 2 or three votes tell you about "agreement"? Close voting exists to prevent abuse, not establish consensus.

Comment: @Shog9 Good point. I guess reopening really isn't that hard if someone closes in error.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I'm not sure if so-called low-activity tags are actually at a disadvantage. I think you have some of those tags, and you seem to have very good answer-to-upvote ratio, a lot better than I've seen for most people contributing to high activity tags (myself included). Having 1000 upvotes with (just) 200 answers is rare for any tag, not just low activity ones.

Comment: Just a little question, suppose a question has `> 1` tags and I achieved gold in just one of them, would this privilege still work?

Comment: "duplicates are questions that ask for a solution to fundamentally identical problems - many questions have similar or identical answers but are not duplicates." -- I agree, but that's not what the text says when closing a question as a duplicate (nor the text after closing). Those texts implies that a question should *never* be closed as a duplicate of an unanswered question, and that it is a duplicate if any of the *answers* on the other question match. I'm referring to "This question has been asked before and already has an answer." and "This question already has an answer here:"

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor, php and mySql are not niche tags, they are also a large part of the problem sucking in duplicate questions faster then the current system can cope with.   I expect that niche tags don't get 2 or 3 answers to a duplicate question within minutes of the question being posted.

Comment: +1 This is a great idea. It seems quite right for a privilege to be associated with the very challenging achievement of reaching gold status on a tag.

Comment: @hjpotter92 Yes, you need a gold badge in just one of the tags it seems. If you think about it, the system wouldn't work well otherwise - it would only function on one-tag questions (or for the Jon Skeet's of this world).

Comment: @Shog9 Are these uber-votes constrained by the normal daily vote limits?

Comment: @IanRingrose Perhaps I'm reading your comment wrong, but I don't think I said anything to suggest that php and my-sql are niche tags.  I can certainly see the advantage of this behavior in those tags.  I'm just a little sad that I'm the top answerer in [tag:sparql] and [tag:rdf] at the moment, so I recognize a lot of dupes pretty quickly, but still have a hard time getting them closed because of low traffic in the tag.  Similarly, it looks like only one in the top ten of [tag:lisp] and [tag:common-lisp] will be able to use this.

Comment: @Duncan Yes. The only change was to the strength of these votes, not to the total number of votes per day allocated for each user.

Comment: Aha, its increased overall vote power in a way anyway. If you take 5 people, yesterday they were able to close only 40 questions, but now they can close as much as 200! Good news.

Comment: @Shog9 is there any reputation requirement for this, aside from the gold badge and the ability to close questions?

Comment: @vcsjones: Gold tag badges already have a rep requirement.

Comment: No, @vcsjones. Pretty hard to get the badge without earning at least 10K, but for the folks who managed it, more power to 'em.

Comment: they'll hit everyone with hammers..! Ha ha..!! :) GO FORTH AND USE YOUR NEW POWERS FOR GOOD! I'm impressed..! :)

Comment: @Your Common Sense: That reminds me of the "5 hens lay 5 eggs in 5 days" math joke.

Comment: @Shog9 glad to hear you're also thinking about something for niche-tags. Lately I've found myself in a situation that I had to flag a post for mod attention to reopen it. I always feel like I'm bothering the mighty mods too much when flagging for these purposes :p
Maybe you could use the top answerers list to recognize tag-"superheroes" (like you called them).

Comment: This power is truly unlimited: If you want to close/reopen a post, simply edit it, add a tag you have gold in, open/close it, then edit it to remove the tag.  Bwahahahahahahahaha ha ha heh.

Comment: This in itself might be a good idea. But why is it a good idea to have made this surprising change without notifying people?

Comment: Yeah, we did think of that, @Yakk. Only *initial* tags count...

Comment: @Shog9 If this an experimental feature?  I'm asking so because this question appears as an _event that ends in 5 days_.

Comment: It's definitely experimental, @devnull.

Comment: @Shog9 So you guys shall do some sort of analysis for the data over the week or something?  Giving people power _temporarily_ seems evil.

Comment: Whether or not it's temporary depends on how it's used... But yeah, we'll talk more about this next week @dev.

Comment: Power corrupts, absolute power corrupts absolutely. I have already reevaluated a duplicate vote of my own, and objected to a duplicate vote by another as it was not sufficiently on topic and appeared to be a means of promoting a previous answer, not necessarily a bad thing, if it was an accurate answer.

Comment: **[Potential Abuse Warning]** Can anyone verify that if a question does not have a tag that you have a gold badge for, and you edit in a tag in which you have a gold badge for, will you be able to then single-handedly close the question after that? @Shog9

Comment: @SamuelLiew If you backread a little further you'll see [this response](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254589/when-did-i-get-close-vote-superpowers?cb=1#comment21119_254590).

Comment: @Shog9 Only initial tags count, or only tags that were there before <magic gold close voter> posted? How will this interact with improperly tagged questions, or questions missing appropriate tags? For example, if the original post was missing a language tag, or if someone is porting from lang-x to lang-y and tagged it only lang-x.

Comment: Only initial tags, @thegrinner. Based on my previous analysis of the available data, the actual cost will be small - though of course, there will be some that fall through the cracks and require the usual 5 votes.

Comment: One issue that I just ran into that might be worth considering is that if the OP edits the question, it gets bumped to the reopen queue without much clear indication that the Q was closed as a dupe (I think). I had closed a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23679925/revisions), the OP edited without meaningfully changing the question, and 5 non-tag experts reopened since the question itself was perfectly fine, it was just a dupe. Might be an edge case, but thought I'd mention it.

Comment: Well, this is not a complete idea... I mean, there are tags e.g. the qt with about 30K questions without people having golden badges. Still, it is a significant tag IMHO. What we might see C++ "gurus" coming to the qt badge knowing not so much about it and closing, and the actual qt "gurus" will not have even the same power. That scenario sounds unfair.

Comment: Is it Stack Overflow only feature? If no then why don't you move it to the Meta Stack Exchange?

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders/231212#231212 @hims056

Comment: @Shog9 and what if gold badge holder repeatedly closes questions as duplicates because they are on similar topic but problem is actually different and solution does not solve the problem.

Comment: Same thing that happens if a question gets closed incorrectly in any other scenario, @dkozl. If you have a specific situation in mind here, you might want to start a new discussion.

Comment: I hate this superpower. People now making duplicate without thinking much on question. I was suspect of this superpower. And no moderator looks for that question.

Comment: Please [refer to your discussion here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261096/users-with-the-c-gold-badge-can-single-handely-mark-c-question-as-duplicates), @AnkushMadankar - your question as it stands is clearly a duplicate; if you disagree, you'll need to edit it to differentiate your needs from those described in the previous question.

Comment: is this still valid? I was unable to use my powers on this http://stackoverflow.com/q/25050636/1771795

Comment: Why is a single user allowed to close a question but 5 must be required to reopen it? Is that really fair?

Comment: Same rules apply to reopen, @mcadam

Comment: @shog9 in the sense that someone with the gold badge can reopen it by themselves?

Comment: You know... This is all covered in the answer you're commenting on, @mcadam

Comment: Is there a way to use a gold badge for cleaning up (deleting) answers in that tag?

Comment: 'hit everyone with hammers' lol

Comment: "many questions have similar or identical answers but are not duplicates." This seems to contradict other advice I've seen on Meta about criteria for identifying dupes.

Answer (score 26):

It seems that this doesn't work in the simplest manner possible.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17017040/nullreferenceexception-system-text-encoding-ascii-getbytes) was originally tagged [vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb.net) and [nullreferenceexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nullreferenceexception). I do not have a gold badge in either one. But I felt that the question was general enough that it should also be tagged [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net). So I added the new tag, and performed an experiment. I opened the question again in a new browser window, and tried to close it as a duplicate. My close vote was counted, but it was only a "normal" close vote.

What is the algorithm for determining whether the question is eligible for super-closing by the current user. It doesn't seem to depend on the set of tags which are current when the close vote is cast.

Comment: It's the original set of tags.

Comment: Ok, so edits won't change that "original set"?

Comment: Correct. Sure it's suboptimal, but it's the current way of preventing abuse.

Comment: @Mysticial: I can see the potential for abuse - but really, are we going to mistrust our gold badge holders that much? Especially since new users often don't understand the tagging system yet. How about allowing "gold badgers" to close based only on tags they haven't added themselves?

Comment: @TimPietzcker I can understand erring on the side of caution. High-rep wonder-users can often disappoint with their behaviour. In the current design, worst case scenario is that they cast the first of hopefully 5 close votes.