# Provide visual prompts to actions of regular users when they exercise superpowers

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, vote-to-close, dupehammer

This is a follow-up to [this new feature](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254589/335858). Now that regular users can close questions with a single vote, it would be great to have some visual indicator that the action is applied as a superpower action.

For example, showing a red border around the [Close] button in the "Vote to Close" dialog, or providing a bright red title that tells that the question would be closed instantaneously would be a helpful reminder of the greater responsibility.

I think this is a nice feature to have, because the superpower is on the tag-by-tag basis.

> *With great power comes great responsibility*
>
> <sub>Uncle Ben</sub>

---

> Why would you act differently if you have superpowers? We trust you enough, you should trust yourself. [*Sklivvz*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/7028/sklivvz)

Without superpowers, I vote when I am pretty sure the question should get closed. I know that there are four other users who need to agree with my decision - in other words, the site has a safety net protecting it from my mistake.

With superpower activated, I know that the safety net is gone, so I would spend an extra minute making sure that I am not making a mistake.

> If you're not sure that it should be closed, then you shouldn't be voting to close it.

A vote to close as a duplicate has two parts to it: in addition to the vote itself, it includes the supposed duplicate question. When I am casting a non-binding vote, picking the best question for the duplicate is less important, because other members of the community can provide a better one. Knowing that I have superpowers would make me spend an extra minute making sure that I am picking the best duplicate among potential candidates.

Besides, a good user interface should not have non-concurrent "Heisenberg" components: end-user should always know what action is about to be taken, except when the concurrent timing prevents the system from communicating this to the user.

Comment: Do you know that the whole page reloads if you do?

Comment: @Braiam But that happens after you've voted, right?

Comment: Why would you act differently if you have superpowers? We trust you enough, you should trust yourself.

Comment: @Sklivvz That's a great follow-up question, I edited the question to answer this. In general, though, when more than one outcome is possible from a single user action, it's nice to tell the user what exactly is going to happen after he clicks that button.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight The thing to keep in mind is you have the same ability to reopen with a single vote as long as you have the gold badge.  But you can only close/reopen vote once.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: The page reloads immediately when you cast the final vote to show the question is closed. That, coupled with the single-reopen vote ability bluefeet mentions should give you a) the notice you ask for, and b) the ability to back out.

Comment: Heck, I might make a userscript for this if I could figure out how to know what gold badges a user has.

Comment: How about an "I'm not sure" checkbox which would make your vote be normal?

Comment: I think the same premise applies here as the reason why moderators *aren't* allowed to cast non-binding votes. If you're not sure that it should be closed, then you shouldn't be voting to close it. The same thing can easily apply to any regular user. Really, all users *should* follow that premise. Pretend your vote is the only one that counts and vote accordingly. I don't like that people rely on the fact that it will take four more votes for theirs to take effect, and their vote doesn't mean as much.

Comment: [I asked for this on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231625/147247) and suggested a gold badge symbol on the vote-to-close button as a reminder. It's not that I won't VTC if I have powers, but just that it startled me and for a moment I felt rude. I just want to be reminded what I am doing.

Answer (score 8):

> in other words, the site has a safety net protecting it from my mistake.

Not if everyone thinks that way. You cast the first vote expecting 4 others to sanity-check your decision, and 4 others cast their votes each assuming the previous voter(s) have done their homework. I'm not making this up; there are folks who try to *only* cast the 5th close vote.

So the more I think about this idea, the less I like it. *All* of your close votes matter. And *all* of your close votes are subject to review.

I sincerely hope you take it seriously and use your votes - all of them - wisely. But if you don't care to do that, then don't - participation in moderation is entirely optional.

Comment: I think banging on about how careful closevoters *should* be rather misses the point. The fact of the matter is not *all* of us are *always* going to be that careful. I personally have been closevoting on ELU for over 3 years - if I'm the first one, there will be plenty of time for someone to contest my (invariably, *commented*) vote, which for some time now I've been able to rescind. If I'm the *last* one, I can see that, so I take more care. All we're asking for here is an onscreen indication of ***unexpectedly greater than usual consequences***. Saying "be more careful" doesn't help.

Comment: What would you do if all of your close votes had immediate effects, @FumbleFingers? P.S.: this is Stack Overflow's meta; if you're interested in discussing this in the context of the entire network, you might want to check out [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231625/please-remind-me-when-i-am-wielding-the-dupe-hammer).

Comment: It's only becoming clear to me *now* that my superpower only applies to *duplicate* VTCs. I can remember that easily enough, *now I know*, but I would just point out that I knew none of this until I unexpectedly found I'd unilaterally closed a Q on ELU (where I had to ask what was going on on meta). The power will remain somewhat "random" to me, since I'm not going to keep checking to find out if I happen to have the necessary status for any tags on the question.

Comment: To be honest, unless I could have notification *at the time* saying whether the superpower applies, I'd rather not have it at all. I just don't understand how a problem as serious as this wasn't foreseen and programmed for when the facility was introduced - and I *really* don't understand why it hasn't immediately been accepted once it's pointed out. The fact that *most* people with the power might not see it as problematic doesn't detract from the difficulties it poses for people in my position.

Comment: If the power applied to *all* dup VTCs (or all VTCs for all reasons) I wouldn't have a problem. I'd simply take more care than I do right now when casting the first (or an *early*) VTC. Sometimes I might not bother VTCing at all, because I wouldn't always have the time & inclination to apply that extra care, but at least I'd be in control if the system was ***predictable***. And currently to me it ***isn't***.

Comment: Unforeseen? No, @Fumble, I expected this - I've been having the same argument with moderators for years. The mistake you're making is in thinking that normal vote-to-close is predictable.

Comment: You say in your linked SE meta answer that you're "philosophically" against letting us know our "context-specific status", but I certainly don't understand *why*. It also seems totally inconsistent with the fact that we're told how many other people have VTC'd (which clearly affects what happens next if that number is already ***four***). If the only reason for your "philosophical" position is you think it serves me right for being "careless", I frankly think that's patronising. If you have a more meaningful justification, I'm not aware of it yet.

Comment: **Philosophically,** the notion of voting without conviction disgusts me; it doesn't "serve you right", it serves all of us wrong. If your only reason for voting is that you're not #5, then *stop voting altogether!* Votes can be added and removed at any time by voters or by the system itself; what you intend to be #3 could become the *effective* #1 or #5, and *you have no control over this*. It is ironic that folks are saying they're more careful when they know their vote is binding: anyone casting a binding vote can *completely undo the damage*, but in many cases they cannot for normal votes.

Comment: The suggestion that my *only reason for voting is that I'm not #5* is a grossly misleading caricature. Also, I realise that because of your position within SE it's quite likely you're more idealistic about how much effort closevoters in general put into making absolutely certain they're right before they VTC. But I don't see how your abhorrence of "voting without conviction" (another gross oversimplification) should automatically lead to the notion that this "notification" feature request lacks merit.

Comment: You *admit as much* in [your answer here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231625/please-remind-me-when-i-am-wielding-the-dupe-hammer/233746#233746), @Fumble. And with that, I'm going to take this conversation to a different meta, as I suspect your specific concerns have little connection to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 5):

The only existing answer here doesn't really address the problem at all.

I just discovered I have the ability to unilaterally close [some] questions on [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/). The particular question where this came to light was arguably "marginal" (I don't know, because I've specifically avoided looking *too* closely into it for the time being).

The fact of the matter is if I know *my vote alone* may close a question, I'm actually less likely to cast it at all. In general, I simply won't have the time or inclination to check and establish...

> 1: Is this question tagged with some category for which I have a gold badge?
>    2: Am I 100% certain I can defend my vote to close, under close scrutiny?
>    3: Did I cite the most suitable duplicate?

That last point may not be so significant on all SO sites, but I would just mention that the site search facilities don't work at all well on ELU, because many of the "words" we're interested in aren't actually *indexed* (they're ignored as "noise words" by the standard system). Finding dups isn't always easy.

I think if TPTB can't arrange for a clear visual indication that my closevote will be *unilaterally* actioned, either the facility should be withdrawn, or I want some mechanism to relinquish my unwanted power.

Comment: Most of the time, you won't be asked to defend your vote. But if you are, you should be able to *in every case* - I cannot properly comprehend the mindset that would lead you to think you are not abusing the system by casting indefensible votes. I'll address the rest of your concerns on EL&U's meta.

Comment: Finding a good duplicate can be difficult. E.g., under the SQL tag, a common question is "How do I get rid of duplicate rows in this JOIN query?" A day or so ago, I found something over 2300 questions about "join duplicate rows" under that tag. I suppose I **could** have found one that that was close to a 'best' duplicate...

Comment: @Shog9: I find the implications of your comment disappointing. Firstly, you've twisted my words to imply I might deliberately adopt positions which I know are indefensible. Secondly, and more importantly, if you don't comprehend the mindset of someone who admits he might make mistakes, that does rather suggest *you personally* are not easily able to change your mind when faced with different perspectives or new information. I'm not saying your initial thinking is any more or less likely to be wrong in any given context, but you can see where this dogmatic approach leads in the long run.

Comment: There's a difference between believing you are correct, being willing to explain/justify your decisions... And just being stubborn. If you aren't willing to defend your decision, then what opportunity do you leave for others to point out an error? We all make mistakes; the system allows them to be corrected. But if you are unwilling to stand behind your decisions, you abdicate the responsibility for your mistakes as well.

Comment: @Shog9: Yet again you massively exaggerate my position in order to knock it down. I'm always "willing" to stand behind my decisions - but equally, I'm always prepared to realise later (perhaps, by being persuaded) that I made a bad call. I get the feeling some users on ELU might classify me as a bit "intransigent", but by comparison you seem unwilling to budge an inch. I've accepted that in the final analysis you call the shots in respect of "no notification", despite not providing what I would call adequate justification. You seem unwilling to concede I've even got a point in the first place.

Answer (score -2):

Normally if you are not sure if another question is a duplicate then you should not be voting to close as a duplicate.

However a good case can be made that we still wish benefit from the information that a question may be a duplicate.

Therefore can we have a formal way that **any** users can indicate a “possible duplicate” without cashing a close vote?    This can be done with comment at present, however these don’t feed into any sort of review queue.

Comment: `Normally ... you should not be voting to close as a duplicate.` I frequently VTC as a duplicate when I _know_ it's a duplicate even if I can't find the best duplicate to point at and add "(or one of the many other duplicates)". If I had super powers I'd either spend the time to find "the" duplicate or give up and not VTC at all until someone else provided a better duplicate than I found myself. `a formal way that any` - that _is_ writing a comment. If it's more formal than a comment it's a close vote, something in between just adds complexity.

Comment: This alone is a good idea. You should consider breaking it out.

Comment: The problem isn't that I am not sure I'm doing the right thing. The problem is that it might be a _mistake_, even if I _am_ sure of myself! That happens! But a closure is so much more final than, say, adding an answer that turns out to be totally wrong. The latter is easily deleted.