# Isn't dupehammer active for every user with gold badge?

Tags: support, dupehammer

I just saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25159493/short-code-for-application-wide-keyboard-events-in-c) closed as duplicate. Close votes has been casted by Hans Passant and Sriram Sakthivel:

[image: detail of banner of "marked as duplicate"]

There is something strange: Sriram has a gold badge near his name (because it has a gold badge for C#) the question has been correctly closed as dup with its vote but also Hans has such badge...shouldn't question be closed immediately when Hans first voted?

Comment: I noticed it too. Maybe Hans' hammer is broken?

Comment: [tag:winforms] tag where Hans has a hammer was [not in the original revision](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25159493/revisions); his dupehammer couldn't apply

Comment: @PatrickHofman it's heavy, there is an age it has to be donated to younger guys...

Comment: @gnat: But he does have C# and only the first revision tags apply. But he didn't vote to close as a dupe.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Adriano yes I see now. [tag:c#] should do

Comment: The saddest duplicate I ever did saw. :-c

Comment: @CodyGray well maybe not best one out there, I think this topic has been discussed in [this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254602/provide-visual-prompts-to-actions-of-regular-users-when-they-exercise-superpower?rq=1).

Comment: Uhh, I didn't mean *this* question, I mean the one that Sriram picked.

Comment: @CodyGray me too! I mean: problem of "best duplicate" for dupehammer has been discussed in [that post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254602/provide-visual-prompts-to-actions-of-regular-users-when-they-exercise-superpower?rq=1).

Comment: I can't remember how I voted and can't see it anymore.  The hammer does tend to miss sometimes.  I know it fails if the tag was added later.  In this case, I might have picked a dup that didn't have the [c#] tag.

Comment: @Hans: the tags on the post you are voting on count; the dupe target tags do not.

Comment: @Hans: I've often enough voted as off-topic ('unclear' or 'typo', etc.) only to have someone else dupe-hammer the post after me with the exact same result.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I know a guy who fixes hammers. One time he used a hammer to fix his watch, but for some reason that didn't work...

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Hans did not vote to close as a duplicate. He must've picked a **different** option.

He is only listed as someone who voted to close, and only Sriram Sakthivel voted to close as a duplicate.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Also remember that the dup-hammer only looks at the **original** tags the question had. It might be that the first voter didn't have an applicable gold badge, but the second one did. Not in this case though.

Comment: @ChrisF There are certain cases where the initial tags of a question don't accurately represent the question, and so the intent of checking only initial tags thus is worked around. Instead, it should check the last revision made by someone else before the closure (with a sufficient rep threshold by that editor to prevent workarounds from sockpuppets).

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi: it doesn't happen all that often; I don't think complicating matters like that would gain all that much.