# What is the process for correcting dupe hammer misuse?

Tags: support, dupehammer

What is the process for correcting dupe hammer misuse?

A gold tag badge holder has closed a question as a duplicate even though the the question cited the duplicate beforehand and stated that the duplicate did not resolve the issue. What action should I take?

Comment: @jww Abuse would be knowingly closing a question as a duplicate when you know its not one, not just mistakenly closing a duplicate incorrectly without realizing it was wrong.

Comment: @Servy:  To play Devil's Advocate, does the procedure for either scenario really change?

Comment: @Makoto Sure.  if you think someone just made a mistake, you can simply correct it and/or discuss it with them in comments.  If someone is actively trolling and going around closing everything just to mess with people, you realistically need to get a mod involved (even if you also reopen the questions).

Comment: If the user can't reopen the question or doesn't have a gold badge in either scenario, I'd argue that the steps don't really change at all.  But the constant is that a mod should only get involved if it's truly an issue.

Comment: @Makoto You should not flag a post just because you think it should be reopened and you cannot vote to reopen.

Comment: I never said anything about flagging for a mod; I said that the steps should remain the same.  The *last* step is to flag for a mod after everything else has been exhausted (per ChrisF).

Comment: @Makoto Personally I disagree with him there.  Realistically step 4 would be go to meta, at which point mods are certain to see it as well as the rest of the community.  Posting on meta is going to result in a resolution one way or another.  If you flag a post saying it should be reopened, it's virtually always going to get declined using the, "the community can handle it" decline reason.

Comment: What question are you referring to? We often see statements such as, "I've checked this citation but it doesn't apply", when in fact it really **does** apply. Also, has the new question provided enough information to tell us why or how his question doesn't apply to the dupe?

Comment: Your definition of *abuse* certainly does matter. What might have been a single mistake (and you've not provided any evidence of one) does not constitute *abuse*. Abuse is intentional misuse of authority, and *one mistake* does not constitute misuse.

Comment: @Ken - *"and you've not provided any evidence of one"* - you're right. I did not present any evidence. I'm interested in the process; and I'm not interested in "trial by meta". I'll make the case in the proper channels.

Comment: @Ken - *"Abuse is intentional misuse of authority, and one mistake does not constitute misuse"* - I claim negligence is misuse or abuse. If someone cannot execute their duties without being negligent, then it is misuse or abuse.

Comment: That's ridiculous. You're expecting someone to be perfect every single time. Calling one mistake *negligence* is ridiculous, unless you've never made a single mistake in your life. (And I can state with absolute certainty that that is not the case, because you've made a mistake here in calling this *abuse*. It's also not *misuse*, as you've edited to use instead.)

Comment: @Makoto - I told you I had lots of fans... 1 close vote for Opinion Based (as if asking for the process has anything to do with opinion), and 3 Unclear What You're Asking (as if there's anything unclear about asking for the process).

Comment: @Ken - if they are casting a close vote, then its a mistake and hopefully the community safeguards will catch it. If they are wielding their hammer and can't be bothered, then it misuse or abuse. The bar is higher when someone wants to act alone as judge and jury.

Comment: No, I'm one of those folks that expects what you complain about to be reflected in the facts you present, and that objects to false accusations and allegations. Sorry if that offends you.

Comment: Using the hammer is a major PITA.  The complaining is *relentless* when an SO user can target a specific user.  I'd estimate the whine rate at about 60% from my personal use.  "Weh, weh, weh, but I'm special and you don't understand what I'm talking about and you completely suck".  Oh, and let's not forget: "you abuse your privileges" if they can spell it.  Weh, weh, weh.  Knock-knock, your question sucks.

Comment: As other commenters have said, while linking to a duplicate shows that you have done *research* (kudos!) it doesn't make it *not a duplicate*. Instead of just saying "It didn't work for me", at *least* indicate what error occurred, what wasn't satisfactory about those answers, etc. No idea if you did that, since I don't know which question you are referring to. As a dupehammer wielder, I put the burden of proof on the asker in proving its not a duplicate, particularly if its a very *close* duplicate. Granted, I have to feel confident before wielding it as well (and I will reopen given reason).

Comment: One other thing I think you have wrong, is that "The bar is higher when someone wants to act alone as judge and jury". Dupehammer wielders have that privilege because they are judged to have sufficient domain knowledge to make the determination without needing confirmation from the community. They aren't choosing to "act alone as judge and jury". Same with community moderators, their votes are binding because we trust them to make the correct decision (mistakes are always made of course). And we even have a balance, *both* can have their decisions reversed by the community.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET - *They aren't choosing to "act alone as judge and jury..."* - it seems there's a difference between theory and practice that some folks don't realize.

Comment: I get what your saying, but they can't "choose" to not have a binding vote, so if they aren't sure, they shouldn't be closing. At the same time, they shouldn't be VTC if they aren't sure **anyways**. So I don't think there actually is a separation, in that they should act the same whether or not the vote is binding.

Comment: ***to a hammer everything looks like a nail***; everything is reversible if the community cares enough ...

Answer (score 17):

If you think your question has been incorrectly closed as a duplicate by a single vote from a gold tag badge holder the procedure is the same as for any closure you don't think is correct:

1. Edit the question constructively - i.e. don't put meta commentary at the top - that will put the question in the re-open review queue where other users can review the closure.
2. Leave a comment addressed to the closer (I'm 100% sure that'll notify them if they've not commented on the post) emphasising the differences - this may be enough to get them to reverse their vote. (Thanks to [Deduplicator](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283502/what-is-the-process-for-correcting-hammer-abuse#comment142359_283503) for that suggestion)
3. Ask in the **appropriate** chat room for subject experts to review the closure and vote to reopen if they agree with you, don't forget another gold badge holder can reopen with a single vote.
4. **As a last resort** flag for moderator attention. We're not necessarily subject experts so we might not be able to judge whether the question is a duplicate or not. This *will* mean that it could take a while for your question to be reopened by moderator action.

This isn't abuse of the system. These users can make mistakes so you must assume good faith and, in the first instance, look to see if you question can be improved. Give  the thousands of eyes that look at Stack Overflow all day everyday there's a good chance that mistakes will be spotted and corrected fairly quickly.

However, if you have noticed a pattern of incorrect closures - which, unless you are going to trawl through a user's actions (and I'm not sure a regular user can even do this) or regularly check the recently closed questions list, isn't easy - *then* you should flag one of the questions with the "other" option explaining your reasoning.

Comment: This would be what you'd do if you saw a question closed as a duplicate that you think should be reopened.  If you think that a user is going around abusing the feature intentionally (i.e. there have been instances of users going around closing tons of questions as duplicates of a single question, just to get them all closed), then this isn't correct.

Comment: @Servy - unless you are following a user you can't be sure of that.

Comment: Sure, which is why if you suspect abuse you should [flag a mod](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/283503/1159478) rather than try to clean it all up yourself.

Comment: Per you're edit, you're effectively saying that it's not possible to even *suspect* abuse.  Considering it took all of like one day for the first major case of abuse of this system, I'd have to disagree with that.  I don't remember the specifics, but someone went around using the dup hammer to vote to close every single question that he felt should have been close for any reason as a dup of the same question.  It was obvious to everyone, mod or not, that it was abuse of the mechanic.

Comment: @Servy - As I said, you would have to be following a user or constantly checking the recently closed list to spot this. Egregious cases such as you mention *are* easy to spot, but most won't be that bad.

Comment: Or you could just both be actively following the same tag and be active at around the same times of day, and thus looking at most of the same questions.  This would be particularly true in a tag that's not quite as huge as one of the top languages.  The idea that you'd *never* be able to notice that one user has made several highly questionable closures in a subject matter that both of you are very familiar with seems quite wrong.  Obviously if you don't notice abuse you can't report that abuse; if you happen to notice it, this is *not* the proper course of action.

Comment: @Servy the question is about a single closure, not a series of them.

Comment: The question is about *abuse* of the dupe hammer.  It says nothing about it being just one closure.

Comment: Your step 4 should probably be just to post a reopen request on meta, rather than to flag.  As a last resort, it's quite effective, and it's pretty certain to be seen by *some* mod, in the event that moderator intervention is needed.  A "please reopen" flag is just so likely to be declined (quite correctly) by a mod regardless of it's merit.

Comment: @ChrisF - forgive my ignorance... Is this an official process from the site? (Please don't take offense).

Answer (score 12):

If there is actual abuse of the feature, Flag for moderator attention.

Your specific example is not abuse, it's just one person closing one question that you think shouldn't be closed.  If you simply see a closed question that you think is incorrectly closed you should not be flagging for mod attention.  You can vote to reopen if you have the privilege.  You can also edit the question to make it clearer why it's not a duplicate (thus putting it in the reopen queue) if you don't have enough rep.  If there is contention over the closure of a post you can also discuss it in comments, or if the discussion becomes particularly lengthy or heated, move the discussion to meta.

Comment: Though my first recourse, the one time I came over a square post someone hammered into a round hole, was just commenting to him. He took a second look and corrected it immediately.

Comment: @Deduplicator There's a difference between a simple mistake, and abuse.  For a simple mistake, you can just reopen and/or comment.  For *abuse* (which is, by definition, intentional) you need to flag.

Comment: Well... yes. If you look at it with an open mind, and presume good intentions. Some will always call it abuse if they disagree (though I rather doubt you or the OP do that).

Comment: @Deduplicator The point is that if you think it's abuse, flag a mod, and let them decide.  You're quite right that we're not here to determine whether some user is being intentionally disruptive; the mods *are*.

Comment: In certain cases, we already get flags from the system for this. I think it's triggered by one gold-badge user closing, another reopening, and a third re-closing. Maybe only just the first two steps.

Comment: *... it's just one person closing one question that you think shouldn't be closed"* - casting a close vote and using the dupe hammer are two different things. In the first case, its a differing opinion and I would not object (lord knows I cast enough lone off-topic close votes in OpenSSL that have nothing to do with programming and development). In the second case, using the hammer to be judge and jury is another matter. Especially in this case since I visited the dup prior to asking, I cited the dup in the question, and stated it did not resolve the issue.

Comment: @jww No, it's not any different at all.  Someone making a mistake when using the dup hammer is not abuse.  It's a mistake with more severe consequences, but the severity of the consequences of an action have no bearing on whether its abuse or a mistake.  It is purely a matter of intent to distinguish the two.

Comment: The dupe hammer works the way it does, @jww, because you're [not intended to be casting close votes unless you're sure of the vote](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258721/), regardless of its effect.

Comment: @jww And as to you mentioning it in the question, I can't count the number of time's I've seen people post a question saying that another question doesn't solve their problem when that exact question solves their exact problem.  I'm not commenting on whether that's the case with your question, but the fact that you included it in your question doesn't automatically mean it's not a duplicate.

Comment: *"I can't count the number of time's I've seen people post a question saying that another question doesn't solve their problem when that exact question solves their exact problem"* - perhaps, but I can tell you for certain it was not the case in this case. I tried the resolutions, and I would not have asked the question if one of them solved my problem.

Comment: @Josh - *"The dupe hammer works the way it does ... because you're not intended to be casting close votes unless you're sure of the vote, regardless of its effect"* - well, it seems that's broken. I don't know why anyone would want that damn thing. Its too much power for one person. I would not want that privilege, and I would opt-out if given the choice.

Comment: @jww That's fine.  If you're right, then it means one person made one mistake and accidentally closed a question incorrectly.  It happens.  That doesn't make it abuse.  It makes it one question mistakenly closed.  You treat it like any other question mistakenly closed question.  Now if the person posts a comment saying, "screw you jww, I'm closing all your crap with my dupe hammer because you're a poopy face!" then that's abuse.

Comment: Just in case you're not aware of it, @jww, the claw side of the hammer confers the ability to single-handely _re-open_, and that applies no matter who's responsible for the closure.

Comment: @ Servy - if I give you X, you leave X out in the sun and X melts, then that's an accident. If I give you X, tell you don't leave X in the sun, you leave X out in the sun anyway, then that's an negligence. If you can't see the difference, then I'm wasting my time with you. You'll never be able to understand the underlying concepts.

Comment: @jww, what you're talking about here is giving a _metalsmith_ a chunk of _stainless steel_ and telling him not to leave it out in the sun because it'll melt. Be prepared for him to not believe you.