# Please can we have a list of tags showings show many users have gold badge for them

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-badges

In view of '[When did I get close-vote superpowers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254589/when-did-i-get-close-vote-superpowers?cb=1)' and '[How Do I Opt Out of Privileges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231504/how-do-i-opt-out-of-privileges/231505#231505)', 
gold tag badge users have super duplicate closing powers.

Can we please have more information about which tags have gold tag badges, how many, etc.?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is in fact such a list; it's just not the easiest to find.

Here's the direct link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=gold

You can get to it by clicking "Gold Badge" under the Tag Badges section in the [badges page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges).