# SO is for answers. Should it be a cheatsheet for exams and tests as well?

Tags: discussion, homework

There are some questions about homework but I weren't able to find one on this particular problem:

What about answers for particular exams/tests? Say, there is a test used by some school/corporation. Should SO  help to keep these tests usable, or should it make answers freely available for everyone?

In other words, this question is not on helping one particular student to cheat (as it concerned in other questions here) but on making answers available for anyone, rendering these tests quite useless.

In my opinion, such questions should be banned and answers deleted. But I often find my opinion in contradiction with officials, so, I decided to ask.

Comment: We are not in a position to judge the rules of conduct of a school. If a student cheats like that, that is **their problem**, not ours.

Comment: How would we go about verifying a claim that a specific question is from a test or exam in the first place? What levels of proof will we require? Who is going to verify them? How can one appeal a decision to delete a question?

Comment: that's what I were afraid of. "Who I am to judge? So, I'll let dishonored things go. None of my business"

Comment: You can always contact the affected exam board yourself. Make sure whomever is responsible is caught. I just disagree that it is the job of the Stack Overflow moderators to police this.

Comment: A lot of tests are not worth the paper they are written on (or the pixels they use on a monitor). Are you going to outlaw questions like *What is the postfix operator for?* because it has appeared in countless tests?

Comment: related: **[Open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)**

Answer (score 14):

I don't think we can create a separate close reason specifically for questions that appear on an exam somewhere. Policing questions with this criteria would be too difficult for us. That responsibility really needs to stay with the institution giving out the exam or homework problems.

A lot of test/homework questions have problems that make them close-worthy, though, so I often just use an existing close reason from the dialog.

- If you see a hyper-specific question about a general programming concept, it can often be closed as a duplicate that asks about the concept. (This helps the test-taker learn, without spoon-feeding them the answer to their test question.) (Also, [you now have close-vote super powers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254589/1288).)
- If a question looks like it was copy/pasted from an assignment, sometimes I'll close it as "lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem," since the OP usually doesn't explain where they're stuck ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23326821/1288)).

Comment: Generally, you are right that it would be futile to try to remove all such questions from SO because we cannot know all the exam questions that are being asked. But I think it would be useful if we would at least quickly close questions that are obviously copied from an assignment, *and explicitely say so*. It would give a clear signal to new users that we are not here to do their homework. I don't think these homework questions are of any value to anyone but the people who ask them, and even that value is questionable.