# Coursera questions

Tags: discussion

The Coursera [terms of service](https://www.coursera.org/about/terms) say (among other things):

> All students participating in the class must agree to abide by the following code of conduct:
>
> - I will register for only one account.
> - My answers to homework, quizzes and exams will be my own work (except for
>       assignments that explicitly permit collaboration).
> - I will not make solutions to homework, quizzes or exams available to anyone
>       else. This includes both solutions written by me, as well as any official 
>       solutions provided by the course staff.
> - I will not engage in any other activities that will 
>       dishonestly improve my results or dishonestly improve/hurt 
>       the results of others.

There are a reasonable number of explicitly-[coursera]-tagged questions (45) (20 overlap with [r], which is my main focus), and presumably a lot of untagged ones (searching on "coursera" alone (not the tag) gives 692 hits; there are probably even more that don't mention it).

I believe the general answer to questions about the [ethics of answering homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254658/so-is-for-answers-should-it-be-a-cheatsheet-for-exams-and-tests-as-well/254675#254675) is that [it's up to the individual answerer to decide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18242/what-is-the-policy-here-on-homework) how they feel about answering, and [up to the student](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) to abide by the rules of their institution.

Is Coursera large/prominent enough that it's worth considering as a special case?

**update**: to answer the four votes to close as "unclear what you're asking": the `coursera` tag is different from the generic `homework` tag in that (1) it is **not ambiguous what it means**, and (2) the policy of Coursera on external resources *seemed* by my reading to prohibit SO questions (I have updated my belief on that point based on the experience-based statement below that appropriate SO questions are in fact explicitly encouraged in Coursera courses). So I was asking whether `coursera` could in fact be considered significantly different from `homework`, to the extent that the tag would be useful/could be kept.  (I think I have the community's answer ...)

Just curious.

Comment: I'm not sure what to think of this question; their terms of service are, so far as I can see, entirely irrelevant to us on Stack Overflow, regardless of the size of Coursera (or the number of students).

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274845/burninate-and-blacklist-the-coursera-tag

Comment: the question is currently at +11/-7, indicating a lot of disagreement about whether it's useful or not.  I've read the [homework tag burnination discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated); I think this tag is a bit different from a more generic `homework` tag (there's much less ambiguity), and there's a somewhat better argument for it. I also think I'm in the minority in thinking that I, personally, would like to know whether a question is Coursera homework when deciding whether to answer it or not.

Comment: Has it been decided to remove the tag?  Because someone is currently removing the tag from questions.

Comment: ... and now we're at +33/-24.  I'm guessing downvotes are from veterans of the `homework` discussion who are sick of this topic. I'm reluctantly convinced, by @Joe's answer below and by the depth of feeling here, that we are headed for burnination.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Why should we make a special case for them, or for any other large educational institution? It has never been on Stack Exchange to enforce the code of conduct of other sites or universities, so why start now?

If a question is a well-asked, on topic question that can be given a solid technical answer, I have no problems with it being on the site and being answered. Others outside of the Coursera class might benefit from it, so I see no need to close these questions or discourage answering good questions.

If they are bad questions, treat them as you would any other bad question on the site.

Comment: +1 But that's the thing...most of them are very basic, some are not well written at all, and an answer to almost all of them could be found in the help files or a simple SO search.  I guess there's really nothing that can be done except standard SO protocol of down/up voting, tagging, and/or closing

Comment: which I guess would translate to "tag as coursera and downvote" (as most of these questions don't appear to be off-topic -- just absolutely no research effort).

Comment: @BenBolker - You are free to vote how you want, but I tend not to care about the source of a question, just whether it was asked well and is on topic. I will say that the nasty comments I've been cleaning up on recent Coursera questions will not be tolerated, however.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear in my comment.  I'm suggesting downvoting these questions if they deserve it due to lack of usefulness or lack of research effort (which most of them do), and tagging so that people like me who don't personally feel comfortable in helping people cheat on their homework can avoid the questions more easily.

Comment: @BenBolker the tag would effectively be a `homework` tag; which has been [burninated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated) after much debate.

Comment: Should we have a new question to burninate [tag:coursera] then?

Comment: @Joe Already exists [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274845/burninate-and-blacklist-the-coursera-tag).

Comment: @RichardScriven If it's not well written, we should clean it up or close it. If it's found in SO search, we should close as dupe. If it's basic, but well written and not a dupe, there's nothing wrong with it. We should answer it (preferably with a stellar, canonical answer) and move on to the next question. The "Standard SO protocol" you mention **works**.

Comment: "and universities" *and highschools*. They're important too. >:( (yes, I realize that's an incomplete list (of 2 items) :)

Answer (score 23):

I've taken one of the more common R classes on Coursera, and they explicitly tell you to go to StackOverflow and/or the R-help mailing list if you have a question that's appropriate (and they make some effort to explain what "appropriate" is, telling folks to ask more basic questions on their own forum).  While StackOverflow can obviously make any choice on its own regarding these questions, there's absolutely no reason to special case Coursera.

In the majority of cases that I've had experience with, the actually graded material is either too quick to be able to be helped by SO (ie, quizzes which you can't really pause for a two day question on SO) or projects of the nature that SO would be perfectly fine (where you can't really ask the entire project as an SO question, but it's reasonable to ask how to do the sub-parts).

Comment: Useful to have information from someone who's actually taken one of these courses.

Comment: Side note: I took the course on gamification on coursea (it was me'h) and Stack Overflow was used as an example of successful gamification.

Comment: I think there is a big difference between going to Stack Overflow to ask how to read a data format in R (which is encouraged by Coursera) and going to SO to copy the exact homework assignment with the exact homework dataset.

Comment: yes, @ynka, but that means that the decision falls back to the usual SO rules: "this is a bad (little research effort)/off-topic question, so downvote/vote to close it" -- if a SO question trying to get an answer to a Coursera question is not *automatically* a violation of terms of service, then I would basically retract my arguments in favour of a `coursera` tag.

Comment: Exactly: it would be a good or bad question without knowing it came from Coursera, and a decent number of them are.  (Plenty are _not_, and hopefully those get closed anyway.)

Answer (score 2):

Questions Coursera students ask usually are abstracted enough to the point where it furthers their knowledge of the subject to have their question answered without really doing their homework for them. As long as the student doesn't ask for someone to complete an entire feature of a project, it stays within the spirit of learning and should be encouraged.

Comment: I agree with your second sentence, but not necessarily with the first (depends on your definition of "usually", I guess).  Most of the ones I've seen are people getting hung up by some minor misunderstanding.