# Burninate and blacklist the coursera tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request, meta-tags

The [coursera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coursera) is essentially equivalent to the 'homework' tag (may it never be revived).  While this provides easy pickings for questions that are ones that are likely bad and should be closed, the tag should be destroyed and forever forbidden from being used for *exactly* the same reason the homework tag is now that way.

It is a [meta tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/meta-tags/info) pure and simple.

Fortunately, at this time, there are only 46 questions with this tag.  Additionaly, there are no cases where it is the only tag on the question.  Removing it from all questions *will* get it into the automatic removal of the tag process however, given its nature I am *certain* that it will reappear just as the homework tag took some heavy handed stamping out.

One of the key issues with a meta tag is that it imparts a *large* amount of context that is unknown to anyone who isn't familiar with it.  This unsaid context then leads to poor questions (the context being used as an excuse for the quality of the question) and answers that likewise, depend on the context and are unusable by anyone else.  By removing this tag, it forces people to write better quality questions that <sub><sup>hopefully</sup></sub> clearly state the assumptions and context of the environment leading to more useful questions and answers.

Comment: This request doesn't really say why it should be burninated, black listed. You mention that it's essentially similar to [homework] without providing reasons. Furthermore, it would be theoretically possible for someone to be a coursera expert, just by having don't the questions already. At 45 questions, meh, but I really wish both requesters and voters put considerably more thought into these requests.

Comment: @Ben - The tag should be burninated because 1. We don't want questions like, I am trying this algo from *Courseera* and it doesn't work (I mean, why say from where you are trying this problem?). 2.Course-era is an *external resource*, so there is very little chance of people asking *valid* questions about it. I would also suggest burninating *Coding-bat* tag.

Comment: It should be burninated because (like the homework tag) it doesn't add anything useful to the question. Is the answer to the question different with or without the coursera tag? No. So it isn't useful.

Comment: @MattBurland Great description of a meta tag

Comment: Is [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274834/1169519) somehow related?

Comment: @Teemu it is what reminded me of its existence.

Comment: It's a meta-tag in the sense of ["the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/), but **not** in the sense of "commonly means different things to different people". In the sense defined above of "doesn't add anything useful to the question", well, that criterion is itself subjective -- depends on what you find useful. (The definition of "useful" above is "might change the answer to the question", but that's not *my* definition of "useful".) (I do realize I'm on the losing end of this, so I should probably just shut up.)

Comment: @BenBolker how is it different than 'homework' which was also deemed a meta tag and yet also meets your criteria.

Comment: I claim that it's not subjective or ambiguous -- the second of the two criteria listed above -- in the way that `homework` is.

Comment: Such a statement wasn't in the question @TheLostMind, which was my point. Most things are external to SO so your characterisation of an external resource probably being invalid is strange. I haven't looked at the questions, but a broad characterisation of questions asked about other resources being invalid is opinion only unless you can back it up with facts. I really don't care about this tag but these burninate requests are beginning to feel like witch-hunts. All I ask for is evidence not some unsubstantiated sentences without evidence.

Comment: Suggest this discussion be limited to burnination; blacklisting is not trivial to do and with such a low number of questions it shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @Ben -Unless *Courseera* makes all its code and design available on the internet, and if people ask questions related to the code *of* courseera rather than the code for Courseera assignments, the tag is useless.

Comment: There _are_ a few questions that are about Coursera itself (accessing it via code, etc) and not about the content of its courses: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26060712/logging-into-a-coursera-account-using-python http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24883582/why-i-failed-to-login-coursera-using-requests-library http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22921241/error-using-coursera-dl-in-windows

Comment: @JLRishe maybe `cousera-api` tag would be more descriptive?

Comment: If we keep this tag, should we also keep the [tag:project-euler] tag?

Comment: @corsiKa I've argued against the existence of [project euler tag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274534/289086) and [spoj](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/181970/213963) in the past.  The source of the question is irrelevant to the categorization of the problem and especially problematic when it becomes an excuse for a poorly worded, contrived question (you *can* have good coursera, project euler or spoj questions - especially when they aren't tagged as such).

Comment: And I agree with that sentiment. I just think if the community disagrees with us on euler, they in theory should disagree with cousera too. Unless the cousera-euler parallel causes them to rethink their opinion of the euler tags. The two should be the same outcome - either both stay or both go. We shouldn't burn cousera because it's bad, but keep euler because so many of us enjoy going to project euler now and then. =)

Comment: @corsiKa I've added to the question to expand on the reasoning why these types of 'where I got the problem' meta tags are problematic.  Coursera, PE, and SPOJ all have their own context that makes them difficult questions to use when that context is left unsaid and only in the tag. Things like memory and performance are issues in SPOJ, while the core simple problem is in PE, and the academic correctness in Coursera. Removing the meta tag and forcing the OP to write the question better rather than using the meta tag as an excuse is a *good* thing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The burnination is now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). No questions carry the tag at the moment, Cerbrus and I just cleaned out the remaining questions (in response to [Coursera tags are getting readded to questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275161/coursera-tags-are-getting-readded-to-questions)).

[image: tag burninated]

♫♩ Burninating the countryside ♪♬ burninating the peasants ♫♩ burninating all the peoples ♬♪ in the thatch roofed cottages! ♬♩

*Wicked dueling guitar-solos*.

The zombie-tag reaper will take care of the tag wiki tonight.

I do **not** think it needs to be blacklisted. I've added the tag RSS feed to my burninated-monitor, we'll see if it comes back.

For questions about the Coursera App Platform I created a separate, new tag: [coursera-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coursera-api). Feel free to assign this to appropriate questions.

Answer (score 44):

I agree. Such a source or inspiration of a question is irrelevant. This tag doesn't add any useful information related to the *problem* to solve. I really don't understand why should anyone care whether the question comes from coursera, edx or any other learning site (well, regarding the comment discussion, I do understand why, but I still don't think this justifies adding noise to the site). This information might be added in the question itself, if the attribution is really needed.

Comment: I care because I prefer not to answer questions, no matter how well formulated, that are violating the OP's terms of service. The tag makes it easy for me to ignore them.  (I know that the majority of the SO community might disagree with me, but it's an answer to your question.)

Comment: @BenBolker It's not your duty to make people honour other site's terms of service. Of course, feel free to play conscience-policeman but not by the cost of adding noise to this site.

Comment: I know it's not my duty, and I'm not trying to make anyone else do it, but it's my personal preference. You said you didn't understand why anyone should care about the source of a question, so I told you why I cared ... I do realize I'm in the minority/on the losing end of the burnination debate.

Comment: @BenBolker OK, I understand now why anyone would like to know this. However, it's not entirely that you're not trying to make anyone else do it - existence of this tag forces this awareness on everyone. And some people would like to keep this site focused on programming :) I also don't like people who cheat and choose the cheap path, but it's their business and in the end they will pay the price :)

Comment: Tags aren't for adding useful information to problems. They are for notifying users to what the problem is related (e.g. CSS tag for people who are looking for CSS questions).

Comment: @TylerH and for ignoring questions, like Ben said. I think there is a reason we can ignore tags!

Comment: @TylerH: But what value is there in knowing a question is Coursea *related*? Other than making it easier for Ben to ignore it, which itself is predicated on either the OP tagging the question themselves or somebody else recognizing the question as from coursea and tagging it.

Comment: @TylerH What the problem is related to is a useful information. Most of the tags indicate the important technical context of a question. They allow to filter questions based on your *technical* / *professional* preferences. This tag on the other hand is a [meta-tag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/meta-tags/info), as indicated by the OP.

Comment: @MattBurland and BartoszKP - I'm not arguing that the tag should be kept :-) I'm saying that tags are clues about languages or frameworks (et al) related to the question. BartoszKP's answer seemed to suggest otherwise.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26060712/logging-into-a-coursera-account-using-python) deserve the Coursera tag? It's about trying to grab information from a Coursera account.

Comment: @APerson Wow, nice find. I agree that such cases would be only *valid* usages of this tag. However I still don't think it deserves a tag for it - the answer suggests that the procedure is the same as programmatically logging in to most sites... Nothing specific about coursera.