# Coursera tags are getting readded to questions

Tags: discussion, tags, meta-tags

A [recent burninate request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274845/1757964) for [coursera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coursera) which received overwhelming community support (+98/-13 on the question and +44/-4 on the answer at press time).

Thus, I've been removing that tag from a bunch of questions which were generic R questions and thus had nothing to do with Coursera. (Examples: [one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6057942), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6057978), [three](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6058018), [four](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6058040))

However, when I checked the tag page recently, I noticed that several questions which I had removed the tag from reappeared. Looking at their revision histories, I noticed that a few of them had edit wars over whether or not the tag belonged; many of these edit wars weren't even on posts I had edited.

Examples (I'm adding more as I'm finding them):

- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25874453/revisions (after my initial edit, 3 more tag edits)
- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25346988/revisions (after my initial edit, 2 more tag edits)
- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25798263/revisions (4 tag edits; also look at [the comment thread there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25798263/passing-a-directory-through-a-function-in-r-then-storing-a-variable-for-each-cs#comment40352415_25798263))
- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25825057/revisions (my edit got rolled back *without* fixing any of the problems the rollback left on the post (e.g. the sentence "Please tell me if I made any posting mistakes"); counting the rollback, 2 tag edits after mine)
- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26517482/revisions (4 tag edits)
- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25773776/revisions (3 tag edits)

(In the interest of disclosure, I caused the final reverts on the first two edit wars by requesting that the tag be removed; this was because I had already fixed as much as I could on the posts and didn't want to clutter up the suggested edit queue with a tag-only edit.)

Is this "anti-tag burnination" a good idea? Doesn't it go against the wishes of the community?

Comment: When burninating, you should include a link to the Meta discussion in the edit summary.

Comment: @Stijn I understand why that would be a good idea (and I'll do that in the future) but is it absolutely necessary? Edits should be able to stand on their own as a positive contribution to the post.

Comment: I've removed the tag from some of the questions, notifying the users that added them about the burnination.

Comment: " is it absolutely necessary?" most (if not all) edits should have an explanation of the edit. Even if it seems obvious, this will help others to understand *what* you have changed and *why*. Not all good edits are glaringly obvious at first glance.

Comment: And with @MartijnPieters' help, [there are no questions left](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r+coursera) tagged with both [tag:r] and [tag:coursera]

Comment: @codeMagic I explain all of my edits; however, what's the difference between "retagging; fixed grammar; reindented code" and "burninated tag per [community discussion](http://example.com); fixed grammar; reindented code"?

Comment: @Cerbrus: there are no questions with [tag:coursera], period!

Comment: The difference is obviously the link to the meta which Stijn has pointed out is helpful. Otherwise, future editors might not realize why it has been removed

Comment: Ah, Even better!

Comment: I've also rolled back the roll-back that killed your accepted suggested edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do the same thing you should always do when you see an edit war; flag for moderator attention.  They're the only ones that have the tools to deal with such situations.