# Should the '4clojure' tag be burninated?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

4Clojure is a site with exercises which helps learning the Clojure programming language. There are only 40 questions tagged with [4clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/4clojure) comparing with over 8000 questions tagged with [clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clojure).

The [4clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/4clojure) tag is unambiguous, but it doesn't add any meaningful information to the question. When a question is tagged [clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clojure) then adding [4clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/4clojure) adds almost no value to the question.

An important question in evaluating a tag is: Can you be an expert in this area?
So the answer to "Can you be an expert in 4Clojure?" is: "You can be an expert in 4Clojure questions only if you are expert in Clojure." So the [clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clojure) tag is sufficient here. The source of code in a question is not so important to have its own tag. There is no special tag [clojure-in-action] for problems with code examples from book "Clojure in Action".

I have to admit that maybe half from this 40 question tagged [4clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/4clojure) is my fault. I am a new user on Stack Overflow, and I edited several old questions adding the [4clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/4clojure) or [project-euler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project-euler) tag. I also improved the tag wiki for this question (which was very short). Now I understand that this was wrong, and I want to start a discussion in this subject.

Comment: do we delete all tags that are specifically for a certain resource then? The [tag:railstutorial.org] tag has a LOT of associated questions.

Comment: Now, let's assuming that being able to filter on a tag is a good thing and that the ability to find what you're after more easily is in fact meaningful. Do you have _any_ argument left?

Comment: See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274845/burninate-and-blacklist-the-coursera-tag

Comment: @sevenseacat: Even if you argue that being able to find all questions inspired by http://ruby.railstutorial.org would be useful (Remember they must be self-contained!), we have `url:` for searching.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, consider this, isn't this tag a meta tag? Does it add anything that existing tags don't convey?

Partially, yes: It provides context that the question relates to exercises, and that users who enjoy the [clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clojure) and dislikes [4clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/4clojure) questions can ignore the tag. It helps filter questions.

On the other hand, no: "4clojure" is not a specific technology. Questions asked that relates to 4clojure exercises themselves, as such the tag doesn't add anything useful that's not already come with "clojure".

Depending on the quality of 4clojure questions, perhaps a cleanup first is more appropiate, then it can be burninated.

Comment: does this mean that [[tag:project-euler]] is a meta tag? How is 4clojure that different from project euler?

Comment: I disagree with labeling it a meta tag, I've offered a justification in my answer.

Comment: @Quincunx: [**Yes.**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275935/burninate-project-euler)

Answer (score 1):

I edited all 40 questions removing [4clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/4clojure) and correcting many different errors.
So now [4clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/4clojure) is
[image]

Next victim will be [ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ratio). See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277705/burninate-ratio) soon.

Answer (score -3):

**NO**, it should not be burninated.

It provides a level of utility, doing several of the things described in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging):

> - describes the topic of the question
> - sorting questions into specific, well-defined categories
> - connects experts with questions
> - helps you identify questions that are interesting or relevant to you

On meta tags, Jeff's original [definition](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/):

> There are a few tags on Stack Overflow that have bugged me for a long time. Namely: subjective, best-practices, beginner
>
> How can you tell you’re using a meta-tag? It’s easier than you might think.
>
> 1. If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it’s probably a meta-tag.
> 2. If the tag commonly means different things to different people, it’s probably a meta-tag.

This tag looks nothing like those examples - meta tags are so broad and vague that they have no utility.  This tag has a clear definition, and a question only about the 4clojure tutorials is on topic because it is about "software tools commonly used by programmers".

[4clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/4clojure) provides a level of utility, is not a meta tag, and should not be burninated.

Comment: How does the fact you found that exercise in $tutorial/book/blog/whatever change the problem? The question must still be self-contained and able to stand on its own. Also, ever seen the `url:` search-option?

Comment: It doesn't change the problem.  As mentioned, it identifies and groups related questions that may be of interest to you.  It's a question of whether keeping the tag is harmful, and removing it would improve the quality of the content.  I think the answer to both is no.

Comment: It should also be mentioned that tags have abilities search does not, ie following.

Comment: So, as the tag does not in any way describe the problem, how is that not a meta-tag? And just use your own custom search, browsers have bookmarks for a reason.

Comment: Changing and describing a problem are two different things.  My argument is all about utility anyway, disagree with that instead.

Comment: If it's a good question, it shouldn't matter if it is tagged 4clojure or not.  If it's a poor question, it shouldn't matter if it is tagged 4cloure or not. Closing poor questions is a *good* thing and tags shouldn't be used as excuses for poor quality questions (that are then ignored by the experts and turn into a question ghetto full of crap questions and crap answers).

Comment: You know, both signs for probable meta-tag hold: The tag cannot stand alone, and - at least if 4clojure is useful - they cover many different topics. If it is actually thorough, it will cover all of clojure.