# Are tags tying questions to a specific, well-defined resource useful?

Tags: discussion, tags

During a routine burninate [request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276548/425313), someone raised the tag [4clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/4clojure), which identifies questions derived from a popular interactive clojure tutorial.

Other tags identifying similar learning resources you may recognize came up, [railstutorial.org](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/railstutorial.org) and [project-euler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project-euler).

Given the rapidly increasing scope of this request, I think it's important to take a non-burnination oriented look at the issue.

They look a lot different than Jeff's canonical examples of [meta tags](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/):

[beginner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beginner) [best-practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/best-practices) [subjective](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subjective)

They're in a different class than corporate meta tags:

[microsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft) [coursera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coursera)

They're much more descriptive, and much narrower.

Everything that we do here is about creating the best resource on the web for professional and enthusiast programmers.  It is my belief that these three tags, and any similar ones, are unique enough that they don't belong among the useless meta tags.

They do several of the things the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) says a good tag should do:

> - describe the topic of the question
> - sort questions into specific, well-defined categories
> - connect experts with questions
> - help you identify questions that are interesting or relevant to you

They connect these questions together in a useful way that language tags alone cannot.

My justifications aside, let me ask: Do these tags create any value?  Are they legitimately in a different class than the useless meta tags?  Would StackOverflow be an improved resource if they were gone?

Comment: Just saying, the [tag:microsoft] tag has *"DO NOT USE THIS TAG!!! This tag is too general to be useful. Use tags more relevant to the software or device you're targeting. "* as the excerpt. I don't have any comment for now but nonetheless, I hope this post will create a good discussion.

Comment: Regarding [tag:coursera]: What probably was the telling point is that asking a question (which someone might reason deserves that tag) did obviously violate their terms of service.

Answer (score 6):

I went and read through a few of the first couple questions on those tags and here's the thing that jumped out at me after reading them.

If you remove all references to the learning sites, the tag and in the question body, you are generally left with a good on topic question about a specific programming question. To me that says that the information is at best further context and at worst noise. There are a few questions that seem to become unclear or off-topic with that information removed but that seems to be more because it is a poorly formed question that leans on an offsite resource for the reason it lacks information in the question itself.

So that being the case I don't see a value in the tags at all since the only time they seem to be of use are when the question itself is poorly formed to begin with.

Outside of that, the ability to follow or ignore these tags don't seem to outweigh the additional noise that is made by their use.

Comment: Thanks for taking a close look. Follow up, project-euler is the most unique of these tags, because it connects similar questions across languages.  Are you comfortable saying "burninate project-euler, we're better off without it" based on your research?

Comment: With euler it's even more the case that the tag does not in any way describe the question. Also, the euler tag had a disclaimer which is just about "Do not answer", as well as a request to ask on their forum instead.

Comment: @BradKoch That one seems to be a little tricky. As Deduplicator says it doesn't really help to describe the problem and can generally be removed without consequence. But I can see use in being able to locate those questions. However, a better search would probably turn up those questions as easily as a tag would.

Answer (score -2):

I think it depends. There is no clear boundary between the senseless tag today and a scoping tag tomorrow. In particular, if a learning resource grabs for thoses tags in StackOverflow, they can improve bad questions, find out if the exam questions are all answered and so on.

In terms of delivering answers to the technical questions these are of no value than. In terms of scoping to the origin, they make sense.

Comment: One can use `url:` to find questions referencing that site.