# Is [todomvc] a useful tag?

Tags: discussion, tag-creation-process

A user seems to be going on a spree of suggested edits, creating the new tag [todomvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/todomvc) and adding it to a large number of questions that in one way or another mention TodoMVC. However, I'm not totally convinced of the value of this tag.

TodoMVC isn't just one specific library or project - it's a project that entails example apps implemented in many different languages. It doesn't provide any concepts unique to itself - it's a demo of the MVC functionality that exists across different languages. The threshold for a tag being "good" is usually whether someone can be an expert in it - it doesn't seem likely that anyone is going to be an "expert" in TodoMVC, but rather in specific languages in which there may be a TodoMVC example. Most of the questions out there that mention TodoMVC seem to be more about aspects of the language the asker is working with - it seems like the fact that the code in question is a TodoMVC example is just incedental.

I don't feel that this tag adds a level of value that justifies bumping up a bunch of old questions so as to add it. I'm interested in the community opinion as to whether this is worthwhile, or if it should be stopped now.

Comment: It is one "specific thing", it has a github depot, 8 programmers contributing to the project, a version number, SO users asking questions about it.  There is no harm whatsoever in tagging these questions with the project name.

Comment: Yeah, I guess "specific thing" wasn't the best wording for what I meant - I just felt like since it primarily exists to show off the MVC features within the languages themselves, it may fall on the wrong side of the "tags should relate to what a question is about / not what it contains" reasoning. I just didn't see many questions that were, at their core, **about** something inherent to TodoMVC.

Comment: This sounds an awful lot like [4clojure](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276548/should-the-4clojure-tag-be-burninated) and [project-euler](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275935/burninate-project-euler).

Comment: @JasonMArcher, I appreciate those examples - although this is arguably maybe *slightly* less meta of a tag, that's exactly the catergory I felt that this might fall into.