# Burnination requests

Tags: discussion, burninate-system

I've been using Stack Overflow for quite some time, and I don't ever seem to recall the volume of burninate requests that currently pollutes meta like a virus. I think the current system for handling these types of requests is deeply flawed. Not that I disagree with most of them, but there has to be a better way.

1. There never seems to be a community consensus on these requests.  Most of the posts that I see *maybe* have only one answer and very few views.  The first page of results for the tag shows the highest view count as 500.  I hardly think that's enough to be a representative sample of the entire Stack Overflow user base.
2. Not that I am opposed to improving the site, but seriously, don't we have better things to do with our time? The close queue or review queue comes to mind.
3. I feel that if this is something the community has a deep interest in doing, some sort of system support should be added to facilitate it.

Comment: Removing `feature-request` because I don't see one in here. I, however, do agree that we get a lot of requests for this and they can be a bit noisy.  If you have a suggestion on how to fix this problem, then that'd be a `feature-request` and I'd be curious to hear your ideas.

Comment: How active were you on the *old* Meta Stack Overflow (now renamed to Meta Stack Exchange)? Some of the new burnination requests are simply dupes to requests posted there. Stack Overflow is also forever growing so some tags are sticking out more now than they may have done in the past.

Comment: @bluefeet Good call, thinks for pointing that out.  Nothing comes to mind right now, but I'll think on it for a while.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I rarely saw these types of questions getting a lot of attention on the old meta, with occasional exceptions (i.e. Homework).

Comment: The only 'controversial' burnination request that I can recall was [the `coursera` tag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274845/burninate-and-blacklist-the-coursera-tag), which was controversial because some people wanted to be able to track what they perceived to be a low-quality-post magnet.

Comment: @iamkrillin Is part of the problem the fact that `burninate-request` posts show up in the Hot Meta Posts?

Comment: @bluefeet using a queue of some type comes to mind.

Comment: @bluefeet that certainly makes them more visibile.

Comment: @iamkrillin If you used a queue I doubt you'd get people putting in the time to actually fix up the content effectively.  People in queues want to be able to handle posts very quickly, not spend several minutes (minimum) per post putting in a lot of work.

Comment: @Servy after the queue determined that the tag should indeed be burninated, have the system do it.

Comment: @iamkrillin Burnination requests aren't just about removing the tag from all questions that have it.  They're far more complex.  Often they involve disambiguateing the questions, re-tagging the questions with one of 2 or more possible tags, closing the questions because they're topic is offtopic or otherwise a magnet for low quality content, etc.  The main reason it's *not* automated to be, "remove this tag from all questions it's on" is precisely because doing that is so rarely the correct course of action (alone).

Comment: @Servy true that, but my point still stands.  Surely there is a better way that what we have now.

Comment: @iamkrillin And my point still stands, a review queue probably isn't that way, even if there is room for improvement.

Comment: `that currently pollute meta like a virus` - that's a pretty hostile reaction to trying to improve the site.  Now [hat] questions during Winter Bash, *that's* pollution.

Comment: Bad tags incur technical debt over time as well. A tag that's added will slowly build up over time, eventually picking up really bad questions. My request for [tag:social], for example, has started to get questions about social media, and has no real guidance for what it should be used for.

Comment: Your points 1 and 2 are completely invalid. Why would you need a "representative sample of the entire SO user base" to decide that a "microsoft" tag is crap and should be blacklisted? #2 is BS because a) most meta users _do_ spend their time reviewing and closing, and b) just because there's other things to clean up doesn't mean we shouldn't clean up tags. 3 is a valid argument: Apparently there is a process to blacklist tags, but it can only be used by SE staff and is almost never used because it's apparently complicated/expensive/whatever. Having this as a mod tool instead would be good.

Comment: @l4mpi Because when you have a small subset of users deciding what is best the whole idea of "community" is lost IMO.

Comment: You completely miss my point. A burnination request is not a conspiracy attempting to "decide what is best" for SO, but a simple janitorial action. Some tags are ambiguous or broad and then get split, synonymized or cleaned up by members of the community, or mods and SE employees in extreme cases. You don't need to ask the whole community if that's ok every single time; we don't do so for edits or closing or tag wikis either. As an analogy, when you see trash lying around in a public space in your community, you don't have to hold a vote, you can simply pick it up and throw it away.

Comment: In the last 24 hours, a [burninate-request] (the only one) posted 11 hours ago has the sixth-highest view count and fourth-highest score on meta. It's *so clear* that these questions are completely unrepresentative of the community!

Comment: The feature request seems to be adding a "burninate request" review room for a larger subset of SO users.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To address your points:

1. The user base: Only [282506](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/267107) users have an account on meta.so, that is only 7% of the 3856452 users on main. From those 282506 only a subset is interested in active moderation of the site. A couple of (up)votes is all you can hope for...
2. It depends if we need to spend our time better. Tags with bad questions sometimes acts as honeypots attracting more crap. It is usefull if the few people that want to spend their time in the close vote queue (for example) do that while focussing on a specific tag.
3. We can use some structure, not all requests end-up well. Please read-on

#### Burninate process guideline

The main problem with some burninate requests is that they lack a plan and research.

For a burninate request to be successful it needs the following ingredients:

- Why does the tag need to go, why is it bad, why can't it stay? That needs examples of some questions that demonstrate its misuse
- the tag statistics, number of questions, number of followers, unanswered count
- the tag counts to show the [correlation](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/266852/tags-that-are-used-together?tag=strong) with other tags. This indicates if the tag is used in a particular context more often.
- Which action you expect from the community , choose all or any of:

  - introduce a new tag (including excerpt and wiki)
  - retag guidance (remove or replace)
  - close vote instructions
  - edit instructions (which always includes **FIX EVERYTHING**)
- update for the tag wiki and excerpt (if applicable)
- synonyms to be proposed with other tags
- earlier or similar requests on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/burninate-request) or [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/burninate-request)
- one or more search queries to help the community find the correct questions
- define how progress is measured
- Invite people to let them know in comments if they are going to help
- Let users report their progress

Maybe there is a chatroom that is related to the tag, ask for help there.

Some extra tips if you expect to close vote questions as part of burninating. It needs 5 votes from 3K-users to close a question. You can leave a burninate request in the [SO Close Voters room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) but due to  the limited capabilities on filtering in the queue we are the most effective if the time between voting and the regulars handling the queue is short (as in within 30 minutes or so) and comes with a [tag] and a specific close reason (for example: [ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby)/off-topic). We have scheduled events and daily meet-ups (in the evening of an SE-day)

Comment: This answer is well though out and reasoned.  Though I don't think it really addresses my core complaints/issues.  Marking as answer.

Comment: @iamkrillin please check if my update still warrants your acceptance