# No point in using [points]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

I noticed the tag [points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/points) is used for two unrelated concepts, namely the numerical counter used in games or comparisons, or the geometric one also used for gps locations.

[coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coordinates) and [point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/point) are good destinations for the geometrical ones.

Comment: Ooh.  No tag wiki to determine what the original intention was for either.  I personally dont' like the "score/numerical counter" half of the tag.  It just doesn't seem useful.  I think there is no "point" in using the tag for that purpose.

Comment: Your observation might be correct but I miss in your post what you expect from me to do? Can you elaborate a little bit and maybe take some points from [my answer about burnination requests](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284185/578411)?

Comment: @ryanyuyu another day on meta another day of puns.

Comment: The game related usage should probably be removed.  If anyone wants to talk about points used in games they should be in the [Game Development](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) community.  Someone more knowledgeable will need to indicate how to go about that process.

Comment: So, are you saying we should burninate [points], or synonymize it with [point]?

Comment: Is there any justification for keeping [tag:coordinates] or [tag:point] either? I kind of object to the GIS focus of [tag:coordinates], to be honest.

Answer (score 12):

Nobody is an expert for [points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/points), no matter the interpretation (game points, geometric points). Who is an expert on geometric points but not on geometric squares/rectangles/circles?! Nobody. If I'm interested in geometry I'll follow [geometry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/geometry).

We should kill [circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/circle) as well which actually says:

> This tag has been deprecated. Please use [geometry] instead.

Also to be put to death: rectangles, ellipse, polyhedra, ... Put a list of further tags that you find in the comments here.

All of those tags should be bulk-deleted, banned and [geometry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/geometry) added to those question.

Comment: This is the third time I've seen a rectangle tag come up in a burinnation request. (I believe is was just [tag:rectangle] in previous cases, though.) Really need to clean those up. +1