# Should we burninate the [points] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

The 688 questions currently tagged [points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/points) can do without the tag or becoming a synonym of [point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/point).

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

The main use of the [points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/points) tag appears to be that of [point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/point). For reference:

- [points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/points): a scoring system for games or algorithms. geometric items should use [coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coordinates) and [point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/point)
- [point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/point): A point is a fundamental geometry entity.

From my review of the posts tagged [points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/points) it appears to be confusing and heavily misused. In fact it was hard to find any questions where the tag was used in the tag wiki context.

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Yes, but perhaps very narrow, and can be described by algorithm tags?

> Does the tag add *any* meaningful information to the post?

When used in the same way as [point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/point) it adds nothing extra compared to [point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/point).

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

No, although the tag wiki does attempt to clarify the correct use.

Comment: Why not make it a synonym of [tag:point]?

Comment: @PaulStenne I raised the point, and it might indeed be the solution, but I am worried it now has multiple uses and you're then essentially just flipping the misuse. However, it did seem very few questions had any "point system" reference at all.

Comment: I'd write a full answer detailing why it should be made a synonym but to be perfectly honest I cannot find enough point puns for now. If anyone feels like taking a stab at it, make your point.

Comment: I see no point of having either tag. Cleanup and disambiguation is in order.

Comment: Suggested title: This tag gets no [points] for usefulness

Comment: What about points as a typographical entity? Perhaps a synonym of [font-size]?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296707/no-point-in-using-points

Comment: This request currently has 12 [points].