# Is there any [point] in keeping this tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

It seems to me that [point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/point) is, at best, pointless; it could even be considered harmful. Here are my assessments of the formal burnination criteria:

---

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? And is it unambiguous?**
I would say it seldom (or even never) *describes* a question's content (though it may be relevant). Its terse [tag-wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/point/info) offers some disambiguation (i.e. it's about geometry rather than, say, a reward given in a game) but there is still a number of different scopes in which it can be used: a point in actual space, a point on a graph, etc.

**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**
In my opinion: No, it isn't. The concept as described in the wiki would maybe work on Math.SE (or other sites) but it's not a core programming issue.

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**
Not really; there are (or could be) far better tags to use, which would serve both as better search targets and as more suitable 'fields' in which answerers could earn badges. On this issue, maybe also see the [discussion about the points tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296707/10871073).

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**
Notwithstanding the disambiguation provided by the tag's wiki, a brief search through its newest posts reveals quite a variety of meanings.

- [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11082696/10871073) it is about a language-specific data type.
- [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/139655/10871073) it about the 1/72" unit used for font sizes.
- [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65164840/10871073) it's about pointers. (OK - that one's a cheap stab at a usage mistake, but I thought I'd throw it in to the mix, anyway.)

---

As the tag currently as over 1,000 questions (1,782 at the time of posting), it is also customary to ask:

**Is the tag causing a fairly large amount of harm?**
I would answer: Yes - both potentially, by discouraging askers from using one or more better tags, and actually, by taking up the fifth tag slot, thus *precluding* a better tag - as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65048093/10871073).

Another question that is often asked when considering tag burnination is, "Can one be an expert in this tag?" To answer this, I would like to quote the comment posted by Makyen♦, in a preliminary discussion we had in [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/51122339#51122339), prior to my posting this:

> Ok. Then, I think a pointed argument could be made that the tag really
> doesn't match the criteria for a tag. Can someone really be an expert
> on point? Well, yes, an expert can be on point, but that's not *the*
> point. *sigh* I guess we'll just have to go through it point-by-point.

So, other than serving as a ripe punning-target, does [point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/point) serve any purpose, or should we feed it to Trogdor?

Comment: If the tag is specifically for geometry points then perhaps it would be better named [tag:geometry-point]? Certainly it would make it less ambiguous. Though I agree that I don't really see the *point* in the tag.

Comment: Oh my goodness, this could be the question with the most terrible puns. Anyway, you are right, that tag has too many different meanings and is so generic that it doesn't make sense to keep. Just sayin', it only has 66 watchers, so as you can see, it's not a tag you would actually search for because it's weird and generic and who cares.

Comment: The _harm_ part is a bit of a stretch imo. Every pointless tag possibly took the place of a better one, but honestly, there are very many bad tags to choose from. If it was actively causing confusion in some way, e.g. a significant portion of the questions that should be tagged pointer got tagged point, you'd have a stronger case. Questions rarely need the full 5 tags.

Comment: @ErikA Yeah - I actually agree with you that it's a stretch, on some levels. But it's actually quite difficult (for me, anyway) to *precisely* define what *harm* means, in the context of a tag. Personally, I think general "tag clutter" is harmful, but others may well disagree.

Comment: It's certainly not a useful tag. But what I realised on other websites, once it's there and doesn't really harm, it would just be wasted effort to remove it. For example, on one coding website someone noticed that there's a default sprite that's just a red line. Not useful at all. But it was in that kind of state where you wouldn't add it because it doesn't do anything and that would be wasted effort, but also not remove it because it doesn't really hurt and that would be wasted effort too.

Comment: A point is a well defined geometric object. If we get rid of point, then we should also clean [line] (5.4k Qs), rectangles (1.2k questions, plural?), plane (0.3k Qs) and potentially do something with cube and cubes.

Comment: @Trilarion I already had the [line] tag in my sights! I was waiting to see how this request went down, before tackling that (and the others you mention).

Comment: @jps Get rid of `[point]` and you cannot have a `[line]`. Get rid of that and you cannot have any geometric shape. With those out, you just have an empty plane.

Comment: @VLAZ I think your last point is out of line: please be more careful, or we could have a pundemic on our hands.

Comment: I don't see any value in this tag.

Comment: Maybe the `[point]` of the `[plane]` tag is to easily `[line]` up aircraft software. Some of that really needs to be `[square]` in the `[center]` of the `[path]` to avoid anything being `[folded]` or `[flattened]`.

Comment: But wait, now I get it, @Trilarion: If we don't have points, then we don't have lines, and that's a serious problem, because if we don't have lines, how should this be on-line?

Comment: @Scratte the `flatten` tag I could see still being useful. That's more of a CS list operation than a geometric one. Also, amazing.

Comment: I don't think it would be particularly on-topic for Math.SE either. There's really nothing that can be said about points themselves; they're always boring, but exist within some more-interesting context.

Comment: There's [no point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_No_Point) to this tag. Let it burn as [a navigational aid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_No_Point_Light_(Washington)).

Comment: Amazing. How much time wasted on meta-thinking instead producing something meaningful that matters. Tag no tag color no color font no font-  Questions-Answer-Learn-Repeat

Comment: @Scratte Why tags aren't clickable in your comment? That's one of the biggest disappointment of my week (year?)

Comment: You can make automatic quick-links to tags with `[tag:name]`. That works in posts and in comments. In posts, it will apply the actual tag formatting, but that doesn't happen in comments: they just turn into a bare link. So I like to insert the brackets to make them look a bit more like a tag: `[[tag:name]]`. This achieves the same effect of distinguishing tags from the running text, *plus* adds the link, without being nearly as annoying as the code formatting. Now you know and can do as I do. :-) (cc @Pac0 — glad you're having a great year)

Comment: @Pac0: The canonical is *[Add data.SE style “magic links” to comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments/94000#94000)* (slightly misleading title). The tags part is in sub section *"Supported magic links in comments"*.