# Do we need a [triangle]-ular tag again?

Tags: discussion, retag-request

Looks like this question already exists: [Unify [triangle] [rectangle] [shape] [circle] and the like under [geometry]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254937/5958455)

**However**, the [triangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/triangle) tag has somehow emerged again since then, with 10 questions tagged at the time of writing this post.

Should we merge [triangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/triangle) into [geometry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/geometry) properly, again?

Comment: Why not just zip it?

Comment: BTW, the request was completed just by [adding circle to the list of synonyms](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254937/unify-triangle-rectangle-shape-circle-and-the-like-under-geometry#comment685802_254937). None of the others were acted upon. The others didn't exist by the time the post was marked completed.

Comment: @Braiam I do feel that \[triangle\] may be useful in some way or another, for example computer graphics are extensively triangle-based.

Comment: We also have [square] [hexagonal-tiles] [polygon] [convex-polygon] [cube] [hypercube]. I think some are unrelated to geometry, but that doesn’t stop some people

Comment: We already have better tags to cover for those iBug. Also, I doubt people would use it in a way that anyone will find useful. All questions are related to one another just because the word "triangle" was used. That's not how tags are supposed to work. Also, **the tag was zipped before**.

Comment: It depends what [triangle] you look at the issue.

Comment: I'm starting to think that some tags exist just for meme fodder

Comment: I think you make a fair [`[point]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/403537/10871073), so I'll click the `triangle` near the top-left corner of your question. ‎

Comment: if it was merged before, Why not just ban it to prevent it from appearing over and over?

Comment: There was a question the other day about printing a triangle using asterisks -- a common beginners' homework assignment. The poster tagged their question with [triangle], which I edited out. They put it back. I had to remove it again and explain why it was not useful for categorizing their question. It would be good to ban the tag.

Comment: @Chris If I recall, blacklisting a tag isn't an elegant process, and it's more or less the nuclear option. Clearing out all questions on the tag so that it goes away is *usually* good enough, since you need 1.5k rep to create it again. Not sure what's best here, since that apparently wasn't enough in this particular instance.

Comment: @zcoop98, I agree, but on the other hand, is it a sustainable solution to create delete xyz tag posts indefinitely?

Comment: @Chris It's very sustainable. We can keep creating burnination posts on meta for the same tag forever. That's the whole point.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph for the memes, I suppose, yes, you are right.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph It would be more sustainable if there were badges for that!