# Delete [classnotfoundexception] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I propose to delete/burniate the [classnotfoundexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/classnotfoundexception) tag:

- It's name is very generic;
- The wiki suggests it's only for the Java ClassNotFoundException (which means it's heavily misused);
- Nobody can be a ClassNotFoundException-expert.

Comment: [tag:noclassdeffounderror] should be burned in the same fire.

Comment: The whole no experts thing is a bogus metric. See [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284185/4639281) and [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/288751) for more info. I don't see any reason currently to keep the tag, but I also see no convincing argument to remove it, nor any statistics about the tag and its use / misuse, and your request shows a lack of research effort and commitment.

Comment: Many ClassNotFoundExceptions are typo-level problems resolvable by anyone, but I expect at least some of them require actual expert knowledge of Java class loading.

Comment: Also, the lack of a pun in the title is a show stopper.

Comment: `Raise PunNotFoundException` try harder