# The learn-c-the-hard-way tag just seems no good to me

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

[learn-c-the-hard-way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/learn-c-the-hard-way) is a bad tag, in my opinion, because it's misleading and not useful.

I did not even know there was book with that title, and I thought this had to do with the approach the OP used it regarding his/her post/problem.

Moreover, I do not think it's useful, because it's used too little. I mean it's lot like kernighan-and-ritchie tag, which is not used as much as it should, since people do not know it (I just found out about it).

I feel it just wastes space, tiny space of course, but a cleanup of not-useful tags, should in my opinion take this tag into account as well.

Comment: Not knowing about a thing is a bad reason to ban the tag. There are a ton of things I have no clue exist but which have a tag on SO. It just says something about *you*, not the tag. – Note that I'm not against removing the tag though, just not for that reason.

Comment: Good point @deceze, but it's not about a programming idiom for example that I do not know and it's nice to learn about it. Learning that a book with that tag exists doesn't seem so useful to me. So, for what reason you would like the tag to be banned? Maybe for the second reason I mentioned.

Comment: If the tag itself is not useful in any way, then it should be removed. Is there someone going to look at that tag specifically because they know a lot about it and can answer questions? Probably not. – Is someone going to look for answers to their problem in this tag specifically? *Maaaaybe?!* If that book is well known enough and spawns occasional questions which require answers, then it's *possssibly* useful?! But looking at it it doesn't seem that way.

Comment: I would really like to hear what the downvoter has to say.

Comment: I don't see any harm in it. The Zed Shaw "Learn X the hard way" tutorials are fairly popular and I used "Learn C the hard way" to brush up on my ancient C knowledge. Having this tag lets me track questions related to the content in the tutorial. I personally think it's fine.

Comment: @kev You could just have that text _Learn X the hard way_ in the question. I don't see a reason to have a whole tag for it. It would still be searchable.

Comment: @Matt - not always, I find SO's on-site full text search feature to be comically inaccurate. Here I can just click on the tag and it just works.

Comment: Hard to see how destroying the tag is going to make your life better.  Instead of being able to tell that the Q isn't interesting from the front page, you now have to navigate to it and read it.  You still haven't read the book, that's 5 minutes of your life you'll never get back.

Comment: @G.Samaras - missed your comment, I was the aforementioned downvoter. My point is that it's different from tags such as [item], [variable], [expand] etc which are rather widely scoped and provide little context.

Comment: It has been burninated! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/learn-c-the-hard-way

Comment: It's ok @Kev, I guessed it. :)

Comment: @deceze "Is someone going to look for answers to their problem in this tag specifically? Maaaaybe?!"  I don't know anything about this particular tag, but I know that in the Lisp and Scheme areas, there are a few tags that make it *very easy* to find duplicates of problems that come up from tricky parts of the books (or outdated parts of the books, etc.).  Maybe original askers won't look for the tags, but the experienced users will use them for the dupes.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The source of a question, as in what tutorial / educative site or book it's from, is completely irrelevant. As such, I'd suggest burninating the tag, just as has been done with the [Coursera](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274845/burninate-and-blacklist-the-coursera-tag) tag.

Basically, the tag doesn't add any useful information to the question.

Edit:

The burnination now appears to be [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

[image: tag burninated]

Comment: Yes, that's the spirit. What if two books talk about the same subject? There would be two questions, where the only tag that would differ would be the book. I feel that mentioning in the question, that I read that in *x* book, is just enough. +1.

Comment: Or to put it like another user said: [tag:learn-c-the-hard-way] should be burninated because it doesn't add anything useful to the question. Is the answer to the question different with or without the coursera tag? No. So it isn't useful.

Comment: Actually, such a tag is often detrimental to the question: It invites just linking to the chapter/exercise/whatever, instead of writing a self-contained question.

Comment: From reviewing the summaries of each question, the questions are specifically about content in the LCTHW tutorials, how is that not useful? I don't think this tag is a problem and since discovering it when I was brushing up on C using Zed's tutorial I found it useful.

Comment: @Kev: What does it matter that the question originated in a (specific) tutorial? How does that influence the question? It doesn't. It's unnecessary information.

Comment: @Cerbrus because if you're looking for questions specifically about that tutorial and particular exercises then you get to them quickly because their tagged and specific.

Comment: Or you could look for help on the tutorial / course's site.

Comment: @Cerbrus the whole point of SO is to come and ask "programming questions", also the help 404's http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/help.html (and isn't in archive.org) and it was never going to be a useful resource because it was fairly static.

Comment: "The source of a question, as in what tutorial / educative site or book it's from, is completely irrelevant."  I disagree, at least in some cases. Sometimes questions show up with code that is supposed to work, but doesn't, and the key to understanding what's happening is where the code came from.   E.g., in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24721676/1281433), the fact that the code, by a very well known Lisper, seems to just plain not work, is explained by the early publication date.  When duplicates arise, some of these questions are easiest to find because they've got book tags.

Comment: "Mostly irrelevant" then... Besides, nothing you couldn't find with [a simple google search](https://www.google.nl/webhp#q=stackoverflow+%22On+Lisp%22+continuation+)

Comment: And sometimes, knowing where things came from, it can become clear that the code from the book actually isn't supposed to work, and the asker misread something.  E.g., in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19720833/1281433), the OP is asking about code that (OP thinks) is supposed to work, but in fact, the book it's from presents it as intermediate code;  it works on some cases, but not all cases.  (The book develops a solution iteratively.)  It's much easier to answer with appropriate context when we know where the code came from.

Comment: Imo, that's another tag that might as well be burninated. Only 46 questions on it. The problem with tags (and questions) like that is that those really only can be answered by people who've read the book. I doubt people would go looking for questions about a book after working through it, you'd have to stumble upon the question and happen to recognise (and own) the book... Which can be done without a tag.

Comment: "The problem with tags (and questions) like that is that those really only can be answered by people who've read the book" - that is a seriously flawed reason to justify removing that tag. Tags don't need to have a minimum number of questions to be permitted to exist. The tag isn't confusing/overlywide in any way, unlike "triangle" or "ratio". This is tag vandalism.

Answer (score 10):

Where the tag is only used on a handful of questions and you are sure that it's a bad tag, it's perfectly fine for you to just remove it yourself. If it was truly a useful tag then it will get recreated at some point.

Burnination requests should really only be used for tags that are used on 100's of questions as editing all of these in one go would lead to the home page being flooded with updates, pushing new questions off even quicker than usual.

Comment: Or if the asker is simply not sure. Better they get unconfused than they go off on a tangent and cause lots of inadvertent damage.

Comment: @Deduplicator - even then if it's only used on a **handful** of questions then the scope for damage is limited.

Comment: Well, for those questions about a miniscule tag, I don't see the tag itself (deciding whether and how to handle it, as well as getting help for doing so) as the focus of the question, but shaping and understanding policy on SO. Which means it's actually about all the other tags which (seem to) fit into the same mold one might stumble over later-on too.