# Should [gdx] be merged into [libgdx]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

I was helping a user with their libGDX question and they had used the [gdx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gdx) tag on their question.

Looking at what else has been tagged with it, it looks like it was used 8 times, either in addition to, or instead of, the more appropriate [libgdx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/libgdx) tag.

Should/can these be merged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as they are obviously the same thing.

I did it for the handful questions there were, leaving only one which will be roomba-ed soon anyway.

[You should have simply gone ahead, as it was a clear-cut case and only a good handful questions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291356)

Comment: Thanks! And sorry, I had no idea that at my rep level I could have done this. Now I know :)

Comment: Well, now you know how to handle it next time, so all is good.

Comment: Oh, and now I see; you just went through and manually updated each one. Yeah, I knew I could have done that; thought there was a higher level way. Shrug. :D