# Retag [cfg] to [context-free-grammar]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Today I noticed that there are two tags related to context-free grammar, namely
[cfg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cfg) and [context-free-grammar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/context-free-grammar).

The abbreviated tag has 34 questions tagged. Upon first glance most are about context-free grammar, with an exception of [one that is about .cfg config files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29817051/3488231).

The other tag has 652 questions.

Due to the difference in number, and the fact that the abbreviated tag may not have a very clear meaning, I think [cfg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cfg) should be retagged to [context-free-grammar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/context-free-grammar).

However, given the low number of questions tagged [cfg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cfg), is it worth the effort and worth bumping all the old questions?

Note: If I had enough rep to not flood the review queue, I might have retagged them myself, as per the suggestion in [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291356/3488231).

Comment: Consider it [meta-tag:status-completed].