# Tag [cfg] was created again

Tags: support, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation, blocklist-request

Tag [cfg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cfg) was created [again](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291733/retag-cfg-to-context-free-grammar). This time it was used on the questions of four categories:

1. ones that should be tagged with [context-free-grammar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/context-free-grammar) instead. I re-tagged them accordingly.
2. Ones that should be tagged with [control-flow-graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/control-flow-graph) instead. I re-tagged them accordingly.
3. General configuration questions, and questions about various *.cfg* files. I tried my best to re-tag them appropriately. <sup>1</sup>
4. What's left are questions also tagged with [rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust), and I don't fully understand what are those about, and if there should be a separate tag for them.

Based on this I ask:

1. Somebody with proper knowledge in Rust re-tag what's left of [cfg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cfg) tag, at the moment - 8 questions (DONE),
2. after re-tagging happened - include [cfg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cfg) into stop list of tags, so it couldn't be created again: it always will be a magnet for ambiguity.

---

EDIT: Rust related questions re-tagged. Please proceed with adding this tag into stop list.

---

<sup>1</sup>: One of questions was so strange that I didn't know what to do with it. I re-tagged it with [visual-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio), but if you have better ideas (or spare VTCs), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74888654) it is.

Comment: Should some of those be retagged [configuration-files]?

Comment: Perhaps, after it's cleaned up (again), [[tag:cfg]] should be made a synonym of [[tag:context-free-grammar]] to help avoid the ambiguity in the future.

Comment: @ThomA banning the tag makes more sense, because people who want to use it to mean other things *will* try, and *will not* care when it gets auto-synonymized to the wrong thing.

Comment: I don't know Rust, but `cfg` [appears to be its rough equivalent to C's `#ifdef`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/attribute/cfg.html).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, we have [tag:conditional-compilation], but I'm not sure if it's the best idea to use it here.

Comment: `cfg` is used for expressing conditions for conditional compiling, there is also cfg macro which lets you check compile time flags at runtime. With a quick look I can tell that these 8 questions are related with conditional compiling. Maybe it can be replaced with `rust-cfg` tag as it is done in  `tokio` -> `rust-tokio` , `cargo` -> `rust-cargo`

Comment: As a Rust curator, tagging [conditional-compilation] is more prevalent and clear to me for Rust questions about `cfg!(...)`, `#[cfg(...)]` and `'cfg(...)'` syntaxes. Even `rust-cfg` as Ömer Erden proposes doesn't really help much IMO.

Comment: Can't say I'm a big fan of [TLAs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-letter_acronym). Too many collisions. Canadian Food Guide, for example in this case.

Comment: Yeah this is clearly a case for the blacklist IMO. There are three-letter acronyms and then there is CFG which might be the ringleader.