# Synonymize [spark-framework] to [spark-java]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request, synonym-request

The [spark-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spark-framework) tag refers to the exact same thing as [spark-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spark-java), the first should be made a synonym of the second.

The excerpt for spark-framework reads:

> Spark is a Sinatra inspired micro web framework for Java.

And the one for spark-java reads:

> Spark is a lightweight web application framework inspired by Ruby's Sinatra.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Preserving [spark-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spark-framework) as a synonym of [spark-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spark-java) does not look worthwhile (the tag-names are too similar), thus I looked into [simply burning it down](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291356):

- I added the single fact the first tag wiki had and the master didn't to the master (wikipedia-link).
- Then I manually re-tagged the 10 questions (for so few questions, that's ok).
  I looked for other things to correct, but there was remarkably little to copy-edit...

[image: Trogdor]

Comment: I edited a few also, so you didn't do it alone :-)

Comment: Ah, there were a few more, at some point ;-)) Well done.