# Merge tags [spark-java], [java-spark] and [spark-framework]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

It seems something similar was done here: [Synonymize [spark-framework] to [spark-java]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294995/synonymize-spark-framework-to-spark-java).

Right now, [spark-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spark-java) has 91 questions, while [java-spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-spark) and [spark-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spark-framework) have 19 and 2 respectively. The [spark-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spark-framework) has no description and the other two have pretty much the same:

> [java-spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-spark): Spark Framework is a simple and lightweight Java web framework built for rapid development.
>
> [spark-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spark-java): Spark is a lightweight web application framework inspired by Ruby's Sinatra.

I believe the best to do here would be to kill both [java-spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-spark) and [spark-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spark-framework) and bring their questions to [spark-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spark-java).

The actual name of the project is simply Spark. Since it's a framework, [spark-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spark-framework) does make sense and I kinda like it. But we should probably stick with the current most popular tag, since most users are probably used to it and it matches the [project's domain](http://sparkjava.com/) and its [*groupId*](http://sparkjava.com/documentation.html).

Comment: spark-framework is retagged

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to delete a tag?

Comment: I will be deleted at 03:00 UTC when the clean-up script runs

Comment: Oh, poor poor @rene. You *will* be missed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've visited those 19 questions in the tag [java-spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-spark) and edited, voted and retagged.

I did something similar to the tag [spark-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spark-framework).

Both tags no longer have questions and if it stays that way until 03:00 UTC the tags will be deleted by the tag clean-up script.

Enjoy your now focused tag. Please keep it clean.