# Make [spark-framework] a synonym of [spark-java]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request, synonym-request

The tag [spark-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spark-framework) has been burninated twice before, [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294995/synonymize-spark-framework-to-spark-java?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314095/merge-tags-spark-java-java-spark-and-spark-framework). It was recreated just a few days after being burninated the last time. [spark-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spark-java) is the more popular tag with 414 questions while [spark-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spark-framework) has only 48.

Both tags are about the same framework.

[spark-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spark-java)'s about:

> Spark is a lightweight web application framework inspired by Ruby's Sinatra. Its main focus is rapid development in pure Java with no need for extensive, additional XML configuration.

[spark-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spark-framework)'s about:

> Spark Framework is a simple and lightweight Java web framework built for rapid development built in Java.
>
> ...
>
> Spark was originally inspired by the web framework Sinatra, but it's intention isn't to compete with Sinatra, or other similar web frameworks in different languages.

Can we deal with [spark-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spark-framework) once and for all?