# Unpair the [pair]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

I had suggested the burnination of the [learn-c-the-hard-way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/learn-c-the-hard-way) tag and [that green dragon came to save the day](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291351/the-learn-c-the-hard-way-tag-just-seems-no-good-to-me). I was editing a question about pairs and thought that the [pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pair) would be nice. On second thought I said to myself who is ever going to use [pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pair) as search term. Despite that, I wanted to see if a relevant tag existed.

I got **DO NOT USE** in the wiki of the tag with a reference to this deleted [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012). As a result, I am posting this question. I will edit the wiki to contain bold font. However, someone may not see it, so it would be better to be burninated.

So, I would like to summon the SO dragon:

[image: tag burninated]

Relevant: [When to burninate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191)?

---

So we do not delete the tag, we just keep it until some years pass over again and someone finds it again by chance?

Comment: It's been three years.  We haven't been able to get rid of a tag that was part of an "official" tag cleanup in *three years?*

Comment: @RobertHarvey to who are you talking? In the community I guess. Anyway, better late than never, that's why I thought it would be helpful to post this question, as a reminder. :)

Comment: Note that moderators don't have the ability to "burninate" tags.  SE does, but they have not shown a willingness to do this on a regular basis.  There is no dragon, in other words.

Comment: @RobertHarvey the tag I mentioned in my previous quretion was burninated, so I hope this will too. Maybe the dragon appears only in special cases. :)

Comment: Maybe we should set up a quick burnination crew [in the Tag Burnination chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20577/tag-burnination) and get rid of them all in one go. It shouldn't really take long...

Comment: @RobertHarvey Same for [context]. Related meta post: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295641/3488231

Comment: An [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/320980/tag-wiki-excerpts-that-start-with-do-not-use) that lists all tags that start with "Do not use" in their tag wiki excerpts. Disclaimer: there are false positives.

Comment: @BhargavRao The [pair] tag is one post away from being disambiguated...

Answer (score 12):

Yes, [pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pair) has no clear defined meaning. It should not be used.

But that doesn't mean it should be burninated. Instead, most of those questions should be re-tagged to:

- [std-pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/std-pair) - at least the C++ questions
- [tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tuple) - for more generic pair representations in other languages (like the Python or Haskell questions) Maybe create a [2-tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/2-tuple) tag?
- [keyvaluepair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keyvaluepair)
- [matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matching) - for those questions asking about matching pairs together (uh, that tag could use a cleanup as well, even though the term is [well-defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)))
- [bluetooth-pairing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bluetooth-pairing) could [probably use its own tag](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pairing+%5Bbluetooth%5D)
- …

Comment: Doesn't burninating involve retagging to the proper tags, for those questions which have (or should have) one?

Comment: @Deduplicator: Ideally yes, but to me "burnination" focuses more on removal of a tag than re-tagging (like "cleanup" does). The point of my answer was that [tag:pair] lacks a clear definition and needs to be split up, but most of the questions that use it can indeed use some kind of *pair*-tag.

Comment: tl;dr burninate the pair tag by retagging with other tags?

Comment: @Bergi I am OK with the re-tagging. But after that, I do not see a reason not to burninate the tag. Practically, I think the trade-off between some questions (most of them are poor) loosing the pair tag won't hurt at all, while if the tag remains active, users will use it again and again (like they already did, despite the clear wiki message DO NOT USE! If this tag does not get deleted now, there might be a chance that it will be forgotten again!

Comment: Burnination always involves re-tagging the effected questions with appropriate tags and cleaning up other issues.  Sometimes this means creating new, more focused tags.