# Add more context to [context]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request, retag-request

The [context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/context) tag has the following tag wiki:

> DO NOT USE - Deprecated as part of "The great Stack Overflow tag/question cleanup of 2012". Please use a more specific tag instead. For Android contexts, use [android-context]. For a context menu, use [contextmenu]. For a context-free grammar, use [context-free-grammar].

Despite this, there are still around 2000 questions (but only 16 followers) with this tag, and it is receiving about one new question per day. It appears that most of them are from new users as well.

I therefore request to retag these questions to appropriate tags mentioned in the tag wiki. Also, since most people using this tag are new users, their posts may need a lot of cleanup / to be closed as well.

Comment: There won't be any questions for May or April as I re-tagged the already. I've been re-tagging them slowly, so as not to have to many bumped up at once. So, basically, it is in hand.

Comment: @BrianTompsett Ooh... Apparently I misread "Mar 30" as "May 30", leading to my conclusion that "it is receiving about one new question per day"... Sorry about that

Comment: Related: An [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/320980/tag-wiki-excerpts-that-start-with-do-not-use) that lists all tags that start with "Do not use" in their tag wiki excerpts. Disclaimer: there are false positives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can now answer in  more detail. [Attempts to deprecate this tag have gone on for some time considerable time but never completed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144393/what-to-do-about-wiki-tags-that-reference-the-great-stack-overflow-tag-cleanup). All postings that previously had been tagged [context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/context) have now been carefully retagged. (One posting remains holding the tag open so that the auto-clean process doesn't remove the carefully worded deprecation warning.) The next step will need to be decided, either leave it as it is, deprecated, or move to the next step of blacklisting.

The way that the SO/SE tagging system works, if someone types a phrase containing a space, such as `context window` or `context switch`, this gets recorded as two tags [context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/context)[window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/window) or [context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/context)[switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/switch). This accounted for quite a few of the incidents of deprecated tags, and will continue to do so unless the tag is blacklisted.

**Status Report**

This took some time, for several reasons:

- To not bump up too many old posts at once
- Not to make too much moderator work with knock-on activities (like flagging of poor posts, comments etc)
- Every post had to be read and understood to select the appropriate replacement tag
- Every post had to be improved with spelling, grammar, layout

*However, I did not tidy any associated answers. I thought that a task too far!*

The retagging (of just this one tag) threw up issues with a whole bunch of related tags, which may need further work.

**Missing Tags**

There are quite a few uses of the technical term **context** for which there is no suitable replacement tag yet. In particular the language agnostic use of the term does not have a fully appropriate tag. The tags [scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scope) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/this) can represent some of them, but not all. Also many users when encountering a compiler error message that says `X used in the wrong context` often do not know what tag to use. (But I'm sure that came up in the original 2012 discussions). These are some languages (or systems) which used context in a question for which no clear context tag applies (and might benefit from a generic or specific replacement tag):

[javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), [perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl), [node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node.js), [canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/canvas), [servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/servlet), [ruby-on-rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails), [nlp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nlp), [grep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grep), [awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/awk)

**Imprecise Tags**

There are quite a number of tags containing the string `context` which are not defined. Some have no clear single unambiguous usage, or have very few posts. These include:

- [initialcontext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/initialcontext) 48 posts
- [requestcontext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/requestcontext) 59 posts
- [drawingcontext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drawingcontext) 45 posts
- [contextify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/contextify) 17 posts
- [context-bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/context-bound) 21 posts
- [threadcontext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/threadcontext) 20 posts
- [wcf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wcf)+[ambientcontext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ambientcontext) 4 posts

**Overloaded Tags**

The tag [applicationcontext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/applicationcontext) is defined to be related to the class of that name in [spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring), however there is a frequent use of the term *Application Context* in [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) programming, and 31 posts contain both tags. Probably the tag [android-context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-context) should be used in the android case but this is not clear in the wiki.

In Android there is the tag [android-contextwindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-contextwindow), which seems clear. However, there are 535 posts which contain both [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) and [contextwindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/contextwindow) which should probably be re-tagged as [android-contextwindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-contextwindow), but at the moment this is not causing any confusion or ambiguity.

The term `context.xml` is also used in more posts than described in the specific usage for the tag [context.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/context.xml). It seems there are users of [spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring) who use [context.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/context.xml) outside of the [tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tomcat) environment.

**Duplicated Tags**

- We have [context-switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/context-switch) (165 posts) and [context-switching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/context-switching) (25 posts)
- We have [activation-record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/activation-record) (8 posts) vs [stackframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackframe) (68 posts) vs [stack-frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stack-frame) (15 posts) 
  <sup>because a method/processor context is put in an activation record in a stack frame!</sup>

**Conclusion**

That's all for now folks. My job is done. [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

It's odd, just like previous posters involved in this episode, I was also drawn in by [context-free-grammar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/context-free-grammar). In all the >2000 questions I read I think only two involved grammars.

Comment: Thank you very much for your hard work. I wish I could take a bigger part in this but I don't have 2k rep.

Comment: Well, retagging the last question and thus getting the tag pruned would be right. That means noone below 1500 will use it despite the tag-excerpt (which would be ignored, as is standard), and anyone at or above 1500 will be warned. If it crops up again, that's the time to think about blacklisting, not now. Good work, btw.

Comment: It's back now. [tag:context] has 193 questions

Comment: @BhargavRao [context] is gone again. Thanks for head-up.

Comment: [tag:context] was recreated in Dec 2nd week, and had 12 questions today. I cleaned it up again.

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩 it is back again with 13 questions

Comment: Yup, I'm [watching](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?room=167908&q=tagged%2Fcontext)... Waiting till it hits some 20~25, before I can ask for a blacklist request. (Looks like it'll hit that in a couple of days)

Comment: @BhargavRao this tag is back again with 21 questions