# How should we address/flag an answer by a supposedly educational entity?

Tags: discussion, answers, not-an-answer, moderation, moderator-abilities

While reviewing first answers, I came across [this question and it's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40835598/return-row-and-column-as-a-sequence-of-integers), this is a first (at least for me) seeing a user, identifying himself as an educational faculty member, and calling others not to answer a question.

(The deleted answer, added here later)

> As Academic Conduct Officer for the XXX University Faculty of Science, Technology, Engineering and Mathematics I am reading your question with interest. Rather than ask other people to do your [question type] for you, I suggest that you stick to honest endeavour, and perhaps read the Code of Practice on Student Discipline (sections X and Y apply in this case).
>
> Other posters - your suggestions are doubtless kindly meant, but please don't assist cheating.

While we have a moderation system for Q&A's that are a clear "do my homework for me" case, and seasoned users will flag this appropriately, what should be the case for a supposed "outside authority" calling users to not answer?

I flagged it for moderator intervention, but something about this feels like it should be brought up for discussion...

Is this appropriate?
Should this be posted but as a comment?
Should specific entities receive moderation rights for what the community already regards as an obvious issue?
Any other thoughts for something I may have completely missed here?

EDIT: as commented - the mentioned answer has already been deleted, since it does not answer the question (that was quick :) ). Anyways, my question still stands - is flagging this kind of issue for moderator attention enough?

Comment: The 'answer' has already been deleted by a moderator, because it doesn't answer the question (in the Stack Overflow sense of the word).

Comment: Related / duplicate question: [How to cope with complaints from tutors who want to fight cheaters?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295420/how-to-cope-with-complaints-from-tutors-who-want-to-fight-cheaters).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Flagging for moderator intervention was not needed here. Simply flagging as 'Not an answer' suffices in this case, because regular users can handle the problem.

You may want to leave a comment and explain what the answerer should do instead, as someone has done:

> Although I can see where you are coming from, this is *not* an answer. Gain some reputation and you could *comment*. You may want to talk to the Community Managers team by using the 'contact us' link in the footer.