# Instructions for reporting copyright infringement have (accidentally) been removed from the site

Tags: bug, status-completed, terms-of-service

The [official DMCA Designated Agent](https://dmca.copyright.gov/osp/publish/history.html?search=Stack+Exchange&id=57ce8b21206ff32072005039d1a2e87f) has changed from the one linked in the text below (which was terminated on 2020-07-05). If the status of the contact linked in this note is no longer "Active", you should be able to find the correct contact by [doing a search on dmca.copyright.gov for "Stack Exchange", "Stack Overflow", "stackoverflow.com", and/or "stackexchange.com"](https://dmca.copyright.gov/osp/search.html?key=stackoverflow.com&action=search).

---

The page at [`/legal/contact`](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/contact) tells readers to refer to the Terms of Service for instructions to deal with copyright violations on Stack Overflow's websites.

> If you believe that content residing or accessible on Stack Exchange infringes a copyright, please send a notice of copyright infringement according to [the instructions for reporting copyright infringement](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/public).

However, it looks like the Terms have been updated since that sentenced was written, because no such instructions exist at the linked URL, [`/legal/terms-of-service/public`](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/public).

The page only uses the word "infringement" to indemnify Stack Exchange from the actions of third-parties, and only uses the word "copyright" to explain that copyright law applies and that a Creative Commons license is used on the site. There are no "instructions for reporting copyright infringement".

I notified `legal@stackoverflow.com` (the address listed on `/legal/contact` and the [officially designated DMCA agent contact address of Stack Exchange Inc.](https://dmca.copyright.gov/osp/publish/history.html?id=623544c68cdd750da5966f8337a5029e)) of this on June 26, 2019, and again on July 15, 2019, while seeking to address a violation of my own copyright, but have received no reply.

---

It looks like the link originally pointed to `stackexchange.com/legal`, but when that page was merged into `stackoverflow.com/legal` last year, this section was not included:

> #### 15. Copyright Policy
>
> Stack Exchange has adopted the following policy toward copyright infringement with respect to the Network in accordance with the [Digital Millennium Copyright Act](http://web.archive.org/web/20160331000605/http://www.loc.gov/copyright/legislation/dmca.pdf). The address of Stack Exchange's Designated Agent for copyright takedown notices (“Designated Agent”) is listed below.
>
> #### Reporting Copyright Infringements
>
> If You believe that content residing or accessible on the Network infringes a copyright, please send a notice of copyright infringement containing the following information to the Designated Agent at the address below (all received notices will be posted in full to [Chilling Effects Clearinghouse](http://web.archive.org/web/20160331000605/http://chillingeffects.org/)):
>
> 1. Identification of the work or material being infringed.
> 2. Identification of the material that is claimed to be infringing, including its location, with sufficient detail so that Stack Exchange is capable of finding and verifying its existence.
> 3. Contact information about the notifying party (the Notifying Party), including name, address, telephone number and e-mail address.
> 4. A statement that the Notifying Party has a good faith belief that the material is not authorized by the copyright owner, its agent or law.
> 5. A statement made under penalty of perjury that the information provided in the notice is accurate and that the Notifying Party is authorized to make the complaint on behalf of the copyright owner.
> 6. The Notifying Party's physical or electronic signature.
>
> After the Designated Agent receives notification of an alleged infringement that meets all of the requirements above, Stack Exchange shall:
>
> 1. Disable access to or remove material that it has a reasonable, good faith belief is copyrighted material that has been illegally copied and distributed by any subscriber to the Network.
> 2. Stack Exchange will then immediately notify the subscriber responsible for the allegedly infringing material (the Offending Subscriber) that it has removed or disabled access to the material.
> 3. Stack Exchange reserves the right, at its discretion, to immediately terminate the account of any subscriber who is the subject of repeated takedown notices.
>
> #### Filing Copyright Counterclaims
>
> A subscriber who believes they are the wrongful subject of a copyright takedown notice may file a counter notification with Stack Exchange by providing the 
>     following items in writing to the Designated Agent at the address below (all received notices will be posted in full to [Chilling Effects Clearinghouse](http://web.archive.org/web/20160331000605/http://chillingeffects.org/)):
>
> - The specific URLs of material that Stack Exchange has removed or to which Stack Exchange has disabled access.
> - User’s name, address, telephone number, and email address.
> - A statement that User consent to the jurisdiction of Federal District Court for the judicial district in which your address is located (or New York County, New York if your address is outside of the United States), and that User will accept service of process from the person who provided notification under subsection (c)(1)(C) or an agent of such person.
> - The following statement: "I swear, under penalty of perjury, that I have a good faith belief that the material was removed or disabled as a result of a mistake or misidentification of the material to be removed or disabled."
> - User’s signature.
>
> Upon receipt of a counterclaim, Stack Exchange will forward it to the party who submitted the original copyright infringement claim. The original complainant will then have 10 days to notify us that he or she has filed legal action relating to the allegedly infringing material. If Stack Exchange does not receive any such notification within 10 days, we may restore the material to the Network.
>
> #### Designated Agent
>
> **Attn:** Copyright Agent
> Stack Exchange Inc.
> 110 William St, 28th Floor
> New York, NY 10038
>
> **Tel:** +1 (212) 232-8280
> **Fax:** +1 (212) 785-4578
> **Email:** dmca@stackexchange.com

Comment: The part about uploading notices to Chilling Effects needs to be removed since [SE stopped uploading notices two years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311707/since-when-did-se-stop-uploading-dmca-takedown-notices-to-lumen-database).

Comment: This has been fixed as per [this MSE announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375064/208518).