# DMCA take-downs ignored

Tags: support, legal, dmca-notice

I have sent a DMCA take-down to SO and followed it up with an email, but got no response after three weeks. Is there a better way to contact SO than the legal email address for DMCA notices?

Comment: "but got no response" - how long ago did you send it? Keep in mind that SO is a big site and has a lot to go through. Might take a couple of days, or even a week or two before they get to it. Things take time, especially in the world of legal

Comment: Three weeks, updated to reflect.

Comment: Three weeks is rather long. DMCA requires the company to act "expeditiously" (but doesn't define an actual time schedule).

Comment: I wonder if they just ignore them to see if they get sued or not.

Comment: @user11567957 I don't think that's the most likely explanation here.

Comment: Did you mail legal@stackoverflow.com or dmca@stackoverflow.com? That might matter. They used to have specific instructions for DMCA claims, but I can't find them atm.

Comment: @ErikA: [The instructions have been removed some time ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387746/instructions-for-reporting-copyright-infringement-have-accidentally-been-remov)

Comment: @ErikA I have tried both.

Comment: Is this DMCA takedown for [your own SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56344190)?

Comment: @AndrewT. no it's for an answer to my question.

Comment: @user11567957: Do you mind to elaborate what exactly your takedown notice was about? It's possible that you have a case, but none of the answers looks even slightly like a copyright infringe.

Comment: I'd be extremely surprised if the contents of any of those answers are enough to not fall under the fair use exception, but I guess that's why people have lawyers, so they can discuss those things.

Comment: @BDL There was some proprietary code in one of OP's questions, which they later redacted. They also tried to redact it from the answers but one user repeatedly rolled back their edits, and I assume that's why they're now resorting to a DMCA takedown.

Comment: @F1Krazy that is correct. Having said that maybe I should DMCA the question now because trolls are jumping in with the down-votes, probably due to this question.

Comment: @user11567957, I am not a lawyer, but if you posted code that you own in the question, you licensed the code to SO under an MIT license, which means that the answerer was within their rights to use your code according to that open-source license, so I don't think you can DMCA the code because its use is properly licensed. If you posted copyrighted code that you do not own and therefore couldn't license, then you probably also lack standing to file a DMCA takedown on that code.

Comment: @AndrewRay interesting theory but a condition of the MIT licence is that the copyright notice is preserved and since it's not displayed on that page the license is invalid.

Comment: @AndrewRay Can you point to anywhere on this network that say contributions of any kind is licensed under the MIT license, please? According to [The MIT License – Clarity on Using Code on Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271080/the-mit-license-clarity-on-using-code-on-stack-overflow-and-stack-exchange) and [A New Code License: The MIT, this time with Attribution Required](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272956/a-new-code-license-the-mit-this-time-with-attribution-required): "The changes proposed here have been delayed indefinitely "

Answer (score 8):

No, that is all there is you can do.

No one here can assist with that or speed up the process. You are in a queue, allow for [6 to 8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514)<sup>1</sup> to pop-out of the queue and have your request handled.

Related on MSE: [What is the policy for DMCA takedowns, and what can we expect in terms of transparency regarding the removed content?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317709/what-is-the-policy-for-dmca-takedowns-and-what-can-we-expect-in-terms-of-transp)  and related on MSO: [Instructions for reporting copyright infringement have (accidentally) been removed from the site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387746/instructions-for-reporting-copyright-infringement-have-accidentally-been-remov)

I'm not speaking on behalf of SE. The official policy might be different. I'm not a lawyer, I have no idea what a DMCA notice entails, nor which timelines are mandated by the governing legislation.

As in the comments a bit more background gets revealed let me elaborate on that as well.

If the reason for your DMCA request is due to you posting content that violates a copyright of someone else then I doubt the request will be honored (I'm still not a lawyer). Once you posted on Stack Exchange the license grants them to use / publish / keep that content. I don't think a DMCA request is the right tool here.

Instead prepare a custom mod flag that explains the case and offers which edits should be made to both question and answers so they have their value preserved and then have each post redacted to remove the stuff you shouldn't have posted in the first place.
That might get lengthy so maybe prepare what needs to be done off-line/off-site, for example in a secret GitHub Gist that you can then share a link to in your custom modflag.

---

1. Note that the 6 to 8 weeks is a meme. This is in no way an official timeline / service level agreement or something you can use as a formal reference.

Comment: 6-8 weeks would be a DMCA violation and expose SO to the legal risk of being sued.

Comment: I 'm not a lawyer.

Comment: Are you saying a DMCA isn't a super-delete-vote?

Comment: @ivarni I have no idea. The DMCA requests I have seen handled were all normal deletes with a comment from staff probably to prevent that a mod undeletes the post by accident.

Comment: Given the change in context now that we can see the whole story, your edited answer is exactly right.  The edits the OP tried to make to the answer seem rather benign and the rollback war seems unnecessary.

Comment: Not to mention that the code has been on the site for over 18 months before the edits took place.