# Is an answer calling for downvotes against the question Rude?

Tags: discussion, not-an-answer, specific-answer, offensive, code-of-conduct

I was alerted to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61939866/6471538) answer in a chatroom:

> Please note that this is a take home-exam question for the Algorithm Analysis and Design Course at IIIT-Delhi which is still going on. I am the instructor for this course. I would strongly urge users not to offer any solution to this and downvote this so that it is deleted.
>
> [http://faculty.iiitd.ac.in/~syamantak/](http://faculty.iiitd.ac.in/%7Esyamantak/)

To be clear, this is clearly Not An Answer (NAA) and I have flagged it as such. However, is it *Rude/Offensive*? I noticed that it specifically calls for negative moderation action (downvotes and question deletion) against the OP, which seems like it could be interpreted as hostile.

To be clear, I'm not asking whether this sort of "answer" should be allowed to remain on the site. I'm asking whether this is an ordinary NAA answer (flag as NAA or VLQ) or whether it is *red-flaggable* as "Rude or Abusive".

Comment: Considering it's perfectly valid to say "downvote and move on", I'd argue it's fine.

Comment: Certainly less rude than trying to get SO to help you cheat on your test with a zero-effort question.

Comment: I think most people forgot school and "impossible to answer" questions, which needed conversation with classmates to be understood and solved. Today it is compltely normal to post such question here or elsewhere, to get some help. modern times.

Comment: Using unapproved sources for assistance with projects, not authorized by a professor, is typically considered as cheating.

Comment: @nbk Having a "conversation with classmates" during an exam normally gets you kicked out. The question was off topic anyway.

Comment: @BSMP yeah that is right,. but today everything is connrcted and the answer should have been posted on pastebin and shared via social media.

Comment: Highly related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295420/how-to-cope-with-complaints-from-tutors-who-want-to-fight-cheaters

Answer (score 33):

No, it's not rude or abusive.

The user who posted this answer only had 1 rep and was therefore unable to comment. They were probably not well versed in how the site works. They were simply trying to prevent cheating, and the message was courteously written.

A NAA flag suffices in these cases. There is no real need to convert it to a comment, as a person flagging the answer would know how to flag or close vote the question and would have the rep themselves to put the relevant parts of the answer into a comment if needed. Once the question is closed and there were no answers ready to post, there can be no answers on it, so a comment is then unnecessary.

A custom mod flag is not necessary on an answer like this, as the community can deal with it. Although it is ok to custom flag concerns that are out of the ordinary.

Regarding it being a take-home test and the asker cheating, we cannot police that. I'd recommend leaving a comment for the answerer to take a screenshot and show it to the appropriate university authorities. Only the university can do something about it. The university may also contact Stack Overflow in order to obtain more evidence, if they are going to pursue disciplinary action against the asker.

Comment: I agree with almost everything in this answer. My only nitpick would be to clarify that, while a custom mod flag is not *necessary*, it would not be inappropriate/unwelcome, either. There *are* things that a moderator might want to do in cases like this that regular users cannot do.

Comment: @CodyGray yeh I agree with that. I thought about it and realised there's nothing mods can do - it's up to the education institution to contact SO. The only thing would be to expedite quick closure of the question and possible deletion. Either or I'm fine with your feedback. See the edit.

Comment: Mods can and have contacted educational institutions about these sorts of things. I probably wouldn't in this case, but meh. Just don't want to discourage people from raising custom flags, because this is the sort of thing that definitely seems like it would require moderator attention.

Comment: @CodyGray sure - look I'm happy for you to add that in as an edit. I'm out of the mod loop - so it's ok to improve the answer collaboratively.

Comment: Why edit when I can nitpick in the comments, @Yvette? I haven't changed *that* much. :-p