# Is there a benefit to closing a question as a duplicate of more than one question?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

Take [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python) into consideration. It was closed as a duplicate of two questions:

[image]

In [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python#comment761166_952914) of that question, there are links to three duplicate questions. This *seems* to be the goal of closing questions as duplicates - other, relevant, duplicate questions should be linked in order to serve as a reference to future users. In doing so, some questions may cover aspects that the other question(s) fail to. In addition, wording and explanations may also be different.

Now that [gold badge holders can cast binding duplicate close votes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254589/when-did-i-get-close-vote-superpowers), they may be the only ones to vote to close a particular question. In other words, the question can only be closed as a duplicate of one question in cases like these.

Would it be beneficial to allow a gold badge holder to add in multiple duplicate questions *when* voting to close a question? In other words, if I'm the only one voting to close a question, would it be beneficial if I could add in multiple questions so that they would appear in the header? If so, it would also be nice to add additional duplicates *after* the question has been closed, too. I know you can link to additional duplicates in the comments, but it would be more official if we had the ability to add them to the banner that appears above a duplicate question.

Comment: In the example you discuss the question would have not been reopened because there is only one person who thinks it's not a duplicate, even though a bunch of people think it is. I don't see this requested feature as being something that would have affected that example.

Comment: @Servy Maybe not. I guess the relevancy of that question is that it was closed as a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/if-x-or-y-or-z-blah), but is now closed to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23496860/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-the-same-as-at-least-one-of-two-other-variables). You are probably right though.

Comment: You're assuming that the person who first closed it would have used this functionality to close the question as a duplicate of both questions.  I'm not so sure that would have happened.

Comment: My assumption was that they would have used the functionality to add in the additional question *after* it had been closed. Not sure if that would have happened either though, that's why I'm wondering if there would be any benefits in this functionality.

Comment: I'd love to have the possibility to close a question as duplicate of multiple questions. Often a question can be solved by combining the solutions from two other questions, the OP just have to put the dots together. It might also help the OP to think about problems differently in the future. Rather than seeing a problem as one monolithic thing, they are composed of multiple subproblems, which can be solved individually.

Comment: Not that long ago, a question on SO could get 2 or 3 answers.  How can anybody possibly object to getting more than 1 good answer?

Comment: related: [More than one question per post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275908/more-than-one-question-per-post)

Comment: I think its a needed feature.  I'll frequently see questions like "How do I do Foo and send the result as an SMS?".  That's really 2 questions (how do I send an sms, how do I do Foo) that may both be answered.  I'd love to be able to put it as duplicate of both.

Comment: Related: [Gold-badge holders and moderators can now edit duplicate links](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291824/232567)

Answer (score 15):

Most duplicates are posted by new users and contain either more than one question and/or more than one problem.

In these cases almost all the time, you close the question as a duplicate of the **main** question or problem and someone comes along and undoes it immediately because the duplicate does not answer the 6 other questions/problems in the question, and is there not an **exact duplicate**.

In almost every case the **other** questions/problems are duplicates themselves as well.

Multiple duplicate targets would stop this reopening of bad questions or at least give some reason to have them reclosed by a moderator.

Comment: In that case, whoever re-opened is the problem and needs re-education.

Answer (score 5):

The ideal scenario is that duplicates questions are closed against the *best reference question,* the one ring to rule them all.

The ability to get questions closed quickly (if they are genuine duplicates) trumps the value of having multiple duplicate targets.

Comment: While I agree that closing superpowers is basically the Best Thing Ever, the two features don't have to be mutually exclusive.

Comment: Yes, but the multiple close targets thing was always tied to non-binding votes.  As a mod, I've never had the capability to specify multiple targets (since my vote is binding), so I try to find the best possible duplicate, rather than multiple duplicates.  I've never asked for the capability because I can always put a comment below the question linking the other related posts.

Comment: As an aside, when multiple targets are needed, the question is simply too broad. Nearly always.

Comment: If multiple duplicate targets are required, and the question isn't too broad, you could add an answer that [snaps the blocks together](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/08/04/9856634.aspx).  I understand [people would rather just name the blocks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254710/is-there-a-benefit-to-closing-a-question-as-a-duplicate-of-more-than-one-questio#comment20391_254710) and let the asker figure it out, but somehow I don't think this is an effective way to teach.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom The problem is that if block-snapping is required, the question is almost certainly too broad. As a hammer-wielder, I often close as one block, edit in the dupe link for the other block, and use a comment to explain how they snap together. That gets a bad question closed and also allows OP to walk away satisfied. If there comes to be a *pattern* where people want to snap *the same* blocks together, the decision can be reconsidered. (Edit: I see that this wasn't an option in 2015 when the question was originally asked. What a pity.)

Answer (score 4):

I posted this question almost three years ago, and as of today there was a new update which allows users to close a question as a duplicate of more than one question.

As stated in [this announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291824/232567) made today, gold-badge holders and moderators can now edit duplicate links, which subsequently means that you can remove or add addition questions after a question has already been closed.

1. Click the 'edit' link in the duplicate banner:

   [image]
2. Update the duplicate question list by removing/adding links to questions:

   [image]
3. Result after saving:

   [image]

Comment: Maybe this needs its own question, but what if a question is closed for another reason, say "needs more information", but it's actually a duplicate. As someone with only 3000 rep, I don't see a way to change the type of closure.

Comment: @livingtech it needs to be voted to reopen, and then voted to close again. If you have a gold badge in one of the question's tag *and* you were not involved in the original closure, you can unilaterally close once the question is reopened; but reopening the question is harder. The [SO Close Vote Room](https://socvr.org) may be able to help.