# What to do when multiple other questions must be combined to make a good duplicate?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23877634/1227469) question, the OP was getting output from his code in which two of the lines did not match his expectations. This was due to two separate issues with his code.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/501816/1227469) which seems a good duplicate for his first issue, and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8487255/1227469) which seems a good duplicate for the second. I did not find any single question which adequately addresses the OP's entire post.

Ideally I would have liked to have voted to close the question, and linked to both of the above questions. I have seen this done elsewhere e.g. on the question referred to [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254710/1227469). However, when I vote to close, I am only given the opportunity to enter a single alternative question.

Voting to close as a duplicate wasn't an option for me therefore, since if I did so, the OP would be left without a complete answer to his question. As such, I posted an answer to the OP's question and also linked to the two duplicates in my answer.

Is this the correct approach? How is that some questions get closed with multiple duplicates, and should this option not be provided to all users with close vote privileges?

Comment: I have often encountered this sort of issue and would appreciate input on the general approach. I have a dupe hammer in e.g. the `python` tag but it feels weird to close with multiple, *fundamentally different* questions. But it's much faster than waiting for two others to vote as "needs more focus", and is more immediately helpful to OP.