# Duplicates in the context of data manipulation

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

**Note**: Before *this* question is closed as a duplicate (see [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345295/what-can-we-do-if-a-question-is-a-duplicate-of-two-questions-combined), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257875/what-to-do-when-multiple-other-questions-must-be-combined-to-make-a-good-duplica)), I don't think data manipulation type questions are specifically addressed in this context. In particular, there is an argument that *all* such questions are duplicates, since each step is built on fundamentals which are often addressed by "canonical" answers. My fundamental question is: at what stage does a question become one in its own right, as opposed to too broad?

The question in question:

[**Apply multiple functions to multiple groupby columns**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49512034/get-means-and-sem-in-one-df-with-pandas-groupby)

I choose this question because, on the surface, it looks good. Although lacking an `[mcve]`, it shows the problem, what's been tried, and the desired output.

However, my first instinct was that there are canonical answers to the 2 main sub-questions:

1. [Applying 2 functions via a groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14529838/apply-multiple-functions-to-multiple-groupby-columns)
2. [Flattening column headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507794/python-pandas-how-to-flatten-a-hierarchical-index-in-columns)

Combined, these *should* be sufficient for OP to answer their question. I followed @JoshCaswell's [advice on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/345296/9209546) and closed as a dup of these 2 questions, but this was quickly reversed by a separate responder. I also managed to anger the questioner.

On top, I was subjected to this exchange:

> Hi man, do you have bad day? – XXXXX 7 mins ago
>
> @XXXXX, actually I've had a wonderful day. I reference 2 canonical
>   questions with hundreds of upvotes for a reason..they are very good
>   answers that are sufficient to help OP. – YYYYY 6 mins ago
>
> OK, it is very good add it under question, but it is not dupe. Because
>   close dupe as exact dupe is very nice, close same problem is good, but
>   close like 2, 3 dupe is really bad and I dont understand why do it :(
>   – XXXXX 4 mins ago
>
> So simply close dupe because I am big boss it is really bad :( – XXXXX
>   4 mins ago

I include the above exchange only to present the opposite viewpoint, which *may* be valid.

Some of the highest ranking SO members *of all time* are data-manipulation responders [pandas, SQL, R tags come to mind]. This isn't surprising: there are uncountable combinations of scenarios / problems users will meet.

But I would *much rather* a question reference other solutions and remark where they got stuck, rather than just put 2 answers together for them. In addition, such a question would be more useful to the community.

My questions, in short:

1. Is this specific question either too broad or a duplicate of other(s)?
2. If "no" to the above, when would such a question become too broad or a duplicate?

Comment: Related: [Why would a question thats normally too broad in *any* other language be okay if it's in Python?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/353940)

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about "angering" the OP; people always get upset when you require them to do work they don't want to do, like breaking down their problem. If XXXX is the other gold badger, then point them at the relevant Meta information.

Comment: You are at a critical stage in the typical SO contributor life-cycle.  This is about where the vast majority give up and don't come back.  All fun and games getting to 10K, got to be bit of a drag after that, rolling eyes at the "ugh, not again" questions.  Only real way to get past the hump is to be more selective about the kind of questions you look at.

Comment: Clearly you are a very skilled programmer, you got there in a hurry, there are just a lot of questions that don't need your expertise.  You have no control over them being asked, other users can handle them.  Be sure to keep it fun and rewarding, getting into these kind debates is no fun at all.

Comment: You might like to see this ^.

Comment: @coldspeed, Yup I have read the comments. But I don't think I'm as great as people think! Still make some trivial mistakes. Questions which *may* be duplicates *but where I can't find good duplicate targets* are good practice :). I think overall this is an important discussion. There are *many* users vested in data analysis tags (`[pandas]`, `[SQL]`, `[r]`, etc) and it seems we all have different ideas of what constitutes a duplicate.