# More than one question per post

Tags: support, asking-questions

If I have more than just one question (or error) about something (e.g. a `TextBox` control), should I group all of them in one only post or should I create a different post for each question or problem?

All question/errors would be about the same control.

Comment: Is there a chance the questions are related to the same error/misconception/issue? Or are they as diverse as "how do I read out the result, and by the way, how do I change the background color"?

Comment: More like the second option.

Comment: Then it should be two separate questions ...

Comment: I can see the downside of having to explain various elements over and over again -- even linking to your other questions would be off-putting. But: Carefully wording the question may still be able to make it work as one. For my above suggestion, for example, you could condense it to "How to access different properties of a textbox" -- followed by an explanation of why you want to do all of it at once.

Comment: If one is having multiple questions, that probably means (*In most cases*) they are not  doing any research or putting effort. If one is putting some effort, his question will be particularly about the one thing he is currently blocked with... When I see such questions I usually downvote them for the same reason.

Comment: @TJ One of the points I make in many questions that seem a bit short on research effort is that *skimming* the manual is an important habit.  It's not necessary to memorize every detail, but having a vague idea of "I think there was *something* about X…" is very helpful.  I mention this because the *research* for one question will in this way often indirectly serve as a research for another.

Comment: @TJ: I have questions all the day. Most of them I resolve by thinking or research. I think you really mean "If one is _posting_ multiple questions", right?

Comment: @phresnel of course, I mean if one is asking multiple questions in a single post... That means they are not trying to solve them one by one, instead they want someone to do it all...

Comment: @TJ: I see. That wasn't clear to me.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The question is whether the questions are really about different issues or they are just aspects of the same issue.

One question I find useful in considering whether questions A and B are really just aspects of the same issue is "would someone who can answer question A be likely to be able to answer question B *because* someone who can answer A will *generally* have the knowledge to answer B?" And ask the same by reversing terms A and B. (It is often the case that flipping A and B won't change the answer to this question but sometimes it does.) If the answer is "no", then you are dealing with two issues needing two questions.

And really, separating the issues helps you to get good answers. I've seen people knowledgeable about question A answer with a great answer regarding A but a really terrible answer regarding B. Some people know that they can't give a comprehensive answer and so just won't bother. (I tend to be in this camp: I'll tell the OP that the question should be split and if nothing happens, I won't submit an answer.)

And separating the issues is also good for future readers. If they look at the question and it looks like it contains technologies they are not using, they might just skip it *even if* the answers would in fact help them.

Answer (score 8):

From a mechanical standpoint for the answering/moderation pool, you can't mark *half* (or 1/4, or 3/4, etc.) of a question as duplicate, or off-topic, etc.

In my experience building too many issues into a question seems to be about one-stop shopping and wanting "all the answers right now"--as opposed there being a true need to tie the information together.  If you ask the first question, and then wait for explanations to get a handle on things, it might resolve your second question...or at least help you frame the second question more succinctly.  You would probably use a different (or more precise) code sample instead of repeating the whole thing to focus on just that second issue.  Usually it strikes me that it's laziness about isolating issues on the part of the questioner that leads them to bundle.

I disagree with @Jongware that it's off-putting to link to a previous question as optional background reading.  Each question should stand in its own right without a link, but if you have done a good job with a first question then a follow-up can mention that for anyone who might want more reading.

I'm sure there are exceptions; *"I'd like the text style to be blue and bold and in a different font, here's what I tried `[...code...]` but it didn't have any effect...it just looks like the default."*  That isn't terrible.  But sometimes picking the most challenging aspect of the question can be a smart way of testing the coverage...of those three, font selection is probably the trickiest.  If you ask about font selection and the answer doesn't point you to the styling API documentation, you can follow up.  That might even be a rare case where a comment is okay instead of a new question: *"It worked great, but I didn't see anywhere to set other attributes...is there documentation on how to set things like color and bold?"*

But other than that, always err on the side of one-question-per-question.  Put the energy on expressing that one question as clearly as possible and tailor your supporting examples to that one question.  It's a spectrum that goes up to "here's my entire codebase, fix it"...and stay as far away from that generality as you can.

Comment: Also what do you do when one question answers B perfectly but you asked both A and B?  Then marking the excellent answer as accepted is problematic.

Answer (score 7):

I think it's important to think about future readers here.  Along the lines of Louis' answer, ask yourself:
"Would someone else having problem A also often have problem B?"

If they're that closely related:

> I'm trying to find if there is a significant statistical difference between A and B.  I'm not sure how to use R to find the standard error between two populations.  Also, I'm not sure what exactly to do with that standard error.

then you're okay in one question.

If they're not that closely related- while both occur in the same program, they're two events not particularly likely to occur at once - then they should be split.  I might make exception for two extremely small issues - but many of those are not good questions anyway, separate OR together.  For example:

> I'm writing this web page.  I can't seem to get the title to center properly.  Also, the right context menu doesn't drop down properly.

Probably should be two questions.

Answer (score 1):

> If I have more than just one question (or error)...

Be very careful not to confuse questions with errors, or errors with error messages.

On StackOverflow, it's highly recommended that you try to isolate your errors. By that, I mean that you should at least test which line or which expression gives you an error, by commenting out the rest of the code and trying to reproduce the error with the bare minimum amount of code possible. For that purpose, you should try to use the error log to originally pinpoint where the issue is (or if no error messages are given, you should at least try to compare the discrepancy in output).

On StackOverflow, few people asking questions post their error logs (when they have one) and fewer people still take the time to try to isolate the first place where an error occurs.

If they did take the time isolate an error where it first occured, then they would have found out that one can only handle one error at a time (before moving to the next one). With actual errors, that's really the best way to do this. Do only one at a time. For all you know, you may only have one error (even if your IDE/compiler shows you having multiple error messages).

For potentially unrelated misunderstandings and potentially unrelated questions, it can be a bad sign to have to have more than one. Be careful not to bite more than you can chew. Not only you're potentially making it harder for the rest of us to answer your questions, but you're potentially making it harder on yourself as well.

If you find yourself wanting to ask several questions, post your main question, but restrain yourself from posting a second question right away. And again, try to isolate your question, just like you were trying isolate an error, or trying to isolate a small piece of functionality. In many cases, it's important to try something, anything, before posing an actual question.

Often times, people will post a question because they're stuck somewhere (which is fine), but then they'll quickly ask follow up questions (even thought, and despite the fact that they haven't solved their first problem, and thus aren't able to experiment on the rest of the problem yet). And on StackOverflow, experimentation is key. Experimentions first makes for good questions later.

Answer (score -9):

In the case of one than one issue, I write about the main issue ***but*** also include details about the *other* issues; this gives anyone reading the question some insight in what the source of the issue may be.

For example if all your issues are caused by one small mistake, it makes sense to include 'em in just one question than with multiple one, especially as the community will likely mark the multiple questions as duplicates of the first, which may or may not be ironic...

If the initial issue is solved but however the other problems are not, ***then*** it's time to create a new question on the next issue. If you're using a similar method/class/type, then check that you're using them correctly, ***especially if the first question deals with solving an issue with misuse of the similar method/class/type***.

I find that this 'two or more questions in one question' culture is common on Super User, and that many users only have the expertise to answer one or two of the listed questions.

***TL:DR; It depends on your scenario.***

Comment: sounds very confusing that way around