# How to Handle Multi-Part Question

Tags: discussion, answers

I was reading this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27133961/d3js-more-inteactive-network-chart-node-menu) and I'm curious as to the proper way to handle a multi-part question.  The poster is asking for difficult help and I feel that I shouldn't answer unless I cover each part.  But for me to answer all three parts to the best of my ability would be very time consuming.  Is it appropriate to ask the poster to split the question into 3 parts?  This would improve search-ability.  Or should I give an incomplete answer and only cover the parts I can?

Comment: There's a reason we ask for one question per question... I would ask him to split it into three parts, linking for context where appropriate.

Comment: That question in question doesn't look very useful for future research, or even appropriate for the SO policies.

Comment: @gnat, damn, i searched for a good 5 minutes looking for duplicates.

Comment: it was difficult to find to me either :) ...until I figured to look into [meta-tag:too-broad] tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the parts are really about different issues or they are just aspects of the same issue? I've put it [like this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275909/1906307) to someone asking whether they should submit one SO question in which they'd ask multiple questions or submit multiple SO questions:

> One question I find useful in considering whether questions A and B are really just aspects of the same issue is "would someone who can answer question A be likely to be able to answer question B because someone who can answer A will generally have the knowledge to answer B?" And ask the same by reversing terms A and B. (It is often the case that flipping A and B won't change the answer to this question but sometimes it does.) If the answer is "no", then you are dealing with two issues needing two questions.

When I've run into questions that are really combining different issues, what I do is to **point out to the OP that they are actually working against their own interests**:

1. If the tags on the question reflect the technologies involved by the various issues in the question, people will skip without actually reading the question. They'll determine that they can't answer because while they know the technologies for tags A and B, they don't know C and D.
2. The people who actually have experience in all the technologies involved will read the question. However, some of them will still skip, because they can answer one issue but not the other and they'd rather not give a partial answer.
3. The answers that *will* get posted probably won't answer all the issues.
4. The question is less likely to be found useful by other people. If the question comes up on a search, they'll see that the question deals with technologies that do not concern them, so they'll skip it in favor of questions that appear to cover only what they need. (If I have a problem with performing an Ajax query with jQuery, do I really want to look at the question which also add SQL transactions into the mix?) Ultimately, this means less upvotes on the question.

And I vote to close as too broad. If the OP fixes the problem, then I retract the vote.