# Multi-part question answered with multiple answers by same member (different from OP)

Tags: discussion, answers, needs-more-focus

I know how to handle a multi-part question in general, by closing it as too broad as per

- [How to handle a question that asks many things](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267058/how-to-handle-a-question-that-asks-many-things)
- [How to Handle Multi-Part Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277873/how-to-handle-multi-part-question)

But what do I do when a multi-part question has been answered by the same different user with *multiple* separate answers, each addressing a different part of the question?  Is this flag-worthy for moderation by the moderators?

To clarify, these are all answers from the same SO member to the one single one multi-part (and evolving) question.  For the record, the moderator Rob was involved with closing the original question.

Please see images (shrunk to fit size and to make then somewhat illegible to avoid meta effect) to see what I mean:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you mean all those answers is for one question?

Comment: @Sami: yes, absolutely. They're all posted, one after the other

Comment: Well, I would simply flag it for a mod, this is a new phenomenon really.

Comment: I encountered this before, but that was on a single, well-contained question with a bounty on it and someone posted three different answers in three different answer-boxes, instead of one single answer-box with three variations. I flagged those and they were merged in the end.

Comment: @Adriaan You flag them as?

Comment: @Sami custom and explained the situation.

Comment: OK, I've done so just now. I'm somewhat "flag-shy" having had prior flags declined ignominiously

Comment: And also shout out to diamond moderator "Rob" who closed the original question

Comment: Also, in comments I have notified the original poster and the answerer about this meta discussion, but also have given them a warning link about the [Meta Effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect), so that they avoid it from happening if they wish.

Comment: OMG, 10 answers really ?? I would like to see the question then ...

Comment: 8 answers actually. I've some overlap in my images. And the OP appears upset at my asking this question

Comment: looks like it was reduced to 3 answers by updating(merging) and removing parts

Comment: Just two users getting used to the site. Perhaps educating them would be a good start. There is nothing inherently wrong with posting multiple answers. It isn't like the database is somehow going to get injured from this type of activity, and the 100 views is hardly causing some sort of issue with too many people finding low quality on the site - especially given that the question is on hold. This is just a one off instance, and to be honest, there was really no need whatsoever to make this about one post. In the future, perhaps consider addressing a broader behavior instead of a specific one.

Comment: @TravisJ: good viewpoint, and I thank you for that. This is why I tried not to identify the question or the posters, to avoid undue harsh actions. I have flagged the moderators, since perhaps they will want to combine the remaining answers into one.

Comment: Even if a "multi-part" question was on-topic, I believe answers should be *complete* (i.e. a single answer should address the whole question, including "subquestions). A user may decide to provide multiple answers *if they provide different means to answer the question*. I don't know: one answer uses "plain Python", the other one with pandas+numpy to show a vectorized solution.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta Like [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1113578/623023), for instance ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle a question that asks many things](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267058/how-to-handle-a-question-that-asks-many-things)

Answer (score 3):

Vote to close the question as too broad (it would seem if it can have ten separate legitimate answers  by the same user, it may be too broad).

The answers are less of the problem, than the question. Once the question is closed, it is more likely to be deleted, along with the answers on it.

Also "technically" there's no reason someone cannot post two separate answers on the one question (if they are different enough). It's just that usually our questions don't lend themselves to this and we tend to encourage people to edit the original answer to include all the details within the one post.

As for the answerers ten efforts being wasted, we live and learn.

Comment: Interesting that you chose to say there is technically no reason someone cannot post **two** separate answers if they are different enough and the question lends itself to it when technically the same is true for **ten** different answers which is more in keeping with what we see here. :)

Comment: While the letter of the law with regards to broad questions is fine and all, let's not forget that SO is primarily supposed to produce *helpful content*. *Iff* that giant post in itself contains valuable, discoverable, comprehensible content, it may be a net plus to just let it stay.

Comment: O better yet, put all the information in a format where it would be useful, like breaking down the broad questions into more pointed ones.

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland That seems like a challenge; 10 legitimate separate answers to a question that is not too broad!  I've easily found ones with 4 answers without really looking for it (usually I fold them into one answer as options)

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont - I'd be interested in the statistics on that, what open question on SO has the most separate answers from a single user and how many have the gave? My money is on 3 being the most, would love to see you achieve more (especially 10!) legitimately. EDIT - Sorry, just noticed you say you've easily found ones with 4. Well, beats my assumption of 3!

Answer (score -4):

Can we not just edit the accepted answer so that includes the other answers and then close the question as being too broad?

Comment: No need to edit the answers. If the question is off topic, just close it. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/373336/3956566