# Which close reason to use for two questions in one post?

Tags: support

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29279915/visual-studio-c-sharp-2012-label-text-sql-value) today.  It is effectively two questions in one post, one about fixing a SQL query and another about what looks like a DLL / reference problem.  As the two answers that are on the question at the time of writing this demonstrate, the question is not a good fit.  To quote one:

> I can't help with the second question but recommend using ADO.NET.

I want to vote to close this but am unsure which reason is the most appropriate.  I can't imagine there is a duplicate that covers both questions in one post (or at least there shouldn't be).  It's not off-topic.  I don't believe that it is unclear.  It's pretty obvious what he wants, but I guess a case could be made that it is unclear which thing he wants solved for this post.  It's not opinion based.  The only one left is too broad, which kinda covers it in that the answers have to be longer to accommodate both questions, but both could be answered in a reasonably short post.  My only other guess is to flag the mods to handle it.

What is the appropriate way to flag / close this?

Comment: I use *Too broad* for that, and / or edit the post to remove the second question altogether. If there is a dupe, I pick the dupe for one of the questions and use a comment for the other or ask them to post a new question.

Comment: see also: [More than one question per post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275908/more-than-one-question-per-post)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just edit the second question out of the post and tell the author to ask it in a new question if he really needs it answered.

Other than that, flagging as "too broad" is generally the right way to go when there are multiple questions asked in the same question.

Comment: Wouldn't editing to remove an entire question, even it if is one that shouldn't be there, "conflict with the intention of the author"? That seems like a rather dramatic edit to make on someone else's post instead of encouraging them to rework it.

Comment: If the only other option is to close the question, I don't think the author will mind @sphanley. Also, I think it's a lot easier to help the author understand how they could improve their question by showing them, instead of by just telling them. And, if they don't appreciate your edit, they can always roll it back.

Comment: I think in this case I'm just going to flag as too broad.  Editing out the first question invalidates the answers already there.  Editing out the second question leaves it as a prime target for the dupe hammer.  Either way it ends up closed.

Answer (score 4):

A comment goes a long ways to fix these kinds of problems.  If you can word it with a positive attitude("You will probably get a better response if...") and they are willing to comply, then they will be learning how to write better questions.  If we force their hand by editing it for them or closing without a comment, it's less likely that they will get any better.

We can see in this case the user was happy to edit their own question in response to a comment.

If they ignore the comment, and the comment is valid, then others will see that you've asked the asker to improve the question.  Since the asker did not comply, viewers will conclude the asker is not interested in fixing the problem, and vote to close.

- If you are first on the scene, leave a comment explaining:

  - What is wrong (two questions in one)
  - How it can be improved (remove a question)
  - Why it will be better (will get more/better responses)
- Optionally, vote to close (in this case Too Broad).  My personal preference is to only comment if I'm first on the scene.
- If someone else has already commented and the asker hasn't responded, vote to close.

Depending on the traffic the question sees, it may close pretty quickly before the asker has a chance to fix it, but at least the comment will show them there was interest in helping them improve it.  If they have a good attitude they can improve it and ask to reopen.

Comment: I guess I could have clarified my question slightly in that I did comment on that post explaining what should be done.  After no activity for a while I was contemplating what I should do if the situation didn't resolve itself.  And then I ended up here with my question.  Totally agree that the first step is to let the OP know what is wrong and give them a change to fix it themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you shouldn't just edit the question, without clarifying in comments- but clarify in comments if possible.

If you do end up flagging/voting to close, "Unclear what you're asking" is the right reason, not "Too Broad", though I don't think too many would quibble either way.  Since there isn't one clear question in the question, it's unclear which question they want answered.