# Why isn't it good to ask multiple questions and answers in one question?

Tags: support

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [Detailed information about java gui programming, direct3d, opengl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51540463/detailed-information-about-java-gui-programming-direct3d-opengl)

Why do these kind of questions get downvoted? I made it so many people can access it and get a wide information about it. Isn't this forum for people's benefit, like I assumed? But the post made me lose 4 of my 5 rep.

[image]

Comment: What about the information you were given in the close reason, and the two additional, rather detailed, comments that were posted didn't answer this question for you?

Comment: The question is waay too broad, like the comments are already explaining (hence the downvotes). You might find clarity following the links posted beneath your questions and see what is considered a good and useful question on SO.

Comment: SO isn't a forum. It's a Q&A site. I already explained in comments why the question is too broad. The close reason clearly states: *Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.*

Comment: shall i ask all those questions at another topics then? wouldnt this take time and be spammy?

Comment: @Asaf31214 Others have already explained to you why those questions are also problematic individually, not just as a group.

Comment: For the downvotes here: [Meta SO: What is the meta effect?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect)

Comment: @user202729 That link doesn't explain the downvotes on this post.

Comment: [Help center/What is "meta"? How does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: **Downvotes are on posts, not users.**

Comment: @Asaf31214 I don't know about you but there are times that taking in a flood of negative votes / posts seems... well... very discouraging.  Don't give up, try to digest the advice, gather your thoughts and then ask just one question to start. Take the time to really look at the question before clicking the button. In the past I had been and to a point still evolve my question over time. Now I put a lot more effort into asking the best question I can from the start. I still end up evolving the question. Give it a try.

Comment: See the help center.. [Questions to avoid asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) You're getting downvoted because the question is bad and this meta post is drawing attention to it, causing it to get more views (thus downvotes) than normal.

Comment: Your question isn't stating a discussion of a feature. You are asking *why* your post was generating downvotes.

Comment: Q: *do they both have their own coding languages?*  A: *yes*. I don't call that wide information to be honest. Maybe it is best posted at your own blog. Most questions you have listed can be googled and return more starting points then you covered as answer.

Comment: @rene i already told there may be incomplete answers and im open to edits

Comment: @codeer i asked why this kind of questioıns are downrated. i didnt ask why my question is downrated

Comment: @Asaf31214 And yet you had gotten lots of different well written feedback on the problems with your question *before even asking on meta*, and you still haven't indicated in what way that feedback didn't help you determine what you did wrong, nor have you attempted to resolve those problems.  Asking a bunch of people to repeat what you've already been told isn't helpful.

Comment: @Servy i got told that kind of question is unuseful to ask. and i am asking here why it is like that since it helps many people with various reason

Comment: @Asaf31214 You were given *lots* of information on why those questions weren't appropriate.  You were not just told that it's not useful without reasoning.

Comment: @Servy i received links about it. read them. i already obey the rule "it should be a discussion about forum rules"

Comment: If you read the information then why are you repeatedly asking questions that they have already answered?

Comment: @Servy isnt meta for discussing rules? or only reading it? as i told many times before i was trying to discuss that rule

Comment: @Asaf31214 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371614/why-isnt-it-good-to-ask-multiple-questions-and-answers-in-one-question/371615?noredirect=1#comment614347_371614 ← contains a link to how voting on meta works, and that it doesn't affect rep.

Comment: @Asaf31214 Yes, meta is an appropriate place to discuss a rule on the site.  But that doesn't make it appropriate to ask a question *that others have already answered for you* just because you want people to repeat those answers, multiple times.  That's not helpful to anyone.  You also weren't discussing a rule, you asked why your question was downvoted. (Which would also be an on topic question, again, if you hadn't already been given the answer already.)

Comment: @Servy if you read correct, i didnt ask why my question is downrated. why these kind of questions get downrated.

Comment: @Asaf31214 And now, you got your answer. Right?

Comment: @Asaf31214 And how did the comments on your question fail to answer that for you?  Those comments will apply to other questions like yours, that have the same problems it has.

Comment: @Asaf31214: Why did your remove the screenshot of your post?

Comment: @krlzlx i was just trying to edit a typo. i didnt add that screenshot too

Comment: its ok now i edited back

Comment: @gnat That one is for ways to handle it, this one is for the reason why is it bad.

Comment: @gnat no its definetely seperate than mine

Comment: It's fairer to ask 13 individual questions so that they can each be downvoted and closed on their own merits.  It is not possible for one curator to issue 11 downvotes on one bad question with 11 bad sections, so you are effectively dodging 10 downvotes.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The reason lists of questions are discouraged is partly because they're difficult to answer (nobody wants to write a long-form article answering an 11 part question), but it's mostly about searchability/findability. The title "Detailed information about java gui programming, direct3d, opengl" is so general that it's unlikely anyone will ever search for that (unless they're looking for a book to read).

Each question on Stack Overflow should stand on its own, and it should have some future value to people who are searching for the solution to the same problem. Burying a question (and its answer) in a double-digit list greatly hinders the chances that anyone will ever find that information again. Separate your list into individual questions. Do any of them stand on their own? If so, consider posting them as separate questions. If not, you probably need to find a book, or take a class, or find some other off-site resource where you can learn the fundamentals.

Answer (score 10):

It's because you are only supposed to have one question in each question. You're not allowed to have 11 questions. Also you can't answer the question in the question itself, answers should be a separate answer. Furthermore, the questions are too broad. Consider reading up on the help center.

Also think about this: How can you accept an answer for each of your questions?

Comment: and i was asking why the feature is like that

Comment: Multiple questions in the same question cause several problems: It is hard to write a complete answer, one can't vote on single questions/answers anymore. They are harder to search for. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275908/more-than-one-question-per-post

Comment: Some day, the help center should contain the rationale for the rules..............

Comment: @BDL i expected people to answer like "answer for #7:..." and its easier to find your problem when you google it. wish i had such an answer at the beginning

Comment: @Asaf31214 It will be harder to find the problem. People would take years to read through all other unrelated answers.

Comment: @Asaf31214 part of why they want a single question is to make it easier for a search engine to deliver the next person to your question and answer. To make it easier to digest.

Comment: @user202729 they are all related to each other at one point, so i think if someone wants to get information about one of them they will learn others too

Comment: @Asaf31214: Just a side-note: On SO you should really try to write as correct English as you can. Ignoring punctuation and capitalization completely makes texts much harder to read. For example, i should be I, dont -> don't.

Comment: @Asaf31214 That's what the "linked" question lists are for.

Comment: To add on to @BDL it also makes you look childish and uninterested.

Comment: @Asaf31214 how can you Accept an answer if you ask a dozen questions? Which answer is "the best answer" to all these questions at once? None, unfortunately. That makes the answers less valuable, as people coming to your post from Google aren't able to sift through the noise in the post. Stack was created to be a high signal, low noise repository of knowledge. The way you asked your questions seem to go contrary to that

Comment: @Patrice i would be editing all answers to my post so they would be all at one post like questions. if my post wasnt deleted ofc

Comment: @Asaf31214 so you'd put the ANSWERS in the QUESTION?.... doesn't that feel contrary to what the boxes should be used for (not to mention by copy/pasting answers from other people in your question, you may be denying them upvotes and rep...)? To me, it feels like you want to write a blog post.... Don't get me wrong, there IS value in such posts. It just doesn't really fit Stack's model :/

Comment: @BDL thanks for the note I already edited the post

Comment: @Asaf31214 Putting information from other answers into your answer (or question) is really not a good idea. The original author would not get any rep at all for this. And you would be getting points for something that wasn't written by you.

Comment: @BDL so is everyone's problem about my post is reputation? go make fake accounts and answer your own questions if your purpose is reputation

Comment: @Asaf31214 no. That's just a side effect of you copy pasting (by the way if you take an answer from someone else, as per the license we all post under, you should provide attribution to the answerers). The biggest problem remains that, since you bundled all your questions together, the post loses value, as it's hard to search for and find, and then also ends up causing viewers to read a lot more than they need to to get to their answers.

Comment: @Asaf31214  ||| **Questions are questions, answers are answers**. If you have answer to your own question, you should *post a self answer*, **NOT** *edit the question to add the answer*.

Comment: If users with to post 11-part questions, then curators should be able to issue 11 downvotes each,  it's only fair, and the rep should be  allowed to go negative.