# What do I do when a question is a duplicate of multiple questions?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30512833/file-to-string-or-string-to-file) is a bit of a two parter. The question is essentially, "how do I read and write strings from a file?" which can of course be broken into the read question and the write question. As it happens, both of those are duplicates of (separate) questions.

I considered voting to close the question as too broad, but I don't think it's actually very broad at all: the OP is asking about two actions, but they're essentially two sides of the same coin (heck, we even have a term, "I/O" that combines them).

I also considered marking it as a duplicate of one and adding a comment to point to the other, but that didn't seem right. Which do I pick as the dupe?

I posted a comment on the question pointing to the two dupes, but I didn't close to vote. Was there a better course of action?

Comment: For such an exceedingly low-quality question, it doesn't really matter which duplicate you choose. Closing as one and linking to the other in a comment is fine.

Comment: related: [Is there a benefit to closing a question as a duplicate of more than one question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254710/is-there-a-benefit-to-closing-a-question-as-a-duplicate-of-more-than-one-questio)

Comment: Don't forget to add a comment suggesting the OP should ask multiple questions in the future instead of two- (or more-) parters.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you really want a method of picking between multiple duplicates:

1. Pick the question that has the best answer or has better answers in general. If the answers on one aren't better than the others:
2. Pick the question that's most similar to the OP's question. If none are better than the others:
3. Pick the question that already has duplicates pointing at it. If you didn't see one when searching for duplicates, don't go looking for one. Instead:
4. Just pick the oldest one. I realize question age doesn't really matter; this should be viewed as a coin toss. You could just as well pick the newest, the one you found first, or the one whose tab you haven't closed yet.

Comment: Instead of the oldest one, I pick the most popular one (most views, most upvotes, ...). Usually they coincide, but not always.

Comment: @Oriol - That makes sense. The question that already has other dupes pointing to it would probably have the most views.

Comment: it doesn't cover the case when the two questions are less related e.g., [How to convert python timestamp string to epoch?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30468371/4279) is a duplicate of ["How to parse ISO formatted date in python?" and of any the questions that ask how
to convert the UTC time to "seconds since the Epoch" (POSIX timestamp).](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30476450/4279)

Comment: Like @bill said, I would add, that the second duplicate should be a comment.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian - I would think picking the best answer(s) or picking the one most similar to the to the OP's question would still work in that case.

Comment: @BSMP: there are two independent parts: 1. string -> broken-down time (e.g., `datetime` object) 2. UTC time -> "seconds since epoch". Picking a single answer solves only one of the two parts.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian - Ah, OK. I want to say someone's asked about this on Meta before and the answer was that you can answer the OP's question by quoting the other questions as long as you give credit. But I'm not certain that's correct; someone who's been around longer should probably answer that. (In the case where a question is actually multiple, separate issues you could flag it as too broad.)

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively if you feel strategy to find duplicate suggested in good [answer by BSMP](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295500/477420) is does not work for the question - close as "too broad".

It would be less useful to OP, but if collection of problems present in the post requires multiple separate answers "too broad" sounds fair to me. You indeed can comment on what separate questions OP should ask/edit out of that single post if you feel just "to broad" is not nice.